# ¿Son aceptables las preguntas historicas?

Tags: discusión

Teniendo en cuenta los requisitos de que las preguntas tienen que tener una respuesta objetiva y no de opiniones, ¿Son aceptables las preguntas sobre la historia de lenguajes/sistemas/etc?

Ejemplo: ¿Qué cambios hubo de Simula 67 a Smalltalk-71 y Smalltalk-72?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No me queda claro qué no hay de objetivo en una respuesta hacia la pregunta que propone de ejemplo. Cualquier persona que conozca de Simula podrá listarle tres, diez o más items mostrando cuáles fueron los cambios de lenguaje en sintaxis, semántica, diseño, etc. Y sin lugar a dudas esa información o es cierta o es falsa y no habrá lugar a ambigüedades. Quizá el ejemplo que pone a consideración no es el adecuado. Dejando de lado eso, no veo problema en alguna pregunta de tipo histórico porque no encuentro un ejemplo donde una respuesta a preguntas así lleguen a ser subjetivas o sesgadas.

Answer (score 3):

¡Por supuesto!

Hay muchas personas que trabajan con tecnologías legacy que pueden requerir respuestas a este tipo de preguntas.

Comment: Vere como le va en el sitio normal la pregunta que puse de ejemplo. /cruso los dedos.