# Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio

Tags: discusión, temática

A raíz de algunas preguntas en este sitio en las que se discute cuál sería la temática apropiada para StackOverflow en español (como [esta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/115/son-aceptables-las-preguntas-conceptuales), [esta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/109/son-aceptables-las-preguntas-que-en-ingl%C3%A9s-corresponderian-a-programmers-stacke) o [esta otra](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/61/son-aceptables-las-preguntas-historicas)), se me ha ocurrido publicar una especie de encuesta al respecto para ver qué opina la comunidad.

El funcionamiento es sencillo: para cada uno de los temas adicionales al desarrollo del software que se han propuesto como potencialmente válidos para nuestro sitio, voy a publicar una respuesta a esta pregunta. Si os parece un tema adecuado para el sitio, votad la respuesta a favor; si no, votadla en contra.

También incluiré posibles nombres de etiquetas que podrían servir para distinguir y filtrar ese tipo de preguntas. Podéis sugerir más etiquetas en los comentarios y las incorporaré (o si tenéis reputación suficiente, añadidlas directamente editando la respuesta).

Y por supuesto, estáis todos invitados a añadir respuestas/temas adicionales.

Comment: Como no puedo votar mis propias respuestas: yo personalmente estoy a favor de las preguntas tipo Programmers, Code Review e históricas; y estoy en contra de las tipo Super User. Sobre las tipo Server Fault y DBA no lo tengo claro.

Comment: interesante, yo la hubiera hecho wiki comunitario de forma que ya quede como de base como FAQ.

Comment: @rnrneverdies Bien pensado, he pasado a wiki todas las respuestas

Comment: Me llama utilizar los nombres de los sitios (`programmers`, `server-fault`, etc.), en vez de etiquetas traducidas, pero no lo tengo muy claro. La única que claramente me gusta más es `dba`, que no es ni traducción, ni el nombre del sitio. ¿Qué opinan?

Comment: Una de las premisas es evitar la meta etiquetas. Véase [¿Qué son las etiquetas y cómo debo usarlas?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging). Creo que debería señalarse esto en la pregunta y editar las respuestas acorde a esto ya sea para eliminar la meta etiqueta o bien agregar una explicación de la necesidad y/o conveniencia de aplicar una excepción.

Comment: Evitar usar "esta" como título de los enlaces ya que es un caso similar a "click here" (véase http://www.w3.org/QA/Tips/noClickHere)

Comment: Eso es la mejor forma de decidir para cada sitio? Creo que puede ser mejor una pregunta por cada sitio... Porque a veces (tal vez la mayoría), no es un simple pregunta de "si o no".  Por ejemplo, creo que hay muchas preguntas de Programmers que pueden ser dentro de la temática aquí (licensias de software, algoritmos, etc), y otras temas no (como trabajar con otro programador arrogante).  Igual con ServerFault y SuperUser. Unos clases pueden funcionar aquí, y otros no.

Comment: @Flimzy Segurísimo que existen mejores formas, y tu argumentación es perfectamente válida. Esta encuesta es simplemente una idea que se me ocurrió a los pocos días de que el sitio se abriera a beta privada, como una forma de sondear la opinión aproximada de la comunidad. Al final son los votos, reportes y comentarios de los usuarios los que deciden cuál es el contenido apropiado del sitio.

Answer (score 35):

Preguntas **conceptuales sobre el desarrollo de software (arquitectura, algoritmos, metodologías de desarrollo, ciencias de la computación, licencias de software...)** que en inglés se publicarían en el sitio [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Etiquetas sugeridas:

- [arquitectura-de-software](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/arquitectura-de-software) (5 preguntas)
- [algoritmos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/algoritmos) (173 preguntas)
- [patrones-de-diseño](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/patrones-de-dise%c3%b1o) (35 preguntas)
- [diseño-orientado-a-objetos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dise%c3%b1o-orientado-a-objetos) (0 preguntas)

Comment: Ciertamente NADIE usará esas etiquetas, sino las específicas del tema en el que piden ayudan. arquitectura-de-software, patrones-de-diseño, diseño-orientado-a-objetos...

Answer (score 30):

Preguntas sobre **administración y uso avanzado de bases de datos** que en inglés se publicarían en el sitio [Database Administrators](http://dba.stackexchange.com).

Etiquetas sugeridas:

- [dba](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dba) o [administracion-bbdd](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/administracion-bbdd) (0 preguntas)

Comment: Yo voto por [tag:dba] ya que es una sigla conocida

Comment: Tanto 'dba' como 'administracion-bbdd' me parecen meta-etiquetas. Como mencioné en un comentario en la pregunta, una de las premisas de la red de sitios en Stack Exchange es evitar las meta etiquetas. Véase [¿Qué son las etiquetas y cómo debo usarlas?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Answer (score 23):

Preguntas que solicitan **revisiones de código en busca de posibles problemas o sugerencias de mejora** que en inglés se publicarían en el sitio [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Etiquetas sugeridas:

- [revisión-de-código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revisi%c3%b3n-de-c%c3%b3digo) (108 preguntas)

Comment: De acuerdo con estas preguntas en tanto sean para solicitar revisión en los casos que dices. Preguntas del tipo "gimme teh codez" -> Cerradas

Comment: No se olviden de las tildes: `revisión-de-código`

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz Aún no se pueden agregar letras con tildes a los tags

Comment: @JhonAlx Te refieres al meta? Por que en elo sitio principal sí se puede, por ejemplo ya hay [matemáticas](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matem%c3%a1ticas) y [programación-funcional](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programaci%c3%b3n-funcional)

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz sí, solo en Meta. Relacionado: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/23/etiquetas-con-accentos-no-funcionan-por-lo-menos-en-meta

Comment: @CarlosMuñoz La construcción "tag:" en markdown no funciona como se espera si el nombre de la etiqueta tiene tildes. Haz la prueba: pulsa "formular pregunta" o "añadir respuesta", escribe esto: `[tag:revision] [tag:revisión]` y mira el resultado en la vista previa.

Comment: @Konamiman Si ves el historial de ediciones verás que ya lo intenté sin éxito y lo revertí: http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/posts/164/revisions

Comment: Me parece inapropiado las preguntas de code-review; no aportan mucho aparte de la persona inmediata.

Comment: Depende que tan genérico sea lo que se pregunta. Algo de golf sería un poco mejor para premiar la mejora que dé más resultados.

Comment: El tema es que los sitios de stackexchange deberian aportar valor a los futuros visitantes tmb. Si con esto permitimos cualquier pregunta bien puntual sobre un pedazo de codigo gigante en el que el usuario no tiene realmente un scope definido sino simplemente un "esto no me anda", no estoy seguro de que tanto valor pueda aportar. Adicionalmente, en CR se rechazan preguntas de codigo que no funciona para el objetivo perseguido, por lo que "que en ingles se publicarian en Code Review" solo vale para la segunda parte y no para la de los problemas.

Answer (score 17):

Preguntas sobre **gestión de servidores y redes de ordenadores** que en inglés se publicarían en el sitio [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com).

Etiquetas sugeridas:

- [servidores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/servidores) (131 preguntas)

Comment: 'servidores' me parece ser una meta-etiqueta. Como mencioné en un comentario en la pregunta, una de las premisas de la red de sitios en Stack Exchange es evitar las meta etiquetas. Véase [¿Qué son las etiquetas y cómo debo usarlas?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Creo que hay una clase de preguntas sobre servidores que pueden ser dentro de la temática de SO.es, pero sería muy peligroso decir que todas las preguntas de Server Fault están dentro de la temática aquí.  Queremos responder aquí a preguntas sobre [DNS](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/domain-name-system), [VPN](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/vpn) y [Exchange](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/exchange)? Creo que, por mayor parte, no.

Answer (score 14):

Preguntas sobre **historia del desarrollo de software y de lenguajes, herramientas y componentes específicos**, incluyendo cambios relevantes entre versiones.

Etiquetas sugeridas:

- [historia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/historia) (0 preguntas)

Comment: No estoy seguro si una etiqueta historia sería valiosa para el sitio, pero lo que sí estoy seguro es que una pregunta del tipo que cambios hubo entre versión a y b de cualquier cosa no necesita esta etiqueta. Me parece una pregunta más como cualquier otra

Comment: 'historia' me parece ser una meta-etiqueta. Como mencioné en un comentario en la pregunta, una de las premisas de la red de sitios en Stack Exchange es evitar las meta etiquetas. Véase [¿Qué son las etiquetas y cómo debo usarlas?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging)

Comment: Luego de un poco más de un año desde la creación de esta respuesta, [tag:historia] sólo tiene una pregunta y fue publicada este año.

Answer (score 13):

Preguntas sobre **fórmulas de hoja de cálculo** (Excel, Google Sheets, Calc,...)

En inglés se publican

- Excel: en SuperUser y Stack Overflow [excel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/excel) (407 preguntas)
- Google Sheets: en Web Applications y Stack Overflow [google-hoja-de-calculo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-hoja-de-calculo) (79 preguntas)

## Referencias

[Are Excel formulas on topic? META - Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261875/1595451)

Answer (score 4):

Me alegra ver el tipo de respuestas a esta pregunta.  Siendo que nuestra comunidad es singular (no tiene otros sitios en la red todavía) todo tipo de pregunta es aceptable aquí siempre y cuando sea de la temática de StackOverflow.  Preguntas sobre temas como los ya mencionados tienen su lugar aquí.

En cuanto el sitio crezca y madure, podremos visitar este punto de nuevo para evaluar si es necesario retorcer un poco las reglas o nuestras definiciones. Así que, ¡prepárense a preguntar!

Comment: A estas alturas es.SO ya es un sitio graduado. ¿Se seguirán aceptando preguntas respecto de temas dentro de la temática de SuperUser o ServerFault?

Answer (score 2):

Hacer preguntas referentes a **Search Engine Optimization (SEO)**. De acuerdo con el artículo oficial publicado en [¿Que tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar - Centro de Ayuda - Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Creo conveniente que se discuta sobre ello por que son preguntas que incurren a la investigación y tienen un punto de vista de objetivo. En cambio, no encuentro etiqueta alguna que refiera a ello y he ahí mi duda.

**Preguntas como:**

- ¿Cuál es la mejor práctica para optimizar un sitio?
- ¿Cómo usar correctamente el separador del título? «-» o «|»
- ¿Cómo optimizar una imagen sin perder calidad?
- ¿Cómo usar RewriteCond en el .htaccess para comprimir contenido?
- ¿Cuál es la importancia de sitemap.xml?

Todo este tipo de preguntas es publicada originalmente en [Webmasters Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com).

Me gustaría conocer objetivamente el por qué si o no sería considerado incluir dicho contenido en el StackOverflow en Español, si existe alternativa o consideración sobre el tema.

Etiqueta sugerida:

- [seo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/seo) (39 preguntas)
- [google-search-console](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-search-console) para preguntas que tengan que ver con [Google Search Console](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/hacked/docs/use_search_console) y sus [APIs](https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/) específicamente. (10 preguntas)

Comment: Aunque ya existan sitios (foros) altamente especializados en esta temática, no deja de ser atractiva la idea de permitir que esa comunidad encuentre sitio en SOes pues generan un gran movimiento día a día; pero habrá que tener paciencia pues no todo el SEO está relacionado con asuntos técnicos o de desarrollo, hay muchas otras temáticas como LinkBuilding, BlackHat, WhiteHat, LinkJuice, Empresas de PPC, CPA, CPM, etc; estas temáticas son en su gran mayoría no-técnicas y sería necesario ir educando poco a poco sobre el sistema de SO.

Comment: Varian mucho en el tiempo; tecnicas de SEO que funcionen hoy en Google no van a funcionar en un año.

Comment: Adicionalmente no creo que tenga que ver con programacion.

Comment: @FabiánHerediaMontiel el on-site SEO mucho tiene que ver con programación, a menos que dependa de plugins de 3ros que ya estén creados.

Comment: En que sentido puedes programar para SEO que no este cubierto actualmente como programacion? Digo, Google da puntos por ser responsive y cargar rapido, ambas se pueden tomar como preguntas tecnicas independientes a SEO.

Comment: Creo que dependería mucho de la pregunta. Por ejemplo, los dos primeros ejemplos (y el tercero casi también) no deberían ser aceptados porque son demasiado amplios/atraen opiniones o no versan sobre programación en sí. Los dos últimos se ven bien

Comment: En Google Developers se incluye un micrositio sobre SEO se llama [Webmasters](http://developers.google.com/webmasters), por lo que se podría decir, al menos desde la perspectiva de Google que un Webmasters es un rol especializado de un desarrollador

Answer (score 1):

Preguntas sobre: **problemas específicos de diseño de UX/UI, preguntas sobre interface usuario maquina (HCI) e "user reaserch"**, que en inglés se publicarían en el sitio [User Experience](https://ux.stackexchange.com/)

etiquetas sugeridas:

(falta sugerir etiquetas)

Comment: esta es nueva, no estaba en la encuesta original, la agregue por que este es otro sitio que trata sobre aspectos relacionados con el desarrollo de software en general, aunque no sean de programación en si.

Comment: Esta pregunta esta mas orientada al diseño y no a la programación. Ademas, es realmente muy subjetivo el tema del diseño de interfaces y experiencias. Daria lugar a respuesta con connotaciones y gustos muy propios de la persona que la responde.

Comment: Siendo el caso que no tenemos lugar para platicar esto, estaría dispuesto a tener conversaciones de este tipo aquí.

Answer (score -4):

Preguntas de reto de programacion, como los que se hacen en [Code Golf - Stack Exchange](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Todos los retos deberan contar con:

> Una **especificacion clara** de lo que constituye una respuesta correcta, de tal forma que sea posible decidir indisputablemente si
>   una respuesta es valida o no. Pruebas unitarias son alentadas.
>
> Un **unico criterio para ganar**, de tal forma que se pueda decidir indisputablemente que respuesta es la ganadora.

Todas las soluciones a retos deberan:

> Implementar **correctamente** la especificacion requerida.
>
> Ser un **contendiente serio al criterio especificado**; si el criterio es tamaño, que intente ser pequeño; si el criterio es velocidad que intente ser rapido.

**Etiqueta**: [reto](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/reto) (0 preguntas)

Comment: Me parece que aún hay muy pocos usuarios, para alentar este tipo de preguntas, tal ves en un futuro.

Comment: Yo voteo en contra. [Me gusta Code Golf](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/788/peter-olson), pero el estilo de este sitio es muy diferente que los otros sitios de Stack Exchange, y necesita reglas muy diferentes (por ejemplo, no hay nada de "problemas o preguntas reales con los que te encontraste"), y no creo que vale la pena mezclar comunidades tantas diferentes.

Answer (score -12):

Preguntas tipo **Tarea para el hogar**:

Ya he visto algunas preguntas que buscan una solución para una tarea que les han dado en la escuela.  Aceptaremos estas preguntas:

[tarea-escolar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tarea-escolar) [tarea-para-el-hogar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tarea-para-el-hogar)

Comment: creo que en general serian preguntas bastante localizadas. Sin embargo debo admitir que puede haber casos bien validos y que sean útiles para un numero mayor de personas.

Comment: En el sitio en inglés se eliminó la etiqueta homework porque se decidió que si era o no tarea es irrelevante. Mientras que sea una buena pregunta es válida: [The homework tag is now officially deprecated](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated) y [Can we now discourage the use of and burninate the homework tag?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123758/can-we-now-discourage-the-use-of-and-burninate-the-homework-tag)

Comment: Creo que aunque este tipo de preguntas sean aceptables (siempre y cuando incluyan código que demuestre que el estudiante ha intentado algo y no sólo está pidiendo resultados, en cuyo caso creo que no deberían admitirse), no creo que deban tener su propia etiqueta. No hay ningún beneficio real al categorizar esas preguntas como tareas porque es una etiqueta excesivamente genérica que puede incluir cualquier cosa.

Answer (score -16):

Preguntas sobre **recomendaciones de herramientas o librerías para programadores**, tipo *"¿Me recomiendan un buen IDE para el lenguaje X?"* o *"¿Qué librerías hay para generar PDFs en el lenguaje Y?"*

Etiquetas sugeridas:

- [herramientas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/herramientas)
- [recomendaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/recomendaciones)

Comment: Esto podría ser valido al principio, pero invalido cuando el sitio madure un poco.

Comment: Eso disminuiría la calidad de la comunidad, pues se reprime la auto-investigación. Una cosa es preguntar una comparativa de herramientas para adquirir una experiencia que no se tiene y otra preguntar por herramientas debido a nuestra falta de capacidad (de búsqueda) o conocimiento, pues generarían respuestas basadas en opiniones y permiten opiniones de cualquiera en vez de coptar a los expertos en ciertas herramientas. A la larga, se tendría un usuario que no sabe como buscar, acostumbrado a que le digan que opciones tomar y basarse en la opinión de la mayoría para hacer una elección.

Comment: No sería consecuente ir castigando preguntas similares en otros temas mientras avalamos las de estas etiquetas.

Answer (score -19):

Preguntas sobre **el uso de aplicaciones de software y componentes de hardware**, que en inglés se publicarían en el sitio [SuperUser](http://superuser.com).

Etiquetas sugeridas:

- [aplicaciones-software](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/aplicaciones-software)
- [hardware](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hardware)

Comment: esto seria una caos

Comment: Esta es buena, siempre y cuando, sea una pregunta avanzada.