# La problemática de los temas en SOes y la inactividad del sitio

Tags: discusión

> La profesionalidad en StackOverflow debe mostrarse en la calidad de las respuestas, sin importar el grado de dificultad de la pregunta.

Desde la apertura del sitio el debate de la "[Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/definici%C3%B3n-de-la-tem%C3%A1tica-apropiada-para-el-sitio)" ha generado mucho ruido pero no llegado a nada. El sitio comenzó bien, con una buena iniciativa y se percibía el entusiasmo que había de los demás por apoyar a que el sitio madurara y tuviera nuevos integrantes. Lamentablemente, se ha perdido el enfoque objetivo del sitio "aportar".

Ahora percibo que la gente no quiere hacer preguntas por que los primeros comentarios son:

- ¿ya investigaste?
- ¿ya hiciste algo?

A preguntas que considero requieren apoyo y por eso recurre a este sitio, pero al ver respuestas como esas, se van. Es decir; si yo quisiera saber:

¿Cómo conectar MySQL con C++?

Probablemente a muchos les será obvio y sencillo pero a mi no, sé que al final si investigo **TODO** lo puedo encontrar sin buscar apoyo en StackOverflow, pero justo la profesionalidad empieza aportando con cosas "tan simples" como esas y no esperar en todo momento preguntas como:

- ¿Cómo generar un algoritmo completamente aleatorio?

Al final de todo, la inactividad del sitio va aumentando a cada día y lo vemos en las estadísticas que ofrece Area 51 en: [Stack Overflow (in Spanish)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish)
.

Para demostrar esto, me he dedicado a recopilar preguntas que considero que aquí por quererse buscar un estricto sentido profesional, no se han atrevido a preguntar y que en otros sitios en lugar de juzgar la dificultad de la pregunta, sólo apoyan y aportan con respuestas de calidad:

#### StackOverflow (inglés)

- [How to parse JSON using Node.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5726729/how-to-parse-json-using-node-js)
- [How to `git clone` including submodules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796927/how-to-git-clone-including-submodules)
- [How do I get started with Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2353818/how-do-i-get-started-with-node-js/)
- [update multiple picture src from thier diferent figcaption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34697327/update-multiple-picture-src-from-thier-diferent-figcaption)
- [How to set/unset cookie with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery)

#### StackOverflow (Ruso)

- [localStorage может быть заместо бд?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480933/localstorage-%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%B1%D0%B4)
- [replace плохо работает](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/480985/replace-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82)

#### StackOverflow (Portugués)

- [Como criar um plugin para a função $() do jQuery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/14968/como-criar-um-plugin-para-a-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o-do-jquery)
- [Passar url de vídeo para dentro de Modal - Jquery](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/107361/passar-url-de-v%C3%ADdeo-para-dentro-de-modal-jquery)
- [JSON alimentado por while](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/107170/json-alimentado-por-while)

Al final son preguntas sencillas para mí, pero por claridad lo que es sencillo para mí, no significa que lo sea para los demás y yo estoy deseoso de compartir conocimiento, pero si no le permitimos a la comunidad el privilegio de exponer sus dudas, creo que estamos cayendo en el ego.

Comment: yo estoy de acuerdo con lo que dices en rasgos generales algunas veces usan como tu mencionas ¿ya investigaste? y me he topado con pregunta que despues de hablar con el usuario que pregunta, el no a podido inverticar o encontrar nada, simplemente porque no sabia que es lo que estaba buscando exactamente, me explico un usuario puede tener una idea de lo que quiere lograr pero si no sabe cuales son las palabras clave o terminos para buscar lo que quiere hacer, pues como va a publicar lo que hizo si no sabe por donde empezar a buscar, asi que algunas veces ambas preguntas estan entrelazadas

Comment: Sobre la sencilles que dices estoy de acuerdo. Una pregunta sencilla puede ser una gran pregunta, es como si aprendes un lenguaje nuevo y buscas como se crea una variable en tal lenguaje, esa persona no sabia y busco la repuesta ya sea en SO, google o en un libro este año o hace 20, el caso es que alguien la escribio y por eso mas gente lo sabe, pero porque mas gente lo sepa no quiere decir que ahora sea mas facil que al principio cuando alguien que no lo sabia tuvo que buscarlo por primera vez. Saludos

Comment: Yo creo mas bien que si bien es cierto el nivel de participación a disminuido, la mayoría ahora esta dispuesto a ayudar antes que simplemente votar negativamente, En mi caso particular antes de renegar por la mala calidad de las preguntas he tratado de ser amable y tratar de preguntar de que trata la pregunta y he visto en muchos casos que efectivamente ha servido para ayudar a los que preguntan.

Comment: Las tres preguntas del sitio en portugués y una de las dos en ruso tienen código en la propia pregunta, así que preguntar "¿qué has intentado?" ni siquiera fue necesario en este caso. No me parecen buenos ejemplos para apoyar lo que planteas.

Comment: Y en cuanto a las estadísticas del sitio: yo veo que no dejan de subir. Hace una semana estábamos en 400 visitas por día y ahora son 600.

Comment: También yo he notado un bajón en las aportaciones. Lo que pasa es que lo achaco fundamentalmente a las Navidades. Sería interesante contrastarlo mirando las [site analytics](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics). En mi caso las puedo ver en un par de sitios de [se] y sí, en ellos también se observa un claro descenso en posts y visitas en las últimas 3 semanas.

Comment: [apoyo la moción con toda ...](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PYu3CZs0Zkw)

Answer (score 6):

Personalmente creo que depende mucho de la manera en la que esté escrita la pregunta. Y hay muchos casos en los que comentarios como "¿qué has intentado?" o "¿ya hiciste algo?" están más que justificados. No es cuestión de la temática de la pregunta sino de la calidad de la misma.

Estoy de acuerdo en que debemos ser algo menos estrictos mientras el sitio comienza para atraer más gente y que el sitio crezca, y las preguntas sencillas son (y serán) aceptables y bienvenidas. De hecho, no veo nada malo en los ejemplos de preguntas que has puesto.

Pero creo que no hay que confundir sencillez con mala calidad. Y todo dependerá de cómo sea la pregunta: una pregunta no sólo depende del título, su contenido es el que debe determinar si es sencilla o simplemente mala. Por poner un ejemplo, en el caso de "¿Cómo conectar MySQL con C++?", nos podemos encontrar diferentes cuerpos:

- "¿Cómo se haría? ¿Hay diferentes posibilidades? Si las hay, ¿cuál es mejor?"
- "He hecho esto hasta ahora: `[código relevante]` pero me falla y me da el error X. ¿Qué puedo hacer para solucionarlo?"
- "Estoy intentando conectar mi base de datos MySQL con C++ y algo falla, ¿cómo lo puedo solucionar?"
- "Estoy intentando conectarme una base de datos MySQL con C++, aquí dejo una captura de pantalla de mi programa.".

Todas esas preguntas son sencillas, pero en los dos primeros casos la pregunta es simple, aceptable y va a atraer contenido de calidad (incluso cuando la primera es un poco genérica, pero no está mal). Nunca escribiría un comentario del tipo "¿Qué has intentado?" en ninguna de ellas.

Los dos siguientes casos muestran una pregunta simple y al mismo tiempo de mala calidad: casos particulares sin código y/o con contenido pobre (con un poco de suerte la captura de pantalla será del código y, con un poco de más suerte, de código relevante a la pregunta). En esas preguntas sí que dejaría un comentario del tipo "¿Qué has intentado?" o "Comparte código" y puede que dejara un voto negativo.

Las preguntas (sencillas o no) sobre errores particulares de programación que no incluyen código o esfuerzo previo no ayudan a nadie más que al que las pregunta y puede que ni siquiera eso:

- **La gente que intenta responder no sabe cómo hacerlo**. En el caso particular de conectar MySQL con C++: ¿es usando el driver de MySQL para C++? ¿o una de las bibliotecas que hay disponibles online? ¿y cuál de ellas? Dependiendo de eso, la respuesta variará considerablemente.
- **La persona que pregunta casi siempre acaba añadiendo más (sub)preguntas** en los comentarios del tipo "no funciona" o "¿cómo adapto esto a mi código?" o "esa solución usa X pero yo uso Z ¿cómo sería usando Z?".
- **La pregunta/respuesta no va a beneficiar a usuarios futuros** que no saben si el error con el que ellos se encuentran es el mismo expuesto en la pregunta o no.
- **El mal contenido atrae mal contenido**: si la gente ve que puede hacer preguntas del tipo "no sé cómo hacer esto, hacedlo por mí" (*plz send teh codez* en inglés), el sitio se va a llenar de ese tipo de preguntas que no es el tipo de contenido que se desea.

En mi opinión, la máxima a seguir sería: "la persona que pregunta debe ayudar al resto de usuarios a ayudarle en la resolución del problema". Las preguntas (simples o no) sin código y que demuestran poco o nulo interés, no debieran tener cabida en StackOverflow en Español (o en ningún sitio de StackExchange).

No todo vale. Es importante que el sitio crezca y que crezca de manera orgánica (que no sea sólo a base de traducciones del sitio inglés), y al mismo tiempo es importante que el sitio crezca con contenido de calidad.

Por eso cambiaría la primera frase de tu pregunta a:

> La profesionalidad en StackOverflow debe mostrarse en la calidad de las **preguntas y respuestas**, sin importar el grado de dificultad de la pregunta.

...Pero esa es sólo mi opinión :)

Comment: De acuerdo, Alvaro

Comment: Buena respuesta, estoy de acuerdo con tu punto de vista.  Las preguntas deben ser echas con calidad en mente...pero...los usuarios nuevos necesitarán ayuda para lograr esto.  Propongo que sigamos educandolos mostrando paciencia y otros ejemplos para poder subir la calidad del contenido encontrado aquí.

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso particular mi participación se visto ha disminuida por cuestiones estacionales del trabajo:

1. carga de trabajo
2. vacaciones.

Además de situaciones que han requerido acciones de contención.

Me imagino que algo similar podría estar sucediendo en otros casos. Por otro lado, creo que le hacen falta al argumento de la pregunta datos duros para juzgar que la actividad en el sitio ha disminuido de manera preocupante. En Area 51 se indica que

- número de preguntas por día es Excelente.
- otros cuatro indicadores se encuentran en OK
- sólo el número de usuarios ávidos requiere trabajo.

Siendo que publicar respuestas es lo que otorga proporcionalmente el mayor número de puntos, lo que se requiere es

1. Más usuarios aportando respuestas.
2. Más usuarios votando positivamente las respuestas de forma orgánica.

Para ello propongo reforzar las acciones para

1. Promover el sitio (más usuarios)
2. Promover el apego al modelo (más publicaciones, votos, comentarios, todos de forma orgánica)
3. Promover la tenacidad y paciencia de los prospectos a usuarios ávidos actuales, sobre todos aquellos que participan en etiquetas que aún no atraen muchos usuarios.

Comment: mm pero esos son los valores del sitio gringo, y el query solo trae datos hasta diciembre

Comment: @JuanK: Obviamente que no. SO tiene mas de un año de antigüedad y mucho más de 600 preguntas desde hace años.

Comment: revisa... en todo caso los de Stack overflow en español no son, asegurate que estas en el sitio en español donde dice "switch sites"

Comment: @JuanK: Revertí la edición. Sobre la gráfica que publiqué, ejecuté el query para SOes pero al hacer clic en la pestaña del gráfico se cambió a meta.SOes.

Comment: Sobre la gráfica, véase http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/388/sede-bug-que-lleva-a-confusi%C3%B3n-sobre-estad%C3%ADsticas-de-soes