# Versión en español de programmers.stackexchange.com

Tags: discusión, temática

Creo que debería existir una versión en español de https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/, he visto muchas preguntas válidas que no entran dentro del esquema de stackoverflow, pero si entrarían en programmers.

Considero adecuado el fork porque ayudaría a resolver dudas de arquitectura, de herramientas y algoritmos

Comment: Favor de ver http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/163/65 y la [respuesta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/a/235/65) de @JuanM a http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/definici%C3%B3n-de-la-tem%C3%A1tica-apropiada-para-el-sitio/

Answer (score 5):

Es demasiado pronto. Creo que es una buena idea y que debería ocurrir, pero no todavía.

SO en Español se graduó a mediados de 2017 y las [estadísticas](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810) han mejorado considerablemente desde que estábamos en beta:

- ~35.000 usuarios (550 se consideran muy activos)
- ~30.000 preguntas.
- ~50.000 respuestas.

...pero a pesar de ser buenas, quizás aún no sean lo suficiente para justificar dividir el sitio. Creo que sería mejor esperar, dejar que el sitio crezca (incluso con contenido que por naturaleza debiera pertenecer a otro sitio como programmers), y hacer el *fork* más adelante si los números lo permiten. (< Y esa es la parte importante: cuando la división ocurra, debería dar lugar a dos sitios robustos, y no a uno grande y otro enano que acabe sin soporte y abocado al fracaso.)

Hasta entonces diría que la mejor opción es etiquetar las preguntas que deberían ir a programmers con alguna etiqueta característica (por ejemplo: [programmers](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programmers)) y de esta manera identificar las preguntas que tendrán que migrarse en el futuro.

Konamiman ya escribió en meta [una pregunta con una serie de respuestas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/definici%C3%B3n-de-la-tem%C3%A1tica-apropiada-para-el-sitio) relacionadas con este tema y que podrían ser interesante.

Comment: Se me fue el dedo. Gracias por la corrección :)

Comment: ¿Será pertinente actualizar la respuesta considerando que el sitio ya está graduado?

Comment: @Rubén sin duda sería pertinente. El sitio ha cambiado mucho desde que sólo hubiera 600 preguntas... aunque estoy con el corazón dividido sobre qué poner esta vez, creo que mantendría la idea de dejarlos juntos de momento. Voy a editar la respuesta.

Comment: (: Por cierto, la alternativa de tener dos sitios (o más), uno para cada tema, continua siendo "no posible hasta nuevo aviso".

Answer (score 3):

El alcance de Stack Overflow en español no tiene por qué (y de hecho no está) limitado al que tiene el sitio original en inglés, nosotros no tenemos el lujo de poder abrir sitios adicionales. Concretamente, en Stack Overflow en español son perfectamente aceptables las preguntas conceptuales que en inglés se publicarían en programmers.se.

Comment: ¡Exactamente! Si hay preguntas sobre la programación, base de datos, etc - se pueden preguntar aquí.

Comment: Para que las pongan en espera...

Comment: Ya pasó mucho tiempo, pero no creo que haya crecido tanto el sitio. Todavía se queda corto en comparación con en de inglés, creo que no llega al ni al %5.