# ¿Por qué se cerró la pregunta "Buenas prácticas para usar"? ¿Qué define que realmente se cierre?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, pregunta-específica

La siguiente pregunta: [Buenas prácticas para usar Gitlab](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/25563/227) ha sido cerrada como "se basa principalmente en opiniones". Si bien es cierto que este tipo de preguntas no encaja dentro de las reglas propias de StackOverflow, sí encaja dentro del marco de programmers.stackexchange.com.

NOTA: Se indica el título original de la pregunta en cuestión

Inclusive, existen preguntas similares/relacionadas en inglés: [Gitlab workflow, forcing code review or merge request on branch](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/245610/102805) y [Need help choosing/creating a workflow for web development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/330680/102805) (esta última, recuerdo que hubo una pregunta similar aquí también). Nosotros como comunidad hemos votado para aceptar este tipo de preguntas, revisando las respuestas de [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/227) (la respuesta más votada por la comunidad):

> Preguntas **conceptuales sobre el desarrollo de software (arquitectura, algoritmos, metodologías de desarrollo, ciencias de la computación, licencias de software...)** que en inglés se publicarían en el sitio [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Entonces, quisiera saber, y que decidamos como comunidad, qué deberíamos hacer realmente en estos casos. Dependiendo de las respuestas emitidas aquí y los votos, se decidirá (nuevamente, como comunidad) qué hacer para casos similares.

Nota: No significa que vamos a aceptar todas las preguntas basadas en opiniones, solo aquellas que realmente encajen en el marco de preguntas que hemos aceptado que pueden estar aquí puesto que no existe un sitio en español para programmers y otros, tal como se menciona en la pregunta del meta. Asimismo, sería bueno también definir cuáles respuestas de [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/227) realmente deberíamos considerar como parte del sitio (no necesariamente en esta pregunta, puede abrirse una nueva, a la espera de que algún miembro activo de la comunidad lo realice :D ).

Comment: Yo tampoco entiendo, especialmente porque primero editaron la pregunta y después la pusieron en espera los mismos usuarios.

Comment: Yo creo que esto podria ser un excelente wiki

Comment: La pregunta del primer enlace se encuentra abierta desde el octubre del 2016 pero no tiene respuesta, tiene un balance 2 votos positivos (+4 / -2) y tan sólo 2 comentarios. Esperaba que tuviera más actividad visible.

Answer (score 4):

1. El sitio que antes se llamaba "Programmers" ahora se llama Software Engineering. Referencia [(4 years later) Dear Stack Exchange: can we change our site name?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7935/233431)
2. En [How do I ask a “Best Practices” question?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8221/233431) de Software Engineering se indica que que en lugar de preguntar por la mejor práctica, el OP debe indicar de que significa "**mejor**" para él.

En inglés hay mucha discusiones acerca de preguntas sobre "mejores prácticas". Me parece que deberíamos tener nuestra propia discusión, pero en este caso, en particular la pregunta me parece que el título es demasiado amplio y sin embargo, el cuerpo de la pregunta es mas específico, así que lo siguiente que debería hacerse es editar el título para que concuerde con el cuerpo de la pregunta.

Comment: Al menos 1 persona responde con coherencia el motivo de cierre, que es lo que busco.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza: Acabo de hacer un ajuste.

Comment: Sí lo he visto. Y sigo de acuerdo contigo.

Answer (score 3):

Creo que se cerró por las razones correctas. Con el alcance actual, es una pregunta que genera opiniones. Pero estoy de acuerdo con que se revise, por fin, el alcance y **se ajuste a nuestra realidad**.

Me gustan las preguntas tipo *«mejores prácticas»*, me parecen valiosas porque podemos acumular la experiencia de muchos y el conjunto vale más que las opiniones individuales.

### Propuesta

- Propongo que se acepten las preguntas sobre *«buenas prácticas»*, **una sola vez**, y que se hagan las más comunes lo más pronto posble (lenguajes de programación, por ejemplo).

  Una sola vez, de modo que no se pretenda que existan muchas preguntas sobre el mismo lenguaje (por ejemplo). Cuando alguien haga una pregunta de este tipo, solo tenemos que referirlo a la pregunta correspondiente.

  Debe existir la etiqueta `buenas-practicas`, para que el conjunto esté facilmente accesible en un solo lugar.

  A la larga, la participación del colectivo acrecentará la cantidad y calidad de la lista y cada opinión nueva pasará formará parte de este patrimonio común. También es una posibilidad que se conviertan en wiki o incluso, si existe alguna vez en español, que sean la base de la [documentación](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation).

Comment: "Creo que se cerró por las razones correctas" en realidad esta es la esencia de la pregunta. ¿Cuáles son esas razones correctas? No las veo o no son del todo específicas para mí. Por ello publico la pregunta. Desde el segundo párrafo en adelante, me queda claro el apoyo que esto puede brindar al sitio y a la comunidad.

Comment: Pues el hecho que tu pienses que no se debería haber cerrado y que yo piense que se cerró correctamente ya es un indicativo de «algo». Básicamente porque cualquier respuesta (o casi cualquiera es correcta). No hay una y solo una forma correcta de usar GitLab. Pero si hay opiniones basadas en la experiencia, educación, formación o habilidades. Uno podría decir _«usa git flow»_ y estaría correcto. Yo podría decir _«jamás uses git flow»_ y también estaría correcto. En general, esa es la razón por la que se cerró. Irónicamente, esa es la razón por las que deberíamos aceptar ese tipo de preguntas.

Comment: Yendo a este caso en específico, una respuesta diciendo "usa git flow" no es una respuesta, es un comentario. Una respuesta diciendo "usa git flow porque *foo*, *bar*, *baz* tal como se demuestra aquí y allí y estos son los resultados" me parece mejor. Esto hace que no se base en opiniones sino en hechos que respaldan la hipótesis inicial (el comentario) y lo convierten en una respuesta fundamental. Y no será una discusión, por el contrario, será un compartir de conocimiento empírico documentado y refinado por la comunidad.

Comment: Ahora que lo pienso mejor, parece ser una alternativa a SO Documentation.

Comment: Obvio, puse «usa git flow» solamente porque hay un número limitado de caracteres. Que bueno que lo notaste.

Comment: No he dicho que he entendido por qué está cerrada. Solo pienso que no es una pregunta basada en opiniones y que quisiera saber más al respecto. Ha cambiado mi punto de vista, pero mi pregunta sigue en pie.

Comment: En fin. Cinco personas votaron por que se cerrara y eligieron un motivo para ello (seis, si me cuento, aunque no voté). Y a menos que los llames a rendir cuentas, difícilmente vas a cambiar de opinión porque el motivo existe desde el inicio de SOes y se ha usado cientos y cientos de veces. Sin embargo, coincido que el tema es rescatable y dejo ahí mi propuesta.

Comment: Será una miriada de personas, pero todas siguen sin decir por qué. Eso me parece que causa más daño al sitio, sobretodo a los usuarios nuevos. Yo busco cómo ayudar a estos usuarios y espero que uds los que votan a cierre puedan ayudarme a ayudarlos.

Comment: las "mejores practicas" cambian con el tiempo, no me convence esta idea...  ¿que pasa si el usuario deja de mantener su respuesta? .. la forma es que sean todas estas respuestas sean tipo wiki comunitario pero eso no es obligatorio. (aunque a veces te [obligan](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/352)), sin embargo concuerdo que se puede hallar la forma de aceptar estas preguntas si estan bien formuladas.

Comment: @EmanuelVe Los lenguajes de programación también cambian con el tiempo. Una respuesta de C++ que usase trigrafos no compilaría en un compilador moderno que usase C++17. Cuando sucede alguien pone una nueva respuesta. No es un problema para los lenguajes y tampoco para las buenas prácticas.