# ¿Cuál es el verdadero motivo de cierre para esta pregunta?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas

Durante la moderación, me encontré con esta pregunta cerrada: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/57877/227

La pregunta, si bien no consiste en programación y no está dentro del alcance del sitio, debería ser cerrada. Eso está fuera de discusión. Mi pregunta es: ¿estamos usando adecuadamente la opción de cierre? ¿Esta pregunta que es puntual (y su respuesta también) es realmente "demasiado amplia"?

Vuelvo a insistir (porque [no es la primera vez que pregunto esto](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/916/227)), ¿qué criterios usan para definir si una pregunta realmente es "demasiado amplia" o "basada en opiniones"?

Answer (score 4):

Sobre esta pregunta que mencionas, la pregunta no tiene una respuesta directa pues no existe dicha tecnologia como algo de-facto: "Hey usa el protocolo QWERTY y listo lo tienes resulto". Por otro lado, para explicar como hacer lo que OP quiere, hace falta abordar diferentes conceptos y hay multiples opciones para elegir las tecnologias a usar. Esto quiza se presta a confision...

Yo la votaria como **no esta claro lo que se pregunta** pues me parece que carece de sentido asi como esta. No se sabe bien a que se referie.

Con respecto a lo otro..

> ¿qué criterios usan para definir si una pregunta realmente es "demasiado amplia" o "basada en opiniones"?

Yo utilizo este criterio, aunque admito que algunas veces (pocas) no me cuadra ningún motivo de cierre y suelo usar *demasiado amplia* como opcion generica, por comodidad.

**Demasiado amplia** es la traducción de "too board", veamos:

> *[too](https://translate.google.com.au/#en/es/too)*: to a higher degree than is desirable, permissible, or possible; excessively
>
> *[board](https://translate.google.com/#en/es/broad)*: covering a large number and wide scope of subjects or areas.

Mi traducción libre es que *demasiado amplia* es para preguntas que: ***Cubren un muy amplio numero de asuntos o areas, siendo excesivos. Por lo tanto, no es adecuada para nuestro formato.***

Ejemplo de pregunta: ¿Como puedo hacer una pagina similar a gmail?

**Principalmente basada en opiniones** es la traducción de "primarily opinion-based"

> *[primarily](https://translate.google.com.au/#en/es/primarily)*: for the most part; mainly.
>
> *[opinion](https://translate.google.com.au/#en/es/opinion)*:  a view or judgment formed about something, not necessarily based on fact or knowledge.
>
> *[based](https://translate.google.com.au/#en/es/based)*: have as the foundation for (something); use as a point from which (something) can develop.

Mi traduccion libre es que *Principalmente basada en opiniones* debe usarse cuando: ***La mayor parte de las posibles respuestas tendrán sus fundamentos en el punto de vista o juicio pre-formado sobre algo de quien responde, no necesariamente basado en hechos o conocimiento.***

Ejemplo de pregunta: ¿Que tiene mas futuro Java o C#?