# ¿Es válido hacer preguntas sobre comparación de algo en específico?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, temática

Me gustaría preguntar algo en SOes pero no sé si sea bueno realizar este tipo de preguntas:

Pregunta hipotética:

> ¿Cuál es la mejor forma de acceder a tus archivos .css y .js?
>
> - Forma 1
> - Forma 2

Quisiera saber si es válido hacer preguntas sobre comparaciones entre dos o más cosas que tuvieran que ver con la programación y claro se incluiría código sobre las diferentes formas en las que accedo a mis archivos. Puede que esta pregunta esté sujeta a opiniones personales, lo cual la haría complicado responder correctamente.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

En el momento en el que pones "¿Cual es la mejor forma..." estás sujeto a una pregunta llena de opiniones personales, ya que cada uno puede tener (y tendrá) opiniones distintas.

Creo que sería válida solamente en el caso de que fuera algo muy específico lo que preguntaras. Por ejemplo, cual de las dos formas es más eficiente, reduciendo lo más posible el código de ambas "formas" de realizar el script.

Por supuesto, tendría que ser algo muy concreto como por ejemplo el uso de una función respecto a otra, si un método emplea más tiempo en ejecutarse que otro, etc...

De esta manera, se puede contextualizar mejor basándose en hechos y no en una mera opinión de cada uno.

Answer (score 3):

Es válido hacer preguntas sobre qué es mejor pero debes establecer claramente a qué te refieres con mejor y esto debería centrarse en una dimensión en particular para prevenir que la pregunta sea demasiado amplia. Mas detalles en mi [respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2291/65) a [¿Por qué se cerró esta pregunta? ¿Qué define que realmente se cierre?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/916/65)