# ¿Qué medidas serían eficaces para evitar hacerle los deberes a los vagos?

Tags: discusión, código-de-conducta, trabajo-escolar

No llevo mucho tiempo en esta comunidad, de hecho la descubrí por las invitaciones que hacen por tener otra cuenta en el sitio inglés, pero cuando entré por el mes de octubre observé un nivel de usuario medio y de sus publicaciones mayor a lo que me encuentro ahora diariamente.

Sólo hablo de Java que es la única etiqueta a la que suelo prestar atención, del resto no conozco.

Últimamente además hay como una **especie de competición por responder preguntas incompletas**. Preguntas a las que hay que echarle imaginación para intuir exactamente lo que quiere el OP y el cuál suele demostrar una falta de respeto a su propia publicación con expresiones gramatical y ortográficamente deficientes (no es por no saber, es por no querer perder un minuto), lenguaje extremadamente coloquial (que tal amigos, a ver si pueden solucionarme un problemilla, etc...) y por supuesto con una completa falta de código y exhibicionismo a la hora de demostrar que simplemente se quiere que otro haga su trabajo.

Como seguramente pedirán ejemplos de ello, aquí dejo algunas:

1. [Número al azar y poder usarlo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43285/n%C3%BAmero-al-azar-y-poder-usarlo)
2. [¿Cómo hacer esta consulta en MySQL?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/43549/83)

Estas son sólo las que tengo más recientes de ayer, iré añadiendo más porque son legión.

El caso es que con la herramienta revisar me han llegado publicaciones de baja calidad (respuestas a esas preguntas), pero hay otras exactamente igual y a mí no me han llegado, no sé si otro se habrá encargado de ello, pero desde luego no se trata igual dependiendo de quien revise.

Un moderador en una de ellas [me dijo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43549/c%C3%B3mo-hacer-esta-consulta-mysql/43550?noredirect=1#comment75546_43550) que lo adecuado en vez de poner comentarios es reportar la pregunta. Suelo hacer eso, votar negativo o votar para cerrarla, pero creo que así se seguirá repitiendo ese comportamiento de respuestas compulsivas de perogrullo y primer día de la clase de programación.

Incluso hubo una pregunta cuya solución estaba directamente en la Wikipedia: [JavaScript no es Java, pero ¿por qué el nombre?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42646/javascript-no-es-java-pero-por-qu%c3%a9-el-nombre) y que derivó en una discusión en el chat que básicamente se resumía en dos bandos:

1. Era válida porque hace más de un año [se votó (en este meta)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/definici%c3%b3n-de-la-tem%c3%a1tica-apropiada-para-el-sitio/165#165) que ese tipo de preguntas se podrían hacer.
2. No era válida porque iba en contra de las normas del Centro de Ayuda (no usar la etiqueta historia), no era un problema de programación y tenía -4 votos y había sido cerrada.

Finalmente un moderador la reabrió porque consideraba que el motivo de cierre no era válido y así se ha quedado pues se desconoce cómo se puede cambiar el motivo de cierre y ya no se ha podido cerrar.

Creo que estas historias nos dicen que **hay una falta de normas o de ganas de seguirlas si las hay**, pues muchas veces estas discusiones ocurren entre usuarios con reputación como para conocer ya el sitio.

De todo esto concluyo que las herramientas actuales **reportar** o **hacer una publicación en meta**, no funcionan porque luego se hace poco seguimiento de las preguntas y el usuario no recibe ninguna comunicación.

Sin embargo **un voto positivo o negativo y un comentario diciendo por qué es mucho más directo y sí se puede hacer esa labor necesaria de educar en el modo de utilizar las herramientas de esta comunidad**. Nadie nace aprendido y también yo quiero saber si estoy equivocado.

Hay algunos que prefieren recibir un voto negativo antes que le manden un comentario, otros que manifiestan querer conocer por qué se les ha dado un voto negativo y que no se quede en el anonimato y entre estos últimos los que cuando se le explica también se ofenden.

Independientemente de estos distintos comportamientos, así sí que se aprende, yo lo he hecho y sufrido y es la mejor forma de aprender a usar el sitio. No me considero ningún experto, pero sí que me gusta seguir las normas y tener respeto al trabajo del resto de miembros de la comunidad: **no puede haber preguntas con 4 respuestas iguales**. Eso me parece faltar el respeto al que se molestó en contestar y ahora recibe a modo de spam lo mismo y peor me parece que prácticamente con las mismas respuestas, unas reciban votos negativos y otros positivos, a unas se les comente y a otras no, etc...

Por ello pido disculpas por el ladrillo interminable que me acabo de marcar, pero creo que todo es relevante, no he repetido nada y **es necesario para que el sitio deje de perder calidad (al menos hablo de Java)**. Si has llegado hasta aquí, mi pregunta es:

¿Opináis que la mejor forma de tratar a las preguntas que no están claras o que no tienen ningún trabajo de investigación debe ser cerrarlas como *demasiado amplia*, votarlas en negativo y también votar negativo a los que las respondan añadiendo una observación explicando esto que comento?

En caso contrario dejar una respuesta con vuestra propuesta por favor.

**EDITO:** Añado como claro ejemplo de spamear respuestas sin valor la que me he encontrado hoy acerca de [conceptos básicos de SQL que uno puede encontrar en Internet muy fácilmente](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43735/seleccionar-dos-columnas-con-mismo-nombre-de-dos-tablas-diferentes) y que para mí no se considera un problema de programación sino una falta de investigación o leer tu texto más básico de iniciación.

Por esto considero que ese comportamiento es también premiar al vago y precisamente son las preguntas con mayor spam de respuestas facilonas y repetidas (como veréis he aplicado la misma receta a esos usuarios).

Comment: Has hecho hincapié en un tema crucial y, aunque largo, la publicación no es para nada un ladrillo. Me parece muy bien que estés dejando comentarios. Para las respuestas repetidas yo en [so] suelo votar negativamente y comentar _¿Qué aporta esta respuesta que no hayan dicho las otras ya?_. Para preguntas demasiado genéricas y poco trabajadas es importante también cerrarlas rápido, antes de que los que buscan reputación desesperadamente tengan tiempo de contestar.

Comment: A mí me pareció que la comunidad (tus acciones incluidas) reaccionó bastante bien con tu primer ejemplo, quizás debería haber sido más rápido. No solo les quedó claro a todos los que contestaban, sino que también se logró una excelente edición y [muy buen comentario de respuesta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/43285/n%c3%bamero-al-azar-y-poder-usarlo#comment75276_43287) en un caso... Pero tu tercer caso me parece que no está relacionado con lo que venías hablando, es un tema que recomendaría para una publicación diferente.

Comment: Sí, estoy de acuerdo con @Mariano. Lo de _no puede haber preguntas con 4 respuestas iguales_ es harina de otro costal y que encajaría mejor en una discusión aparte.

Comment: Creo que no se reaccionó completamente bien @Mariano . Claramente no tiene **ningún trabajo de investigación** e indica que **es para un trabajo y no ha dejado nada de lo que ha intentado**. Además todas las respuestas hacen conjeturas para rellenar los vacíos de la pregunta. Por eso lo que propongo (al margen de que la respuesta sea una solución a lo que nos _imaginamos_ que querría el OP), es que todas las preguntas tipo _"dame el código para lo que digo porque yo no me voy a molestar y para eso está este sitio"_ no tengan ninguna respuesta o se las vote negativamente/comente si la tienen.

Comment: No reportaste la segunda pregunta :( pero no te preocupes, ya la borré. No es lo mismo votar a cierre/comentar que reportar. En el reporte puedes indicar que esta pregunta es un mal ejemplo para el sitio y que ha recibido respuestas. Si no notamos cambios en la estructura de la pregunta, será borrada para evitar 1) tener este tipo de preguntas en el sitio que dan mala impresión de lo que se acepta, 2) que quienes responden este tipo de preguntas vean que necesitan revisar qué están respondiendo.

Comment: Asímismo, considero que siempre debemos dar oportunidad al OP a replantear su pregunta para que sea aceptable para el sitio.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n estoy totalmente de acuerdo con lo que estás diciendo del [primer caso](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/43285/127). Me refería a que la comunidad reaccionó bien porque se comentó en todas las respuestas, se votó -1 (particularmente a los de mayor reputación), pero no abusivamente, y se cerró la pregunta (que podría haber sido antes, pero no estuvo tan mal). Si te fijas, quienes respondieron son usuarios nuevos (o relativamente nuevos), y no podemos pretender que estén familiarizados con el sitio, por eso creo que fue una buena reacción para explicarles los motivos.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n de la misma forma, este comportamiento no creo que sea lo mismo que el [tercer caso](http://es.stackoverflow.com/q/42646/127) que estás citando, donde hubo interacción con el autor, e incluso el mismo autor terminó publicando [una respuesta que suma valor](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/42676/127), por eso es que creo que era material para una publicación diferente (en breve, ahí yo creo que está bien la pregunta).

Comment: Independientemente de las opiniones de los comentarios y que coincido que podrían dar lugar a otras discusiones, me gustaría que no se perdiera de vista la pregunta. _¿Qué medidas serían eficaces para evitar hacerle los deberes a los vagos?_ **¿Os parece bien la que propongo?** ¿Tenéis otras alternativas?

Comment: @Awes0meM4n en mi caso, cuando son usuarios que conocen el funcionamiento del sitio y hacen ese tipo de preguntas doy downvote, si son nuevos, voto para cerrar y hago una recomendación al usuario. Por parte de los que responden solo por ganar puntos con respuestas que ni siquiera responden a la supuesta pregunta tambien doy downvote para penalizar el comportamiento

Comment: @Awes0meM4n: Considero que el contenido de la pregunta es de valor alto pero que tiene problemas de estructura y concordancia, ya que el título dice una cosa pera la narrativa lleva al lector hacia otra dirección. Si tuviera el privilegio de edición haría lo siguiente:  Dividir el contenido en secciones y utilizar títulos a cada una de ellas. En primera instancia pondría tres secciones introducción, desarrollo y conclusión. En **desarrollo**, la sección intermedia, quedaría tal cual el contenido de la revisión actual. En **introducción**, la primer sección, ...

Comment: ... pondría la intención de la publicación y una "advertencia" de lo que el lector encontrará en el desarrollo. En la **conclusión**, la última sección, volvería poner las intenciones, pero usando otras palabras, en primer instancia como lo has hecho en tu [comentario mas reciente](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1283/qu%c3%a9-medidas-ser%c3%adan-eficaces-para-evitar-hacerle-los-deberes-a-los-vagos?cb=1#comment3334_1283). Luego leería todo y haría los ajustes pertinentes poniendo especial atención a los títulos (introducción, desarrollo y conclusión me parecen muy aburridos)

Comment: @Rubén siéntete libre de editarla como quieras. La he abierto yo, pero es para abrir una discusión para ver la mejor forma de atajar un problema que va en alza en contra de la calidad del sitio.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n : lo que pasa es que no tengo el privilegio aún ya que me falta reputación.... ya se resolverá :)

Comment: Quizá se trate de una especie de microcosmos, donde la pregunta del vago sea el disparador de un mecanismo onanista. Puedes darte una vuelta por el área del C++, donde es común ver una pregunta lanzada por un vago semi analfabeto, que es editada varias veces hasta darle una forma más o menos pasable (o ni siquiera), para después recibir dos o tres respuestas, medianamente esmeradas, hay que decirlo, y que recogen autopuntos y comentarios. Curiosamente, una pregunta de esas puede tener unas 10 visitas, tres ediciones y tres respuestas, lo que califica para mí de onanismo de paro.

Answer (score 4):

## Respuesta corta

> ¿Opináis que la mejor forma de tratar a las preguntas que no están claras o que no tienen ningún trabajo de investigación debe ser cerrarlas como demasiado amplia, votarlas en negativo y también votar negativo a los que las respondan añadiendo una observación explicando esto que comento?

En mi opinión "no hay una mejor forma" que sea atemporal y universal. Cada caso debería analizarse por separado.

## Respuesta extensa

> NOTA del autor: Esta publicación es "WIP" (siglas en inglés de trabajo en progreso).

### Prólogo

Los interesados en este sitio tenemos grandes retos:

1. Atraer más usuarios

   - Los que sólo leen también cuentan :)
   - Los que no conocen Stack Exchange podrían batallar al principio y eventualmente convertirse en miembros notables.
2. Atraer más autores

   - Son quienes aportan las "semillas" (una pregunta o respuesta de da pie a conversaciones significativas) y en ocasiones "bosques completos" (una serie de publicaciones diversa que va desde comentarios breves, mensajes ocasionales en el chat hasta preguntas/respuestas "épicas", que no sólo los ha hecho ganadores de medallas sino que han sido citados fuera del sitio.

Para lo anterior es indispensable [comportarse bien](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators), en general seguir los [lineamientos de conducta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) y si no te gustan comentarlos en Meta.

A continuación algunas sugerencias de pautas para decidir cómo moderar las preguntas en el sitio principal

> Nota del autor: "luego" habrá que contrastar con [¿quienes son los moderadores y cuál es su cometido?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/site-moderators)

### Pautas

#### ¿Hace cuanto tiempo se publicó la pregunta?

Si es muy reciente, el OP podría estar en línea y ver un comentario en la misma sesión, por lo que las posibilidades de que el propio autor asimile e implemente la orientación que le podamos dar de forma inmediata son altas, lo he visto muchas veces. En algunos casos, un comentario no es suficiente y la interacción entre ambas partes se extiende. Afortunadamente el sistema está atento y sugerirá pasar a una sesión de chat cuando se cumplan ciertas condiciones.

Si no es muy reciente, pasar al punto siguiente:

#### ¿Qué historial tiene el autor?

Si el OP tiene una reputación muy baja (menor o igual a 20) y ninguna medalla asumamos que no sabe nada de las políticas del sitio y seamos pacientes. Aquí aplica lo mismo del punto anterior, sólo incorporamos un poco de paciencia para darle oportunidad al OP de leer las políticas del sitio y corregir

Si tiene las medallas básica, como la de haber realizado el recorrido y alguna otra, y además cuenta con poca reputación (menos de 100), podemos ser un poco más estrictos.

Si tiene mas de 100 y/o otras medallas o si tiene varias preguntas, digamos más de 3, apliquemos las políticas estrictamente, incluyendo la de ser cordiales.