# ¡Por favor, una linea clara ya de una vez como actuar en SO!

Tags: discusión, usuarios-nuevos, código-de-conducta

Esto ya es cansino, de ver usuarios que quieren cambiar las normas del sitio una y otra vez.

Yo ya casi ni reviso ni nada porque muchos se molestan o te dicen cualquier tontería...

Luego las preguntas o dudas que si negamos la ayuda a los nuevos etc etc..

Venga ya...!

NO - pero hay ciertas normas que todos tenemos que seguir y si los nuevos no hacen el recorrido o no hacen un mínimo de esfuerzo, tenemos nosotros la culpa?

Entonces no atacar o acosar a los que revisan solo porque toman su tiempo de decidir si el contenido es valioso para el sitio o no!

Todos hemos empezado de 0 pero no conviertan esto en un guardería!

Pido por favor de una vez una linea clara, o mejor dicho el requisito mínimo de:

- Como comportarse
- Las preguntas/respuestas permitidas
- Y hasta que punto esta permitido tratar a los nuevos usuarios como críos

Comment: Suscribo la petición, esto se está llenando de quejas que intentan generalizar situaciones particulares. Aunque las reglas deberían ser suficiente... mejor es dejar pasar, dejar hacer.

Comment: Tengo algo claro y eso es, no tratar a los usuarios como tú. No puedes imponer, qué te crees? Que sea estresante para ti, no significa que afecte a toda la comunidad en general, si tanto quieres *no ser niñera*, entonces simplemente no aportes y ya. Es *jarto* que la gente ayude y luego parece que cobra por ayudar. Si no quieres revisar, pues no revises, que eso no hará que StackOverflow se caiga o se desactive. Nuevo es nuevo, y eso siempre será así. Si tomas ese comportamiento con un usuario nuevo estás violando las politicas de StackOverflow. Criticar a millon, y sin siquiera saber.

Comment: @MáximaAlekz - (Creo que)... no haz entendido nada...

Comment: *...y si los nuevos no hacen el recorrido o no hacen un mínimo de esfuerzo, tenemos nosotros la culpa?...* Hay diferentes formas de pensar. Si el nuevo, sabe muy poco sobre lo que pregunta y no logra darse a entender correctamente, entonces está obligado a capacitarse en el tema y luego si volver para preguntar? Suena ilógico y entonces así no habrían politicas que defiendan a los usuarios nuevos. Yo llevo un tiempo en el sitio, aún me siento tan nuevo como uno que apenas tiene 1 punto de reputación. Lo de *cómo comportarse* siempre será relativo. No hay nada fijo.

Comment: En lo posible, si yo quiero hacer el aporte, trato de la mejor forma porque así también quiero que me traten. Y por precisamente eso, porque estoy dando una *ayuda*, no me están obligando a aportar o responder las preguntas, no estoy contratado ni nada de eso. Es 100% opcional que quieras aportar o no. Entonces no veo lugar a tu *pregunta/queja*

Comment: @MáximaAlekz - Bueno... no se cuando tiempo ya estás en esta comunidad... pero este post lo hice porque hubo algunos usuarios que se molestaron mucho (muchísimo) que se le revisaran... hubo insultos ... ataques verbales etc... entonces hice ese post para desahogarme... yo sería el último en este planeta de no ayudar.. sea quien sea...

Comment: Vale, está bien. Aunque debes admitir que la tonada que sobresale en tu post es algo elevada. Y yo, por lo general *soy más defensa que ataque*

Comment: @MáximaAlekz - Si.. lo admito... pero hay 2 motivos... 1. Hubo un usuario “nuevo” que puso un post en meta poniendo a un compañero verde y a mi en SOes ... 2. Mi idioma nativo es alemán, entonces me expreso de tal manera que a veces (o más) haya un malentendido y/o ni se me entienda lo que realmente quiero decir... pero siempre intento de ser lo más claro posible... en ese sentido pido disculpas sí alguien se lo toma esto personal...

Comment: Vale, también me disculpo. Lo que sucede es que como nuevo, yo también *me paro* y doy mi punto de vista, además de denfenderlo. :)

Answer (score 10):

### Cómo comportarse

Es obvio cuál es la relación que debemos tener con todos los miembros de la comunidad, los comentarios y la relación debe estar cimentada siempre  en la cordialidad y el respeto.

Mi propuesta es simple: **Cuando exista alguna inconformidad entre una o más personas realicemos un [chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=es.stackoverflow.com) y ahí podremos externar nuestra ideas o inconformidades directamente.**

### Las preguntas/respuestas permitidas

Las reglas del juego están definidas. Entendemos que no debemos ser tan rígidos o estrictos con los nuevos usuarios, pero hay que ayudar e indicar cómo podrían realizar una pregunta o respuesta.

Sin embargo últimamente existen preguntas que fueron reabiertas o [están en ese proceso, podrían considerarse buenas](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26313/consulta-sobre-desarrollar-una-ia-inteligencia-artificial) pero desgraciadamente son demasiado amplias o basadas en comentarios.

> Existen muchas respuestas posibles, o las buenas respuestas son
> demasiado extensas para este formato. Añade detalles para reducir el
> conjunto de respuestas o separar un problema que se puede responder en
> pocos párrafos.

Recordemos que no somos un foro sino un sitio donde se puede preguntar y responder preguntas relacionadas a la informática. No hay que reinventar la rueda, sigamos las reglas.

> **Cómo preguntar**
>
> ¿Tu pregunta es sobre programación?
>
> **Preferimos preguntas que pueden ser respondidas, no simplemente
> debatidas.**

Alguna vez se comentó que el sitio se estaba convirtiendo en un foro, lo cual no deseamos. Hay que ser especifico/a al preguntar y responder.

### Hasta qué punto está permitido tratar a los nuevos usuarios como principiantes

Como usuarios nuevos, hay que indicarles primeramente cómo realizar su pregunta o respuesta. Los usuarios nuevos al ver que no obtienen la información, pueden cambiar sus hábitos y entender cómo funciona el sitio.

> Les comparto mi experiencia: recuerdo mi primer acercamiento con
> [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/250260/jorgesys), formulé 2 preguntas, ambas fueron cerradas, me moleste tanto
> que entré nuevamente después de meses, [leí](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) cual era la forma adecuada para realizar preguntas y como trabaja el sitio, al final obtuve la ayuda requerida!.

Si los usuarios agregan preguntas o respuestas simplemente hay que apoyar a los [moderadores](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) con nuestros reportes, cierre de preguntas, edición, etc, necesarios para que se modere de una forma adecuada el sitio. Después de todo, este sitio lo moderamos todos.

Comment: El enlace [están en proceso...](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26313/consulta-sobre-desarrollar-una-ia-inteligencia-artificial) devuelve error 404.

Comment: Not found? que raro Rubén, yo si lo veo http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/26313/consulta-sobre-desarrollar-una-ia-inteligencia-artificial , será cuestión de privilegios? =|

Comment: Es lo más probable. Tu tienes muchos más que yo :)

Comment: Cuando un usuario de la red stackoverflow no está conforme con una respuesta lo que hace es votar negativo y, preferiblemente, poner un comentario explicando el error que hay en su opinión. El sitio está diseñado para ser usado así. Esto contribuye a mejorar la calidad de las respuestas. @Ruben Esa pregunta está borrada, necesitas 2000 de reputación para poder verla. O que otras 3 personas (con Rep 2000+) voten para restaurarla. En inglés hay [preguntas cerradas que se consideran muy útiles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Gracias. La pregunta referida tiene un tipo especial de cierre, está "locked" en contraste con otras que el término usado es "closed".

Answer (score 7):

## ¡Por favor, paciencia!

SOes se encuentra en fase Beta Pública, en síntesis, el sitio debe demostrar que puede atraer a suficientes usuarios sin afectar a otros sitios de la red. Se requieren usuarios expertos pero también usuarios nuevos.

Por la naturaleza del sitio, esta fase está tomando tiempo, el cual podemos a aprovechar revisar, por ejemplo, el asunto toral de esta pregunta, **cómo actuar** y lo que concluyamos documentarlo de la mejor forma para que quienes se integren puedan saber que es lo que se espera al respecto.

> Como comportarse

El punto de partida es "[Comportarse bien](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice)". El artículo no está escrito en piedra, podemos proponer mejoras al mismo, pero la idea central es que seamos **respetuosos, corteses y con los nuevos, además pacientes**.

Esto es muy complicado porque cada uno tiene experiencias de vida y posturas diferentes. Lo importante es que podamos tratar nuestras diferencias de forma civilizada, aceptando nuestra diversidad al tiempo que mantenemos el rumbo de este sitio en la dirección correcta.

> Las preguntas/respuestas permitidas

Los temas sobre los que [se puede preguntar aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice), en términos generales son sobre programación. Las propuestas específicas se publicaron y votaron en [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/definici%C3%B3n-de-la-tem%C3%A1tica-apropiada-para-el-sitio). Este hilo no se ha cerrado, así que entiendo que el tema sigue abierto.

> Y hasta que punto esta permitido tratar a los nuevos usuarios como críos

Sobre cómo tratar a las personas, no debe importar la edad, el grado de habilidad sobre temas de programación ni grado en el que conocen como funciona el sitio. Con todos nos debemos **comportar bien**. En diversos espacios y formas se ha sugerido que **seamos especialmente pacientes con los nuevos**, pues es usual que los usuarios que aún no están familiarizados con la forma de trabajar del sitio se sientan ofendidos cuando sus publicaciones reciben votos negativos o de cierre **"demasiado pronto"**.

## Mis sugerencias

- Cuando vayas al sitio principal, revisa primero [Sin respuesta > no hay respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers)

  - Hay 2,481 preguntas sin respuesta.
- En publicaciones de nuevos usuarios,

  - Espera unos días antes de votar negativamente o de cierre, digamos una semana a partir de la fecha de la publicación de la revisión 1.
  - Si te gusta publicar comentarios, publica un comentario, en especial cuando la publicación del nuevo usuario podría recibir votos negativos y/o de cierre.

Answer (score 2):

> Las preguntas/respuestas permitidas

Ya hay una encuesta oficial (Konamiman era moderador cuando lo abrió) al respecto:
[Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/definici%C3%B3n-de-la-tem%C3%A1tica-apropiada-para-el-sitio)

Sería bueno convertir esa encuesta oficial en lo que adanux llama "Una línea clara"
Porque aldanux tiene razón en que hace falta una línea clara. En un sentido u otro, el que sea. La falta de una definición clara de la temática del sitio es mala. Y esto es más importante que las estadísticas de Area 51, ¿quién va a graduar un sitio del que no está definida la temática?

> Como comportarse

Aquí yo creo que es suficiente con lo que hay en el centro de ayuda. No hacen falta más normas o líneas.
Lo que hace falta es moderadores que actuen.
Lo cual significa que probablemente hace falta más moderadores.

> Y hasta que punto esta permitido tratar a los nuevos usuarios como críos

Entiendo que te refieres a dos cosas :

1. **Dar el pez en vez de enseñar a pescar.** Pienso que no es bueno. Nos lleva a atraer usuarios "vampiros" que no aportan nada y cuyas preguntas tampoco van a ser muy interesantes. Sin embargo, tengan en cuenta que incluso una pregunta tan sencila como "¿Como hago un Hola Mundo en C++?" puede ser respondida sin entregar el pez. Si alguien quiere poner ese tipo de respuesta en que se enseña cómo resolver la pregunta pero sin poner un bloque copiable/pegable no hay porqué poner trabas.
2. **Ser más tolerantes con los errores de los nuevos.** Simpre habrá opiniones diferentes. Es normal cansarse de ver cientos de veces los mismos errores y se te quitan las ganas de explicar cómo usar el sitio. ¿Si ellos no se toman la molestia, por qué tendrías que hacerlo tu por ellos? Este tema [sigue candente en el sitio inglés](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late) muchos años despues de su inicio. Durará tanto como la especie humana probablemente. Posiblemente no haya solución definitiva. Pero sí que podría aliviarse con una línea clara por ejemplo en la temática del sitio. Así no nos encontraríamos con discusiones sobre si hay o no que cerrar una pregunta sobre un error con el router.

Comment: El hilo enlazado en "[sigue candente..."](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251758/why-is-stack-overflow-so-negative-of-late) incluye los dos estados que mencioné en mi [comentario](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1475/por-favor-una-linea-clara-ya-de-una-vez-como-actuar-en-so/1482?noredirect=1#comment4179_1482)