# Error al asignar medalla Birrete

Tags: soporte, reputación, medallas

El día de hoy (ayer, en horario UTC) , las notificaciones de logros muestran que "gané" la medalla Birrete, la cual es para quienes *en un día ganan 200 de reputación*, pero el día de hoy no he logrado dicho incremento en reputación. Lo logré el día 13 de febrero y ese día se me asignó la medalla en cuestión.

[image]

La "confusión", como [le llama fedorqui](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1498/65), viene de

1. la reputación que se muestra en meta es la ganada en el sitio principal
2. en meta no se otorga reputación
3. en el perfil de usuario no hay una forma de ver de forma agregada los votos recibidos por día

En [SEDE](http://data.stackexchange.com/) sería posible revisarlo, pero los datos se actualizaron hace dos días, así que habría que esperar 5 días a que se vuelvan a actualizar. Tal vez sirvan queries como los siguientes:

- http://data.stackexchange.com/esme/query/300328/mortarboard-and-more
- http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/165993/reputation-history-accurate-including-everything-except-bounties .

Comment: Estás respondiendo a mi respuesta en tu pregunta :O jaja

Comment: ¿Acaso se puede hacer de otra forma? :)

Comment: A mis ojos, estás repitiendo lo que indicaba en mi respuesta, por lo que no creo que sea necesario volver a escribirlo. Siéntete libre de editar mi respuesta si ves algo mejorable. Al fin y al cabo, la zona de preguntas es donde surge la duda y la de respuestas donde surge la solución :D

Comment: Ya que hablamos de ojos, a los míos, este hilo sigue siendo un reporte de bug, mas que de soporte, pero creo que conviene mas que se queden así las etiquetas mientras se recaba mayor información y "aclaro mis ideas" :D

Comment: Sin problema Rubén, esperemos unos días para confirmar con SEDE.

Comment: Como mencioné en mi comentario a la respuesta, no hubo sorpresas, así que me parece que la meta-etiqueta soporte sí es la correcta. Me tomé la libertad de agregar "la evidencia" a la respuesta. Por el momento creo que la pregunta se puede quedar así como está, y dejar para otro hilo el solicitar que se modifique la descripción de la medalla birrete, si es que esto no se ha discutido en [meta.se] u otro espacio similar.

Comment: @Mariano tal y como acabo de mencionar en [la pregunta al respecto](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1887/83), no es necesario crear la etiqueta [meta-tag:badges] para poder crear su sinónimo por parte de un moderador. Acabo de hacer la prueba en [meta.spanish.se] y funcionó sin problema: https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/synonyms?tab=synonym&filter=all

Comment: @Mariano como decías en algún lugar (no guardo tan bien las referencias como tú jejeje :D), estas etiquetas predeterminadas son un caso especial. En general sí es cierto que no se recomienda crear una etiqueta artificialmente para marcarla como sinónimo. Ahora bien, lo bueno del caso es que estas ya existen en alguna parte, hardcodeadas... Por tanto, no es necesario hacer nada, solamente esperar a un moderador con un rato libre.

Comment: @fedorqui: ¿conoces a un moderador con un rato libre?

Comment: @Rubén en este sitio no :/ Pero a la que haya elecciones y moderadores nuevos y con ganas de aprender cosas nuevas, seguro que sí los habrá :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[En Meta, la medalla Birrete también se puede ganar](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78603/209901). Aunque no tenga mucho sentido porque en Meta no hay reputación *per se*, esto es así "por diseño".

En el caso que nos ocupa, tú obtuviste ayer el equivalente a 200 puntos de reputación en Meta (véase anexo), de ahí que [se te otorgara la medalla aquí](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard?userid=65), en Meta. No se puede ver de dónde salieron esos votos, pero sí veo que publicaste dos respuestas ([1](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1483/83) y [2](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1491/83)) que ahora mismo cuentan con 7 votos entre ambas ([véase la línea de tiempo de una de ellas](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/1491/timeline)), así como [una pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1484/83) con 2 votos. Todo esto suma 80 puntos y faltarían 120 más, que te llegarían de aquí y de allá.

Supongo que la confusión viene del hecho que [hace pocos días, el 13 de febrero, la ganaras en el sitio principal](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/41/mortarboard?userid=65).

*Anexos*

De http://data.stackexchange.com/esme/query/300328/mortarboard-and-more?uid=65 luego que se actualizaron los datos:

[image: Resultado de query]

Comment: Gracias fedorqui. La confusión viene de la descripción de la medalla y porque no pensé que mis publicaciones en meta hubiesen recibido los votos para ganar "reputación virtual", por llamarle de alguna forma. Creo que para salir de dudas habrá que esperar unos días a que se actualicen los datos en SEDE. Tal vez queries como http://data.stackexchange.com/esme/query/300328/mortarboard-and-more o http://data.stackexchange.com/es/query/165993/reputation-history-accurate-including-everything-except-bounties sirvan.

Comment: No creo que haya sorpresas, pero sí, esperemos.

Comment: Pues no hubo sorpresas :)