# Es necesario incluir código en una buena respuesta?

Tags: discusión, respuesta

A raiz de [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/63514/15301), el amigo @Jorgesys y yo tuvimos un intercambio de opiniones sobre la calidad de mi respuesta a la misma. En su opinion,era una respuesta teorica y por tanto de mala calidad. Mi opinion es que mi respuesta daba todas las indicaciones necesarias para resolver el problema,que a mi parecer era demasiado extenso para añadir un extracto de código que realizara todo lo que el OP requería.

Me gustaría saber la opinión de la comunidad para,en caso de estar yo equivocado,no volver a cometer el mismo error. Es necesario e incluso obligatorio añadir código en una buena respuesta?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### NO

En el sitio se define cómo hacer una buena respuesta en : [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Hay muchas recomendaciones y guías, pero en ningún momento se menciona el código.

El código es una herramienta. Solo eso. Cuando la herramienta sirve a tu propósito, que en este caso es responder a una pregunta, usa esa herramienta. Pero hay muchas otras herramientas. Usa la que consideres más apropiada en cada ocasión.

Comment: De hecho lo que si se menciona es el no publicar **solo** codigo. lo importante es la explicacion, el codigo es un apoyo ^^

Answer (score 3):

Respuesta corta:

## Depende

## Explicación

Si bien este sitio en principio es sobre programación, en [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/65) se han propuesto temas en los que podría nos ser útil incluir código tales como:

- [Preguntas conceptuales sobre desarrollo de software](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/163/65)
- [Historia del desarrollo de software,...](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/165/65)
- [Gestión de servidores, ...](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/166/65)

Punto y a parte de lo anterior, en mi opinión, una buena respuesta no tiene que incluir líneas de código completas e inclusive podrían no incluir menciones a comandos, pero esto depende de la naturaleza de la pregunta, sin embargo, lo usual es que las buenas respuestas incluyan código.

Por otro lado, los votantes pueden discrepar del autor en cuanto a la utilidad/calidad de una respuesta e incluso podrían decidir su voto en cuanto a la utilidad del código incluido o la falta de este. En cualquier caso, si alguno vota negativo, es recomendable que indique las razones o de sugerencias sobre cómo mejorar la respuesta.

Comment: Por supuesto que cada usuario es libre de discrepar y valorar tanto positiva como negativamente de acuerdo a su criterio. Quiero aclaran que mi pregunta no esta motivada por una puntuación negativa (si alguien ve mi historial tanto es stackoverflow en ingles como en español creo que puede apreciar que no es la reputación lo que me mueve), si no por aclarar si mi criterio en este caso y para otros sucesivos es correcto. Gracias por tu respuesta