# ¿En que casos es aceptable una pregunta sin código?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, temática

Que pasaría si tengo un problema que no esta relacionado a un código especifico, pero esta indirectamente relacionado con programación, si lo que es busco es una buena practica para resolver un problema mas general y que otros pueden reproducir.

He visto preguntas más antiguas que sin tener código fueron aceptadas y respondidas (incluso algunas que preguntaban por código), pero se que las normas actuales exigen que se publique código que demuestre haber intentado resolver el problema antes de recibir una respuesta. Debido a eso muchas veces las preguntas sin código son relegadas por la comunidad, sin embargo otras son bien aceptadas, recientemente he visto un par de casos:

[¿Para qué sirve el NaN?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/275806/para-qu%c3%a9-sirve-el-nan)

[¿Qué diferencias hay entre callbacks, promises y async/await?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/277690/qu%c3%a9-diferencias-hay-entre-callbacks-promises-y-async-await)

Revisando el centro de ayuda en [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) no encontré mucha información al respecto y revisando [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) dice:

> si tu pregunta es acerca de…
>
> - un problema específico de programación, o
> - un algoritmo de software, o
> - herramientas de software comúnmente utilizadas por programadores; y es
> - un problema práctico, que tiene respuesta y único al desarrollo    de software
>
> … ¡entonces estás en el lugar correcto para preguntar!

Pero creo que no es tan especifico respecto a los alcances y límites de lo que se puede preguntar.

En resumen **¿Qué características debe tener una pregunta sin código para ser bien recibida?**

Preguntas relacionadas:

[¿Qué hacemos con el incremento de preguntas que piden código sin haber intentado?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2840/qu%c3%a9-hacemos-con-el-incremento-de-preguntas-que-piden-c%c3%b3digo-sin-haber-intentado)

[Es necesario incluir código en una buena respuesta?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1782/es-necesario-incluir-c%c3%b3digo-en-una-buena-respuesta)

Comment: Consejo: Lee la orientación de uso de la etiqueta (tag excerpt) y si aún no está del todo claro, el wiki de etiqueta.

Comment: Relacionado [¿Cómo hacer este tipo de preguntas?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3638/65)

Comment: de hecho tengo muchas preguntas asi, mi solucion agarro el numero en el chat y espero que me atiendan, el problema es que los nuevos usuarios no tienen ese privilegio

Comment: @JackNavaRow no creo que sea una buena opción, de esa forma la pregunta no es publica y otros usuarios con el mismo problema no podrían beneficiarse de la solución.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sí, las preguntas sin código son aceptables siempre y cuando estén dentro de la temática del sitio.

Sin embargo, es cierto que algunos moderadores, entiéndase usuarios con privilegios para comentar, votar y votar para cerrar preguntas son los que "exigen" que todas las preguntas que pasan por sus ojos tengan código aún y cuando las guías de uso y temática del sitio no lo requieran. Tengo la impresión que en algunas etiquetas esto es más patente que en otras pero no podría dar ejemplos.

Sobre las características específicas de las preguntas sin código me parece que es mejor discutir cada caso en particular. Puedes usar la etiqueta [revisión-de-pregunta](/questions/tagged/revisi%c3%b3n-de-pregunta) para publicar aquí en Meta la pregunta que tengas duda que sea bien recibida en el sitio principal, sólo incluye en el cuerpo de la pregunta que estás pidiendo orientación sobre cómo deberías hacer la publicación de esa pregunta en específico.

Ejemplo de pregunta sin código dentro de la temática del sitio

- ["node"" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/136407/65)

Comment: Espero que el tipo de usuario que pide código por todo no sea mayoritario, pues si esa es la tendencia acabaremos con un conjunto inmenso de pregunta super concretas que difícilmente ayudarán a los visitantes del futuro. Qué mejor que preguntas que sirvan de referencia, con independencia del código específico del usuario.

Comment: @fedorqui Si mal no recuerdo Nicolas hizo una campaña para preguntas sobre algoritmos pero no si hubo preguntas de esta campaña sin código. Creo tener campañas orientadas a preguntas sin código sería muy útil para reforzar el que tengamos preguntas de este tipo que sirvan de referencia.

Comment: De acuerdo, pero el punto era ¿que hago si quiero hacer una pregunta de ese tipo? ¿Cómo puedo saber si lo que voy a preguntar es aceptable o no?

Comment: @the-breaker y la respuesta breve es publica la pregunta  aquí en meta con la etiqueta [meta-tag:revisión-de-pregunta] incluyendo en el cuerpo de la pregunta que estas buscando orientación de cómo hacer esa pregunta en específico.

Comment: @the-breaker Otra opción es que seas valiente y hagas la pregunta en el sitio principal y ya veremos que pasa. Supongo que lo peor que podría pasar es que te lluevan votos negativos pero que tengas una respuesta con votos positivos que te impida borrarla directamente, pero si fuera una respuesta que te fuera útil no sería tan malo ¿no?

Comment: @Rubén bueno, en ese caso tendría que publicar la pregunta aquí, no se si otros usuarios ya lo han hecho, pero parece la mejor opción por el momento.

Answer (score 5):

La mayoría de las preguntas que se hacen en este sitio son para resolver dudas:

- Tengo **este código** y algo falla... (se necesita el código, a ser posible debería tener todo el código para reproducir el escenario).
- Quiero hacer cierta funcionalidad pero me he atascado aquí (`ver código`), a ver si alguien me ilumina...

Pero hay veces que las preguntas no requieren código, por ejemplo algo como:

- He hecho un *merge* en mi repositorio Git pero me he arrepentido, ¿puedo volver atrás?.
- He ejecutado `npm install` y tengo varios mensajes de error que no están relacionados con mi código.
- ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre los patrones de diseño Factory y Builder?
- Al ejecutar el IDE XXXX recién instalado sobre el SO YYY me sale un error (se añade captura de pantalla).

Son preguntas válidas sobre herramientas o conceptos relacionados con el desarrollo, pero no hay código sobre el que sea necesario trabajar.

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, los ejemplos ayudan a comprender mejor los alcances que pueden tener las preguntas.