# Preguntas de revision de codigo (dudas)

Tags: discusión

Bien partiendo de que este tipo de preguntas son premitidas ver [aqui](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/definici%C3%B3n-de-la-tem%C3%A1tica-apropiada-para-el-sitio/235#164). Mi pregunta es la siguiente, *pero siempre teniendo en cuenta que quizas muchos usuarios no saben que son permitidas en SOes*, o porque vengan de SOen, donde no son premitidas pues cuentan con un lugar para ello en su idioma, y las voten para cerrar ect.

Dicho lo anterior mi duda surge cuando se cierran por:

> se basa principalmente en opiniones

segun leo esto tiene sentido pues las preguntas de revision de codigo son un poco diferentes al resto de pregunta que se publican es SOes, pues una revision de codigo pienso implica opinion de como hacer algo de otra manera, ya sea mas eficiente mas claro de leer de escalar ect.

Con lo cual esta muy relacionado con las opiniones (y por su puesto conocimientos) sobre la materia, y los votos serian tambien por ese camino pensando "opinando" que tal o cual respuesta es mejor o pero por x motivos.

Espero haberme explicado bien, tiene sentido el cierre basado en opiniones, si, pero quizas se deberia de matizar, este tipo de cierres en preguntas del tipo revicion de codigo por lo mencionado anteriormente.

P.D: porque pienso que eliminar esta opcion de cierre para este tipo de preguntas seria mas complicado de implemetar, pues se tendria que tener en cuenta el tag, que tiene por ejemplo y quizas esto no sea prioritario si mi percepcion expuesta es compartida.

Comment: @fedorqui hice algun cambio siento no poder hacerlo mejor. Saludos

Answer (score 6):

Yo creo que si alguien presenta un código que no sea excesivamente extenso y que el mismo sea completo no debería estar mal visto pedir otros puntos de vista.

Al final de este tipo de preguntas se puede aprender bastante viendo como diferentes personas presentan mejoras más o menos curiosas, ingeniosas o se fijan en detalles que para servidor pasan desapercibidos.

Al fin y al cabo no hay que olvidar que quien sabe programar tira más de experiencia que de teoría e incluso suele ser habitual que al tener cierto nivel sientas curiosidad por ver cómo se han resuelto ciertos problemas en programas de código abierto... cuando descubres en ese código soluciones ingeniosas o interesantes no suele ser descabellado copiarlas una vez has conseguido entenderlas.

Asi pues al menos yo no veo con malos ojos este tipo de preguntas.

Otra situación muy diferente sería que se presente una función insulsa o un código incompleto. Quizás haya que analizar cada caso de forma independiente para decidir si las aportaciones realizadas pueden ser interesantes.

Comment: gracias por contestar, me parce muy acertada su respuesta, y me gusto esta parte *sientas curiosidad por ver cómo se han resuelto ciertos problemas* pienso que ver codigo de otros ayuda mucho, y como comenta de codigo abierto, tambien estoy de acuerdo pues se supone que ese mismo codigo ha sido visto por muchos ojos, asi que se puede tener cierta "confianza" de que el codigo esta pulido, claro no siempre en todos los preoyectos, pero si en los mas grandes. Saludos

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR** Yo estoy a favor de este tipo de pregunta, pero me parece muy complicado que encajen en el alcance tan cerrado de soes.

¿De cuántas maneras se puede mejorar un código? Voy a poner las dos opciones que se me ocurren: a) número de caracteres que ocupa (espacio, líneas de código, etc) y b) tiempo de ejecución (en segundos, ciclos de CPU, etc.). En Python hay una forma de optimización que llaman *pythonica* que es una mezcla de comprensión del código escrito, tamaño del código, desempeño y algo que podríamos etiquetar como *"elegancia"* (bastante subjetivo).

Para que una pregunta de revisión pasara debería solicitar una mejora específica, ¿no creen? Y que esta mejora se lo más objetiva posible. Por ejemplo: *"Quiero que esta función ocupe el menor número de caracteres posible, manteniendo la identación"*. O *"busco una alternativa para este código que mejore el tiempo de ejecución"*.

Y entonces alguien podría responder: *"No uses `foooooo()`, mejor usa `bar()` que funciona igual y tiene 4 caracteres menos"*. O *"te propongo este algoritmo que disminuye el tiempo de ejecución en 0.0032seg"*.

Entonces, las preguntas/respuestas deberían tener un conjunto de características para ser aceptadas:

1. El código **debe** funcionar.
2. Se **debe** presentar un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable.
3. *Deberían* incluirse datos de ejemplo
4. *Deberían* indicarse las condiciones de control (tipo: *"el promedio de 5 ejecuciones es 3seg."*).
5. Se **debe** especificar qué se quiere mejorar.
6. La mejora *debería* se objetiva y preferentemente *medible*.

En conclusión, me parece muy complicado. Mejor no cambiar el alcance actual.

Comment: gracias por contesta, aunque algunas cosas que comenta estoy de acuerdo en otras no tanto "pero que tampoco me parecen mal", pero por ejemplo en el punto 1 y 2, me parecen acertados sobre todo el 1 se comenta en el tag de revision de codigo, y el dos pienso, que menos que eso, pero por ejemplo el 5 aunque seria ideal, tampo es tan necesario, pues igual es un usuario nuevo ect, o simplemente en el codigo aparecen cosas sin sentido, que que aunque se quiera mejorar por ejemplo la lectura del mismo, exista una parte que no tiene sentido que este, espero explicarme...

Comment: ...Pero la linea del final *En conclusión, me parece muy complicado. Mejor no.* me dejo confunso con lo que queria decir sobretodo con *Mejor No*, mejor no el que podria aclararlo. "aunque quizas sea yo" que no lo entendi ahora mismo. Saludos

Comment: @AngelAngel Lo quiero decir que es mejor no intentarlo.  Con respecto al punto 5, ¿sería raro que alguien dijera _"quiero mejorar mi código, pero no sé qué mejorar"_? En mi experiencia la mejora es algo que debe planearse... no algo que aparezca por arte de magia o se descubra sin querer queriendo. Pero bueno, de verdad me parece que con lo que tenemos actualmente es más que suficiente y no hay que ampliar el alcance actual de la comunidad.

Comment: *aparezca por arte de magia o se descubra sin querer queriendo* bueno aunque entiendo lo que quiere dicer, le puedo decir que aveces eso pasa, pero le entiendo. Por otro lado ahora tengo mas dudas, pero quizas este entendiendo mal algunas cosas que comenta, aclaro, Yo no estoy pidiendo que se acepten este tipo de pregunta, es que este tipo de preguntas "revision de codigo" son permitidas en el sitio. ver enlace en la pregunta. Le digo esto por esta parte -> *...me parece que con lo que tenemos actualmente es más que suficiente y no hay que ampliar el alcance actual de la comunidad.* pero ...

Comment: ... quizas no le este entendiendo bien un asi gracias por tomarse el tiempo de reponder. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

[Centro de ayuda:](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)

> **Principalmente basada en opinión** - las discusiones enfocadas en
>   opiniones diversas son buenas, pero ellas no encajan bien en nuestro
>   formato.
>
> > Muchas buenas preguntas generan un grado de opinión basado en la expertiz, pero las respuestas a esta pregunta tenderán a ser en su
> >     mayoría enteramente basadas en opiniones, en lugar de hechos,
> >     referencias o expertiz específico.

Lo anterior también aparece en el [centro de ayuda de Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions) y ello no les impide que el sitio funcione. Si ellos pueden nosotros también.

La revisión de código encaja por tanto bien en el modelo de SOes y no es necesario elminar ese motivo de cierre para esas preguntas.

Para promocionar este tipo de preguntas sugeriría editar la etiqueta [revisión-de-código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revisi%c3%b3n-de-c%c3%b3digo) para guiar al usuario que la usa.

Propongo pues esta descripción de etiqueta basada en la descripción actual y en [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) e invito a editarla hasta alcanzar un consenso:

---

Revisión de código es la examinación sistemática (como en la revisión por pares) del código fuente de un programa informático para mejorar la calidad del código, mediante la detección temprana de errores en el código de los programas o alternativas más eficientes a la implementación inicial.

#### ¿Cómo hacer una buena pregunta?

No preguntes sobre código que no funciona, código hipotético o código que no existe. Esas preguntas serán cerradas como no relacionadas.

Si tienes una pregunta de programación que no comple esos requisitos entonces no es apropiada para esta etiqueta. Quizás puedas preguntarla en otra etiqueta o sitio.

**El título de la pregunta.**
Anuncia lo que hace tu código en el título, no lo que te preocupa acerca del código. Se descriptivo e interesante, atraerás más visitas a la pregunta.

He aquí algunos ejemplos de títulos inaceptables por ser muy genéricos.

- ¿Cómo hago más rápido este código? (A todos nos gusta que nuestro código sea rápido. Puedes usar la etiqueta [rendimiento](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/rendimiento) para indicar este deseo.)
- ¿Cómo simplifico esta cadena de condicionales?. (Esto aplica a demasiadas preguntas.)
- Necesito refactorizar esta función de Ruby. (Son los revisores los que aconsejarán si hay o no que factorizarla. No pidas esto en el título.)
- ¿Es esto un buen diseño orientado a objetos? (Muchísimas preguntas podría tener este título. No ayuda a diferenciar la pregunta.)
- Una evaluación online dice que he excedido el tiempo límite. (Demasiado genérico también.)

Además, elimina frases supérfluas similares a las siguientes, puesto que aplican a la inmensa mayoría de preguntas de esta etiqueta:

- ¿Pueden evaluar mi …
- Por favor ayuda en…
- Necesito mejorar esto.
- Reducir la complejidad de…

Debes resumir el objetivo de tu código (qué pretende hacer, no cómo) Algunos buenos ejemplos son:

- Proyecto Euler 9 : Encontrar una tripleta de Pitágoras.
- Juego de la vida con Swing UI.
- Controlador de vista para app de ayuda a dejar de fumar en iOS.
- Validación de entradas para formulario de petición de vacaciones.

Si tu código no tiene un objetivo, entonces es muy probable que tu pregunta contenga código hipotético o que estés preguntando sobre buenas prácticas en general en vez de sobre revisar tu código específico. Esas preguntas están fuera de lugar en esta etiqueta.

**Las normas generales de SOes son de aplicación.**
Y en esta etiqueta incluir un [ejemplo completo, mínimo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) es obligatorio, no simplemente muy recomendable. Además el código debe funcionar. Si no funciona puedes buscar ayuda en otras etiquetas.

Asegúrate de incluir en tu pregunta todo el código a revisar; puedes dejar código auxiliar en enlaces en otros sitios. Quita toda información sensible, como contraseñas, pero no alteres tanto tu código que no se asemeje al original.

Comment: gracias por contestar y por tomarse la "molestia" de elaborar es respuesta pues pienso que es muy util, asi que quizas puedo pensar que el uso de `se basa principalmente en opiniones` para cerrarla ect, para este tipo de preguntas con el tag revision de codigo, tendrian que evitarse en la medida de lo posible y escoger otro motivo de cierre. Saludos

Comment: sobre el apartado de titulos genericos por ejemplo esta muy bien, bueno en general la respuesta en si. Podira ponerse parte de su respuesta en el tag del que hablamos pero solo es una opinion. Saludos