# Política respecto a preguntas de "depura mi programa"

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, temática

Esta pregunta [Problema de cálculo en Java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/76597/problema-de-c%c3%a1lculo-en-java) me ha hecho preguntarme cuál debería ser la política respecto a preguntas en el sentido "depura esto".

No hay ningún problema complicado en la pregunta, es simplemente que el OP no se ha molestado en ir siguiendo su programa y ver que en cada ejecución entra en varios `if` cuando sólo debería entrar en uno, por reutilizar una variable para otra cosa. No es "la división entre enteros devuelve un entero" o "hay que comparar con equals y no con ==". Ya no es una cuestión de falta de conocimientos del OP; es simplemente "dime qué hace mi programa que yo que lo he escrito no lo sé".

En el sitio original estas preguntas se cierran de forma rutinaria con un amable mensaje en plan "esto no es un servicio de depuración"<sup>1</sup>, y francamente me parece el enfoque correcto.

¿Se puede fijar una postura oficial?

- <sup>1</sup> Dicho en inglés, of course.

Comment: Pues me parece que un mensaje amable en castellano también sería pertinente.

Comment: Relacionado: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1949/65, cc: @fedorqui

Comment: _Querido usuario, entendemos que programar es una tarea complicada y que a veces solo un ser superior sabe porqué algo funciona. Sin embargo, si quien lo programó eres tú, probablemente tú estés más cerca de ese ser de lo que estamos nosotros que acabamos de ver este código por primera vez. Resumiendo: no vamos a debuggar tu programa. Añado: voto por cerrar como demasiado amplia_.

Comment: Pero la ayuda para la depuración es un tema _on topic_. Tiene requisitos muy precisos, pero es válido. O eso entiendo leyendo la guía: https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Comment: @toledano Es parte del alcance del sitio, sin duda. Pero es muy diferente una pregunta que muestra esfuerzo por parte del autor diciendo por ejemplo: "*en este punto la variable x es null y no entiendo por qué si...", a casos como "*No me funciona, ingreso N y me da error* [50 líneas de código], *¿por qué?*".

Comment: Comprendo @Mariano pero ¿la pregunta en comento puede servir para establecer una postura oficial? Lo que entiendo es que la política oficial ya existe. ¿Esta pregunta en meta pretende cambiar esa política? Creo que no entiendo la última pregunta sobre la postura oficial.

Comment: @toledano Buen punto. No lo interpreté como un cambio en el alcance sino una discusión sobre cómo y cuándo aplica. Por eso amplié publicando una respuesta.

Answer (score 6):

Creo que no es un tema de definir una **postura**, sino de buscar una buena **metodología**.

La ayuda es bastante clara. En [**¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?**](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) dice:

> [...]
>   **Algunas preguntas no son pertinentes incluso si encajan con una de las categorías mencionadas anteriormente:**
>
> 1. Las preguntas que solicitan ayuda para depuración ("¿por qué no funciona este código?") deben incluir cuál es el comportamiento esperado, el problema o error específico y el mínimo de código necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin una clara enunciación del problema no son útiles para otros usuarios. Ver: [Cómo crear un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Y remarco:

- el comportamiento esperado
- el problema o error específico
- el mínimo de código necesario

---

#### ¿Por dónde empezamos?

Lo primero que yo siempre me pregunto antes de evaluar un cierre es: ¿Puedo mejorar la pregunta? ¿Puedo editarla para que quede bien (incluso si es una edición radical)? ¿Puedo guiar al autor a que mejore la pregunta?
- *Todos lo sabemos, pero es bueno recordarlo*.

La mejor forma de ayudarlo es intentar **comentarle cómo podría depurarlo**: buscar que entienda qué podría hacer en este caso para identificar mejor el problema y, quizás, mejorar su pregunta.
-*La caña y no el pescado*.

---

#### ¿Se debería cerrar?

Cuando, desde tu experiencia y opinión profesional, creas que no se cumplió con el esfuerzo para cumplir las condiciones, entonces **sí, vota para cerrar**. -Simplemente recordemos que todos en algún momento empezamos de cero, intentando ponernos en los zapatos del otro, pensando qué podríamos haber hecho en ese momento de la curva de aprendizaje y si realmente hubiésemos podido depurarlo mejor.

Ahora bien, cada profesional tuvo un aprendizaje diferente. Otros probablemente opinen distinto en cada caso. Por eso es que se vota en cada cierre o reapertura, usando el mejor criterio de cada uno de los revisores.
- *Esto es ser parte de una comunidad*.

---

#### ¿Y en los casos limítrofes?

Muchas veces revisamos preguntas que están al borde de "*la cierro*" o "*está bien, la respondo*". De nuevo, **utiliza tu mejor criterio**. El resto hará lo mismo y el resultado se verá en si se cerró o no.
-*Tan simple como eso*.

Por supuesto, en estos casos que pueden dar lugar a diferentes interpretaciones, es bueno comentar tu punto de vista para que otros entiendan por qué estás votando para cerrar. Un comentario como [el que mencionó fedorqui](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2146/pol%C3%ADtica-respecto-a-preguntas-de-depura-mi-programa#comment6537_2146) siempre ayuda a encausar una publicación por el buen camino.

Answer (score 4):

Lo que hago en mi caso es no responder, porque eso es hacer los deberes, o simplemente comento que se fije, no propongo ninguna solución definitiva, ya que no estas haciendo ningún favor en solucionar ese problema, porque un programador, tiene unos *"ejercicios"* básicos para mejorar en la programación como yo lo miro que son :

1. Saber depurar leyendo el código, ya que en un principio lo redacta **él** por consiguiente tiene que ser **él** , el que mejor sepa depurarlo.
2. El desarrollo de `if` , `for` , en general controles de flujo y puertas lógicas por consiguiente tienen que saber dominarse.

Los temas de *"depuración"* o mismamente de *"sacar callo"*, no estamos ayudando realmente, porque más tarde vendrá con el mismo problema. Ya el aprendizaje de algo lo que lo consigue es el esforzarse en sacarlo o buscando documentación en inglés o tirarte un tiempo intentando descubrirlo haciendo:

1. Salidas por pantalla `echo` , `alert`.
2. Salidas por la consola ,
   `console.log("hola holitas querido vecino!")`;
3. Salidas con los datos dentro de `if's` , `elseif`,
   `for` , etc..

Opciones existen, yo no las respondo como ya dije, no ayudan y el echarse 1 hora con un código para comprenderlo es un bien a largo plazo, es una inversión como buen profesional para un futuro.

Aunque hay que reconocer que tampoco hay que ser un extremista, pero hay casos y casos.