# Preguntas de "¿Es mi código correcto?"

Tags: discusión, preguntas, temática

Por ejemplo: [Problemas con mi primer ejercicios en C#](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/383522/problemas-con-mi-primer-ejercicios-en-c)

La pregunta incluye una descripción del programa y el código intentado, sin embargo no hay un "me falla esto" sino un mucho más amplio "¿es mi código correcto? ¿hace lo que pide el enunciado?"

Creo que recordar que las preguntas de "revisión de código" son aceptadas en el sitio, pero para mí esto no es exactamente eso; una pregunta de revisión de código es "mi código funciona pero quiero mejorarlo" mientras que esto es "no tengo ni idea de si he hecho lo que me piden."

En mi opinión no son buenas preguntas, un programador debería tener una idea de qué hace su código, y saber diseñar unos casos de prueba, y hacer una pregunta más específica (con la salvedad de la revisión de código).

¿Qué opináis?

Comment: Hombre, la verdad es que esas preguntas suelen venir de novatos. La única pregunta que tengo en el sitio (SO en español) es bastante estúpida, pero por algun lado se empieza. No miro tan mal esas preguntas la verdad, siempre y cuando el usuario mejore y empiece a aportar

Comment: Hay que recordar que siempre está https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @JuanFelipeRubiano. codereview es un sitio en inglés, queda fuera del alcance de los novatos.

Comment: Me pregunto si "La programación no es lo tuyo, buscate otra cosa" sería una respuesta aceptable en estos casos.

Comment: @CandidMoe Pues claro que si amigo, como tu empezaste sabiendo ...

Comment: En mi opinión tienes razón. No hace falta tener experiencia para poder describir bien el problema al que te estás enfrentando. Pueden describir su pregunta perfectamente con un "por qué no recibe la variable el server" (por ejemplo) en lugar de "que es lo que falla de mi código". Además este tipo de preguntas, no siempre, pero suelen ir acompañadas de una explicación muy básica y en ocasiones ni eso. A veces se ve a la legua como hacen un copia-pega y dedican 20 segundos a la pregunta esperando que otra persona, de forma completamente altruista, dedique su tiempo a dar con el problema.

Comment: La situación descrita es conocida como "programación voodoo". Consiste en programar juntando trozos de otros programas, que pueden o no abordar el mismo problema, con la esperanza de que mágicamente todo funcione.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Opino que **no deberían permitirse**, puesto que incumplen varias de las normas básicas del sitio:

#### No son preguntas concretas.

- Una pregunta concreta tiene ciertas palabras o expresiones *clave* que permiten localizar la publicación de forma *mas o menos* rápida.
- El problema es (o **debería ser**) fácilmente identificable; admitamos aquí 2 casos: o al leer la pregunta, o con un vistazo rápido al código.

#### Son de poca utilidad para nadie mas que el Autor de la Pregunta.

- Recordemos que uno de los objetivos del sitio es reunir una base de conocimientos útiles **tanto para usuarios actuales como futuros**.
- Consecuencia del apartado anterior: Si la pregunta no plantea un problema concreto, difícilmente será utilizada en un futuro, precisamente por esa carencia: ¿ Que buscamos ?

#### Generan respuestas Basadas en Opiniones.

- Sin un problema concreto ... ¿ Qué respuesta podemos dar ? Cada cual dará **su versión**, **su opinión personal** sobre lo que **ha creído entender** del enunciado del ejercicio (si lo hubiere), del texto de la pregunta, y del propio código.

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo, especialmente en lo de que _Son de poca utilidad para nadie mas que el Autor de la Pregunta_. Si la idea es crear una bibiloteca de conocimiento para todos, este tipo de preguntas no van en ese camino. Además, normalmente son muy concretas y, por tanto, difíciles de clasificar y generalizar. Son una variante, en definitiva, de las preguntas sobre cómo hacer los deberes

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' Pero ese motivo no se puede usar en exclusividad. Por ejemplo, en [Política respecto a preguntas de “depura mi programa”](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2146/19610), se argumentan ciertas acciones a tomar. Personalmente, creo que, a diferencia de esos casos, los tratados aqui incumplen **varias** reglas (tengo *problemillas* con las tildes y el teclado, *sorry*).

Comment: Me desvío ligeramente del tema y quisiera saber que opináis sobre un trozo de código que tiene un problema, pero no es de sintaxis sino de concepto. 1.  Hasta que punto "corregirlo" no es una licencia personal basada en tu propia experiencia/habilidad? Hablamos de for-loops -> list comprehensions en python por ejemplo. 2. ¿Cuál es el alcance de la revisión de código? Entiendo que eso también roza el subjetivismo

Answer (score -1):

me presento como alguien completamente novato en esto y llegué aqui porque realmente es una base de conocimiento valiosa para los que estamos dando los primeros pasos (principalmente por el idioma español).

Ahora respondiendo a la pregunta ¿Qué opináis?, procedo:

Si alguno recuerda... empezamos con alguien que nos llevaba en los brazos, luego se aprende a gatear, luego a caminar con algo de estabilidad, y por ultimo caminar o correr grandes maratones, dependiendo de tus habilidades. En si "es el proceso de aprendizaje", un tutor, propia observacion, mucha practica, algo de perfeccionamiento.

Pero entendiendo la finalidad de esto y para que no se llene de basura, tal vez se pudieran permitir publicar, dejar que alguien de forma completamente altruista ayude a dar los primeros pasos y tal vez tras algun tiempo prudente se pueda habilitar una opcion de que esa pregunta con sus respectivas respuestas y comentarios sean eliminadas por alguien de Nivel Superior.

Gracias por el espacio que nos brindan a quienes aún no estamos iluminados, pero buscamos algo de luz.