# ¿Existe un codereview.stackexchange en español?

Tags: discusión

El caso es que me parece genial la versión de [codereview de stackexchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), y no encuentro o no hay una versión es español.

Muchas veces me encuentro preguntas que tienen que ver más con una revisión de código que con un problema real.

Pienso que debería ser posible mover estas preguntas directamente a esta versión (cuando exista) o crear un link en la entrada de la pregunta para seguir el hilo en la revisión de código.

Bajo mi punto de vista mejorar mi experiencia/aprendizaje no consiste solo en copiar la mejor respuesta de una pregunta en es.stackoverflow,  una buena review puede ayudarme muchisimo más despejandome dudas.

Creo que solo por las siguientes razones merecería tener este sitio

- Limpiar el sitio de este tipo de preguntas
- Tener un sitio en español donde poder hacer reviews

¿Qué pensais ? ¿Se puede conseguir ? ¿Estoy equivocado ? ¿Existe ya esta idea ? y en ese caso , ¿en qué progreso está ?

Comment: No existe y si se quiere proponer, o ya se hizo, has de mirar en [area51.se].

Comment: @lois6b gracias por el comentario, Area 51 XD no tenia ni idea :) me lo apunto

Answer (score 7):

Aún no existe.

En cuanto a limpiar el sitio de ese tipo de preguntas, no le veo sentido.
Aquí se pueden hacer "reviews", para eso está la etiqueta [revisión-de-código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revisi%c3%b3n-de-c%c3%b3digo)

Relacionado

- [Preguntas de revision de codigo (dudas)](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1949/65)
- [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/65), más específicamente [esta respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/164/65)

P.D. En Area 51 no se están aceptando propuestas de nuevos sitios en idiomas distintos al inglés

Relacionado

- [Can we open proposals to complete the “Trilogy” sites in languages already having StackOverflow?](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/25496/133145)
- [Internationalization 'State of the Stack' - Stack Overflow edition](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20987/133145)

Comment: Gracias por contestar. Entonces tendré en cuenta esta etiqueta en el futuro, aunque me sigue pareciendo buena idea tener un sitio especifico para hacer `reviews` en español. Es como decir soy ganadero y en mi granja crío pollos, pero si hace falta tortugas, agaponis, peces y hasta leones ... jejeje pena que en el área 51 no acepten nuevas propuestas en otros idiomas, aun así muchas gracias por la info.