# ¿En algún momento Stack Overflow en español se diversificará según temas? ¿Cuál es el requisito para ésto?

Tags: discusión, comunidad

Stack Overflow en español tiene muchas temáticas amontonadas<sup>1</sup> en una sola comunidad, la cual seguramente crecerá y me parece que es lógico pensar que se tenderá a una diversificación desde la misma comunidad en español. Por lo que es mi curiosidad saber qué requisitos cumplirá la comunidad en español para llegar a ésto.

Se entiende que el inglés es el idioma predominante en internet y en el que además se inició stack overflow, pero el español es un idioma más hablado que el inglés como lengua materna, crecemos pensando en español.

<sup>1</sup> Temáticas amontonadas: Ingeniería del Software, Ciencia Computacional, etc., etc.

Comment: ¿Cuáles son las temáticas que te parece que están amontonadas?

Comment: En inglés hay comunidades separadas para: LaTeX, procesamiento de señales, ingeniería de software, ciencia computacional, etc, etc.

Comment: Pero no todas esas no están "amontonadas" aquí. ¿Ya viste [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/65)?

Comment: Si hay más comunidades en español con esas temáticas, no las encontré y te agradecería que me pasaras sus enlaces.

Comment: El único sitio 100% en español es [es.so]. Otro que permite preguntas en españos es [spanish.se] pero su idioma oficial es inglés, así que su interfaz ni sus artículos de ayuda están traducidos.

Comment: Por cierto, no porque exista un sitio en inglés sobre una temática tendría que ver uno en español y mucho menos eso hace que esa temática se pueda tratar aquí.

Comment: Nadie sugirió que se esté tratando de imitar lo inglés.
¿Piensas que todas las posibles preguntas en español deben venir solamente a esta comunidad?
Las comunidades en inglés van más allá de la programación, y al hacer preguntas en esta comunidad la página te recuerdas que verifiques que tu pregunta es sobre programación. Pues pasa que si quieres preguntar algo sobre sistemas operativos, no hay la etiqueta para ello.

Comment: ¿Tienes identificada alguna pregunta sobre sistemas operativos que le haga falta una etiqueta?

Comment: Sí, Disculpa, pero no quiero deformar mi pregunta inicial, ésta tiene que ver con el crecimiento natural de una comunidad y con la demografía del español y no se trata de quieras convertirla en un caso particular mío.¨

Y si quisiera hacer una pregunta sobre Ingeniería de sonido o genética ¿Se la ha de tratar como un caso particular? También te recuerdo que la comunidad que me sugeriste de Spanish Language trata sobre el idioma español, entonces si la gente que hace preguntas sobre el idioma inglés crece ¿toda la vida deberán preguntar en esta comunidad junto con los de programación?

Comment: Actualmente no hay un sitio en español en la red SE para preguntas sobre ingeniería de sonido o genética, estás temática como no corresponden ni a [es.so] ni a [spanish.se] de preguntarse ahí será cerradas.

Comment: Exacto, a eso me refiero, en cambio en inglés efectivamente existen. 
Además stack overflow en español no menciona en su nombre que se trate solo preguntas de programación.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76819/discussion-between-ruben-and-pillqu).

Answer (score 2):

Cuando nació Stack Overflow (en inglés) pasó que el sitio se dividió en varios aunque hoy en día la dinámica para la creación de nuevos sitios es otra, por ser SOes el primer y único sitio de la red de SE completamente en español , es probable que eventualmente pase algo similar.

Con respecto a ingeniería del software y ciencia computacional, estas no están en la temática actual de SOes, por lo que las preguntas sobre estos temas podrían ser cerradas. Si bien existe la etiqueta [ingenieria-del-software](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ingenieria-del-software) esta tiene menos de 20 preguntas y varias de ellas están cerradas. Es probable que en un proyecto de limpieza se elimine esa etiqueta.

Con respecto al creación de sitios las temáticas mencionadas u otras, el primer requisito podría ser que se levante la suspensión de creación de propuestas de nuevos sitios en Area 51 la cual fue anunciada en [Internationalization 'State of the Stack'](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/20988/133145).

Con base en [Changes to the Area 51 Process v3.0](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27938/133145), el siguiente requisito podría decirse es que exista una comunidad que requiera de un sitio de preguntas y respuestas, sin embargo, habrá que esperar a que lo primero ocurra y luego ver cual es el proceso vigente para la creación de nuevos sitios en idiomas distintos al inglés.

Relacionado

- [¿Existe un codereview.stackexchange en español?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3436/65)
- [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/65)

Comment: En el caso de ingeniería del software, o también en algún otro caso hablado en los comentarios de la pregunta inicial, eso podría limitar el interés de gente bien calificada para participar en SOes en resolución de problemas y preguntas relacionadas con la informática y la programación. La informática se aplica a todos los campos, no solo a web, aplicaciones móviles, bases de datos o simplemente resolver un problema del colegio o universidad. (95% de las preguntas?). Que bonito sería ver una pregunta de programación relacionada con IA, robótica, etc...