# ¿Qué tipo de preguntas se pueden realizar en Stack Overflow en español?

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, temática

Según tengo entendido, en el caso del Stack Overflow en inglés, las preguntas son de bajo nivel y técnicas, en donde uno tiene un problema de código al programar algo en especifico y se desea resolver dudas sobre eso, pero en Stack Overflow en español he visto bastantes preguntas muy generales.

- [¿Es necesario instalar Git en Windows 10 si ya existe en Bash Ubuntu?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/87265/es-necesario-instalar-git-en-windows-10-si-ya-existe-en-bash-ubuntu)
- [Evitar guardar credenciales en el navegador](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/87130/evitar-guardar-credenciales-en-el-navegador)

Según mi experiencia, en el Stack Overflow en inglés estoy casi seguro que este tipo de preguntas serían puestas en pausa y posteriormente cerradas, ¿pero es ese el caso de este sitio? ¿Aquí se permiten este tipo de preguntas?

Comment: Creo que falta definir un poco mejor. ¿Por qué las ves cómo "muy generales"? ¿Estás seguro de que no existen preguntas similares en SOen? ¿Qué leíste/investigaste sobre la temática de SOes que no entiendas para definir el alcance? Para hablar de preguntas generales, creo que deberías acotar mejor esta pregunta también.

Comment: En realidad, en SOen serían aceptadas o tendrían un duplicado :)

Comment: @Mariano Cuando salieron los stackexchange de programmers, super user, etc. siempre me pregunte cuales serian las diferencias entre estos sitios, por lo que al investigar lei varios posts del meta, y generalmente (por no decir siempre) respondian que en stackoverflow (ingles) van problemas de codigo y programacion especificos, en cambio en programmers iban las preguntas de herramientas de programacion, paradigmas, etc, [ejemplo aqui.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68384/whats-the-difference-between-stack-overflow-and-software-engineering-se-previo)

Comment: @CodigoFasil entonces probablemente esta publicación responda a tu pregunta https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/127, aunque los dos ejemplos que mencionas no son para Programmers, y el segundo tampoco entra en SU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Respuesta corta

SOes y SO son sitios similares mas no idénticos. Sin embargo, ambos sitios aceptan preguntas sobre herramientas de programación como git y navegadores.

Referencias :

- https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
- https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic
- [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/65)

## Explicación

En primer lugar SOes no es la localización o traducción de SO. Si bien comparten el mismo modelo y aplicación, uno de las elementos esenciales es la comunidad y cada uno cuenta con comunidades distintas.

Tan es así la importancia de la comunidad, que para crear un nuevo sitio en la red de Stack Exchange debe pasar por un proceso en las que el elemento fundamental a valorar es el que exista una comunidad con miembros que se comprometan y que hagan efectivo ese compromiso.

Por otro lado, SO tiene casi 10 años, podemos aprender de ellos pero también debemos reconocer que no somos iguales, tanto por "edad", SOes recién se graduó en mayo pasado, como por otros factores de los cuáles la cultura es uno que se construye día con día.

### Ejemplos de preguntas similares

#### Primer ejemplo

- [Installing git on Windows 10, unable to access .gitconfig](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38481534/1595451)

#### Segundo ejemplo

- [How do you disable browser Autocomplete on web form field / input tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2530/1595451)

Comment: Si, tienes razon, mas despues me di cuenta de que tambien aceptaban ese tipo de preguntas.

Comment: Suele suceder (me refiero a que a varios nos ha pasado)