# ¿Qué pasa cuando tengo una solución ineficiente a un problema y quiero debatir sobre ello?

Tags: discusión

¿Cómo puedo plantear una pregunta, en la que tengo una solución al problema pero que es demasiado ineficiente,  y quiero debatir sobre ello?

Quiero saber si esto tiene cabida en StackOverFlow o no es una pregunta válida.

Comment: Muchas veces no es la pregunta en sí lo que se cierra si no la forma de formularla y las respuestas que buscas. ¿Puedes poner un ejemplo de esa pregunta que harías para ver cómo la planterías? Un saludo

Comment: Debatir no se puede en el sitio principal, pero puedes usar la etiqueta, [revision-de-codigo] donde expones tu pieza y tus preocupaciones. En este tipo de pregutan. cada respuestas es una propuestas de como mejorar esa pieza. Es claro, una muy buena forma de apreder. Eso se discutio cuando se definia la tematica del sitio, ver [aqui](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/164/25). Tambien puedes usar el Chat.

Comment: Vale, lo hare entonces de esta manera con la etiqueta [revision-de-codigo], muchas gracias chicos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Son preguntas válidas bajo la etiqueta [revisión-de-código](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/revisi%c3%b3n-de-c%c3%b3digo).

Considera que estas preguntas tienen ciertos requisitos:

- Código compilable y ejecutable. Si el código tiene problemas, simplemente no entra bajo esta etiqueta. Se supone que es para revisar un código que puedes usar en tu aplicación, no para hacer debug.
- Plataforma claramente definida. Esto es, debes brindar los detalles técnicos para poder ejecutar el código provisto. Ejemplo: Java y Spring, JavaScript y Axios, etc.
- Intenciones de mejora. Puede tratarse de optimizar el código para que sea más rápido, use menos memoria o quizás cambiarlo para facilitar su mantenibilidad. Esto debe expresarse claramente.

Así mismo, considerar que las respuestas para este tipo de preguntas no deben ser basadas en opiniones, sino en hechos y recomendaciones que realmente, al aplicarlos, se pueden ver las mejoras en el código.