# No sé ni porque tenemos esta licuadora en la casa

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, solicitud-de-quemado

¿Podriamos cerrar la etiqueta [blender]?

- Hasta donde yo sé, no encuentro relación alguna de Blender (el software libre de diseño 3d) con StackOverflow en español. (pero yo no sé mucho de esto, por lo cual estoy abierto a aclaraciones)
- Solamente existen 3 preguntas y una de ellas esta cerrada

---

**Edit**

No voy a tocar la publicación original, para la posteridad. Ok, aqui voy.

**¿Qué debemos saber acerca de Blender, en relación a nuestro ámbito?**

- Blender es un "conjunto de herramientas de software de computación gráfica de 3 dimensiones"<sup>1</sup>, que ademas es gratuito y de código abierto, usado para "filmes animados, efectos visuales, arte, modelos visualizables en tres dimensiones, aplicaciones interactivas en tres dimensiones y video juegos." <sup>2</sup>
- Aun cuando Blender posee una interfaz gráfica de usuario excepcional para realizar todo lo anteriormente señalado, existe la posibilidad de hacer uso de una API que el equipo de Blender ha desarrollado en Python <sup>3</sup> para llevar a cabo tareas mas avanzadas.<sup>4</sup>
- El objetivo de esta característica es "extender la funcionalidad de Blender".<sup>5</sup>  A mi entender, entonces, esta posibilidad existe para tener la capacidad de hacer más/mejores diseños y llegar a un mejor final, dentro del rango de cosas para las cuales el software fue diseñado.
- El uso de esta caracteristica esta claramente definido como "avanzado" <sup>6</sup>  y estos temas "pueden no ser requeridos para un uso típico".<sup>7</sup>  Esto me da a entender a mi que no es como el software fue diseñado para usarse, pero en casos en los que se necesite, la característica esta y es funcional.

**¿Qué dicen nuestros maximos referentes acerca de lo que se puede preguntar en este sitio?** (El [Centro de Ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) y la publicación de meta [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/definici%C3%B3n-de-la-tem%C3%A1tica-apropiada-para-el-sitio), son nuestros máximo referentes.)

- un problema específico de programación, o
- un algoritmo de software, o
- herramientas de software comúnmente utilizadas por programadores; y es
- un problema práctico, que tiene respuesta y único al desarrollo de software
- Preguntas conceptuales sobre el desarrollo de software (arquitectura, algoritmos, metodologías de desarrollo, ciencias de la computación, licencias de software.)
- Preguntas sobre administración y uso avanzado de bases de datos.
- Preguntas que solicitan revisiones de código en busca de posibles problemas o sugerencias de mejora.
- Preguntas sobre historia del desarrollo de software y de lenguajes, herramientas y componentes específicos.
- Preguntas sobre gestión de servidores y redes de ordenadores.
- Preguntas sobre fórmulas de hoja de cálculo (Excel, Google Sheets, Calc,...)
- De la referida publicación en Meta hay varias respuestas votadas negativamente, pero escribo **la opción más negativamente votada** (que pongo a propósito): Preguntas sobre el uso de aplicaciones de software y componentes de hardware.

**Entonces, ¿Por qué propongo que se "quemé" la etiqueta Blender?**

Contraste con la tématica del sitio:

- Para los puntos que son obvios, no voy a poner nada (por ejemplo, es obvio que Blender no tiene nada que ver con bases de datos)
- Blender si es una herramienta de software, pero obviamente no es utilizada por programadores, ya que Blender se usa para diseñar, no para programar.
- Aun cuando se puedan presentar problemas practicos con Blender, no es parte del desarrollo de un software, sino de un diseño.
- El único punto por el que inicié esta discusión (si, es una discusión) es porque posiblemente pueda entrar en el punto de "problema específico de programación", y pienso que dependería mucho. Pueden darse dos situaciones: a) el código que el OP esta usando no es funcional por alguna caracteristica de Python que no sabe usar (listas, diccionarios, POO, etc) o b) el código que el OP esta usando no es funcional porque no sabe como llevar a cabo tal o cual acción de diseño, aun cuando si sepa usar Python. Si se diera el caso "a" sería más bien una pregunta de Python y por lo tanto, la etiqueta Blender estaría de más.

Contraste externo

- Ya existe un sitio de la red StackExchange exclusivo para Blender <sup>8</sup> y allí la etiqueta principal es Python <sup>9</sup>.
- Las preguntas listadas con la etiqueta Blender en SO tienen, básicamente, la misma forma y objetivo que las listadas en Blender SE bajo la etiqueta Python, de nuevo comprobando que sería más logico que estuvieran todas en Blender SE.

Despues de todo este contexto que no me peso para nada escribir, basta con agradecer a los que leyeron hasta acá y volver a la primera pregunta de esta publicación ubicada al principio, la cual someto a discusión.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sup>2</sup>  [Blender (software) Wikipedia - Introducción](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blender_(software))

<sup>3</sup> [Blender (software) Wikipedia - Features](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blender_(software)#Features)

<sup>4</sup> <sup>6</sup> <sup>7</sup> [Blender Manual - Advanced](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/index.html)

<sup>5</sup> [Blender Manual - Advanced - Scripting - Introduction](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/advanced/scripting/introduction.html)

<sup>8</sup> [Sitio de Blender de la red StackExchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/)

<sup>9</sup> [Etiquetas del sitio de Blender de la red StackExchange](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tags)

Comment: No todos tenemos que saber de todo (: ¿Por qué no quieres tener a [tag:blender] en este sitio?

Comment: (Me pregunto porque los negativos....) @Rubén, pues no estoy seguro si esto es acerca de si yo quiero o no, solo pensaba que el software Blender no tiene nada que ver con la tématica del sitio y por eso mismo, lo puse a discusión porque no esta a mi cargo decidir que etiqueta esta aqui o no, sino de la comunidad. Supongo que los votos negativos indican que si quieren la etiqueta :D

Comment: Aún no respondes cuál es el motivo por el que piensas que el software Blender no tiene nada que ver con la temática de este sitio. ¿Ya revisaste lo que se puede hacer con Blender? ¿Podrías hacer una breve descripción para los que no conocen de Blender? ¿Has revisado  [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/65)? En relación a los negativos, puede ser tanto porque la pregunta parace una propuesta y no se está de acuerdo con ella, porque se piensa que no es una pregunta clara, entre otras posibilidades.

Comment: @Rubén, gracias por tus sugerencias y objetividad. He editado la pregunta. La verdad no veo mal los negativos, solo me hubiera gustado saber porque se dieron, es mas, apoyo el voto frecuente y objetivo. Y si, creo que los votos se dieron porque la pregunta/publicación fue un poco pobre al comienzo.

Comment: Kenny: estas propuestas van por voto popular normalmente, por lo que un voto positivo debería interpretarse como "estoy de acuerdo, quemémosla" y uno negativo como "no comparto los motivos, dejémosla". Así voté yo.

Answer (score 2):

Yo creo que mientras las preguntas con [blender](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/blender) se mantengan, dicha etiqueta debe mantenerse.

Sugiero a los que interesados en este tema votar las preguntas.

Comment: La etiqueta en sí a mi tampoco me molesta si se usa como sugiere el extracto: https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/blender/info. También existe [tag:gimp] y posiblemente otras similares, lo importante es mantener el mismo criterio para todas las etiquetas.

Comment: Precisamente esto es lo que quiero ilustrar. Si te fijas @blonfu, en la única pregunta de gimp que hay, al final el problema y la solución eran de python, no de gimp. De manera que estuviera haciendo esto fuera o dentro de gimp, lo que el OP necesitaba era ayuda en python.

Comment: @Kenny entiendo eso, también le he dado vueltas a si era necesaria siendo python el lenguaje en el caso de blender y gimp, pero también te pone en contexto. Hay por ejemplo una etiqueta [tag:flexbox] que no es mas que CSS en realidad y es útil para enfocar el problema de forma más específica.