# Sinónimo para la etiqueta [game]

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, desambiguación-etiquetas

Siguiendo con la propuesta de hacer limpieza, que tanto nos gusta(?), propongo crear un sinonimo para la etiqueta [game](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game), el mismo podría ser [videojuego](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/videojuego) o simplemente [juego](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/juego).

Esta etiqueta tiene 24 preguntas, y una buena explicación, por lo tanto vale la pena mantenerla.

Tener una etiqueta en inglés no tiene sentido en el sitio en español.

La hubiera creado yo, pero no tengo ni 5 puntos en esa etiqueta, así que no me deja.

Comment: He visto en esa etiquetas juegos como "tres en raya" y otros que no pueden considerarse como **video**juego asi que prefiero que la etiqueta sea [tag:juego] a secas.

Comment: Eso parecen ejemplos de meta-etiquetas que deben ser borradas antes que sinonimizadas. ¿Qué valor aporta saber que la pregunta es sobre un juego?

Comment: mas alla de que esta pregunta no sea valida aca: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/188903/what-would-be-the-best-way-to-store-movements-on-a-game-to-allow-a-rollback... me gusta mas [tag:desarrollo-de-juegos].. y si, es una meta etiqueta, pero creo que para algunas preguntas agnosticas y bien hechas podria funcionas.. y eso que soy el primero en pedir borrar todo :p

Comment: Sería genial que hubiese preguntas agnósticas y realmente interesantes sobre desarrollo de juegos, y poder agruparlas en una etiqueta... Quizás también podemos aprovechar para limpiar las preguntas con [tag:game] en las que no se trate de un problema de desarrollo de juegos, sino de algo como https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/138927/127 (que estuve a punto de sacarle la etiqueta y no me animé).. y ver cuántas quedan después de la limpieza

Comment: @Mariano ahi vi la etiqueta, y la segui, y no mire todas las preguntas. pero con gusto te las limpio.. :p.. por lo menos aquellas que no sean de juegos reales (una tarea no es un juego real). Copiaria la pregunta que hice, si fuera valida aca :p, tiene muy buenas respuestas y algunos de los comentarios son todavia mejores. tiene mas repercusion que varias de las preguntas que hice aca.

Comment: @gbianchi jajaja dale, aunque creo que es más que si **tratan** sobre un problema de código para un juego, más bien si la pregunta va sobre algo de **teoría** de juegos... Si sigue habiendo mañana, te doy una mano... Y no veo por qué no podrías preguntar eso acá. Fijate en https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/163/127

Comment: podria ser.. lo que pasa es que es terriblemente basada en opiniones. Es mas, estaba pidiendo particularmente la opinion sobre que patron era el mejor. al final me quede con el mas comodo de implementar.

Comment: @gbianchi cambiás "mejor" por más rápido de implementar/eficiente en el uso de memoria/rápido para calcular diferentes estados determinísticos/lo que quieras, y tenés una pregunta que puede pasar (quizás :-)

Comment: Bueno, también revisé las preguntas, dejando **sólo 8** que creo que tratan sobre temas de juegos... dejé el resto sin tocar hasta que se decida qué hacer.

Comment: yo ya habia tocado @Mariano.. y habia dejado algunas.. habria que ver en que casos es valida la etiqueta...

Comment: @gbianchi fijate en mis útlimas ediciones (https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/127/mariano?tab=activity&sort=revisions) cualquier cosa que te parezca mal, podemos abrir un chat y charlarlo

Answer (score 1):

**Hay que editar**. Había 24 preguntas, limpiamos, y sólo quedan 8. Ya sea para eliminar la etiqueta o para renombrarla, es para hacerlo manualmente, no hace falta complicarnos con un sinónimo (no creo que [game](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game) vuelva a aparecer si hay una opción con "juego" en el nombre).

Tengo 2 motivos por los cuales creo que estaría bueno usar una etiqueta y voy a aprovechar para explayarme sobre mi opinión más en general cuando discutimos sobre si una etiqueta es o no una meta-etiqueta (espero que sirva):

**Es un buen agrupador de búsquedas**. Puede estar al límite de ser una meta-etiqueta, no lo discuto, pero me imagino que habrá más de un interesado o experto en el desarrollo de juegos, independientemente del lenguaje. Creo que es útil para [navegar por la etiqueta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/interesting-topics).

Me parece que hay que tener en cuenta que una meta-etiqueta no es simplemente porque no se sostiene por sí misma; el factor principal es que [no describe el ***contenido*** de la pregunta](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/434).

- > Veamos un extremo, por ejemplo [regex](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) es una etiqueta que "no se sostiene por sí misma". No puede haber una pregunta sin que tenga otra etiqueta (definiendo el lenguaje). Y está claro que no es una meta-etiqueta, no por si se sostiene como etiqueta única, sino porque se vale de sí misma para definir el contenido y el alcance de la pregunta.
  >   <sub>- perdón si aburro siempre con el mismo tema :-)</sub>

La definición de qué es una meta-etiqueta en realidad apunta a tratar de clarificar y poner una base en común para un tema más subjetivo: ¿es útil para el sitio y para clasificar el contenido de las preguntas?

No digo que [game](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game) haya sido bien usada hasta ahora, pero sí que puede existir (con un mejor nombre). En SOes (hasta el momento) me parece que no hay mucho movimiento en Desarrollo de Juegos, pero *podría* haberlo, y podría ser una subcomunidad perfectamente... -Me encantaría que crezca y yo ya la estoy poniendo en favoritas.

Veamos la respuesta a [Detectar y destruir objetos que colisionan](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/128691/127). En ésta, [FJSevilla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/15089/fjsevilla) nos deleita con una explicación del uso de [Sprites](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sprite_(videojuegos)) y cómo hacer una fábrica de objetos de juego. Estos son conceptos que van mucho más allá de Python y de la implementación con Pygame, y pueden abstraerse del lenguaje. Este es un ejemplo que le puede interesar a alguien en el campo del desarrollo de juegos. Es por el contenido teórico de la pregunta y respuesta, y no por un error de lógica al detectar una colisión.

¿No les gustaría poder encontrar más fácil este contenido, o filtrarlo si no les interesa? Eso ayudaría a poder encontrar preguntas como [¿Cómo usar la función kbhit() repetidas veces?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/10496/127), que no tienen nada en el título que dé indicios de sobre qué tratan de fondo.

**Define el alcance**. Uno podría argumentar que [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com) es algo [reacio a incluir](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/360795/5290909) preguntas de [gaming](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/gaming/info) (que generalmente van para [Game Development.SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/) o [Software Engineering.SE](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)), pero tengamos en cuenta que las *preguntas conceptuales sobre el desarrollo de software* [están dentro de la temática del sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/163/127).

Las preguntas de desarrollo de software no necesariamente van sobre un problema o un error específico en el código, sino sobre temas conceptuales, metodología, técnicas y algoritmos conocidos y estudiados exhaustivamente. De hecho, el Desarrollo de Juegos es un campo de estudio específico del desarrollo de software. Una etiqueta para el desarrollo de juegos ayudaría a identificar el alcance de la pregunta, ayudando también a evitar un cierre sistemático por pensar que está "*basada en opiniones*" o porque no tienen código (en los pocos casos muy particulares en los que no lo necesiten).

- > No estoy diciendo que sirva como un comodín anti cierre. Los mismos parámetros de todas las preguntas siguen aplicando, obviamente. Solamente creo que sirve para ayudar a ponerle una advertencia a quienes no están al tanto de que una pregunta que no sea sobre un problema específico de código podría estar dentro de los temas tratados en el sitio.

Y el alcance de la pregunta va en dos sentidos: clasifica a la pregunta, pero también determina qué tipo de respuestas se están buscando, qué contenido se está esperando que se responda.

Me parece que estos son motivos importantes que permiten diferenciar si es o no una meta-etiqueta, y que podríamos aplicar en casos similares que se presenten.

Por último, me gustan mucho más [desarrollo-de-juegos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/desarrollo-de-juegos) o [teoría-de-juegos](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/teor%c3%ada-de-juegos) (que identifican diferentes campos), pero da igual cuál se termine usando.

> **Y no todo es desarrollo de juegos**. Seamos muy exigentes al ver una pregunta etiquetada así: el hecho de que sea sobre el código de un juego no alcanza. Si es sobre "*cómo agregarle un método a la clase `MiSuperDisparadorDeBombasToxicasConRayoCongelante`*", sigue siendo lo mismo que con una clase *`CarritoDeCompras`*, o una clase genérica. O lo mismo para la mayoría de las preguntas de [unity3d](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unity3d)... La **pregunta principal** tiene que ser sobre un tema de desarrollo de juegos (teoría o métodos).

Comment: Teoria de juegos es una materia de la universidada (en realidad no) y no aplica a video juegos, si no que es mas compleja. Dejemosla en desarrollo de juegos ;) y hagamos el cambio de etiquetas si este post llega a 10...

Comment: @gbianchi Sí, puse que era otro concepto, sólo di una alternativa para ir por otro camino, pero también prefiero la primera. Y depende qué universidad, tanto desarrollo de juegos como teoría de juegos son disciplinas independientes (estudié teoría de juegos... en Etología), y ambas tienen su contraparte en Programación.

Comment: @gbianchi esta publicación no llega a 10. No hay tantos interesados en ordenar etiquetas... Te apuesto una recompensa de 50 en tu mejor publicación que en 2 meses sigue abajo (-sin hacer trampa!)