# ¿Son válidas las preguntas sobre instalación de sistemas operativos?

Tags: discusión, temática, pregunta-específica

A raíz de [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/150573/como-instalar-drivers-para-acceder-a-red-wifi-en-ubuntu-16-04) y para estar alineado con el criterio de la comunidad es que pregunto: ¿Son válidas las preguntas sobre instalación de sistemas operativos y/o eventualmente hardware? Entendía que no, si bien es cierto que en el marco de lo que [se puede preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), se menciona:

- un problema específico de programación, o
- un algoritmo de software, o
- herramientas de software comúnmente utilizadas por programadores; y es
- un problema práctico, que tiene respuesta y único al desarrollo de software

Y entendiendo que un sistema operativo es en definitiva una "herramientas de software comúnmente utilizadas por programadores", cualquier pregunta que involucre temas de instalación de sistemas operativos serían válidas? ¿Algunas? ¿Todas? ¿Se puede asumir que un Sistema Operativo siempre es una herramienta de desarrollo?

**Nota**: He, encontrado que ya se ha discutido sobre la temática del sitio [aquí](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/definici%C3%B3n-de-la-tem%C3%A1tica-apropiada-para-el-sitio), pero entiendo que no contempla un tema como éste.

Comment: No son válidas, como ya se ha explicado en las respuestas. Pero sí son necesarias. Y en este sitio se juntan quienes preguntan con quienes podrían responder. Es un potencial desperdiciado...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.

La respuesta más cercana se puede encontrar en la publicación de los otros temas discutidos por la comunidad: [uso de aplicaciones de software y componentes de hardware](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/162/127), con -18 votos actualmente.

Por *herramientas de software comúnmente utilizadas por programadores*, nos referimos a temas como por ejemplo un problema con una IDE en particular, algo que encontramos frecuentemente como dificultad al programar, pero no mucho más que eso

Una calculadora también es una "*herramienta de software*" usada por programadores, pero no vamos a estar respondiendo cómo usarla... ¿no? :-)

Comment: Mariano, era lo que suponía, estuve a punto de mencionar otra de las herramientas más comúnmente usadas para programar, el lapiz y el papel ;).

Answer (score 5):

En mi opinion, no.

Pienso que estas preguntas son poco comunes, sin embargo, tambien pienso que el tema es de interes a la comunidad.

La RAE define herramienta como "instrumento", y define instrumento (muy ambiguamente) como "Cosa o persona de que alguien se sirve para hacer algo o conseguir un fin". Con esto quiero ilustrar que quizas tengamos un problema en la frase "herramienta de software". Basicamente eso significa un programa o software. **Quizas debamos cambiarlo a "herramienta de desarrollo de software".**

Pero volviendo al tema, dentro del contexto de que un programador utilice una herramienta para sus fines (que obviamente es programar), un Sistema Operativo no entra en el rango. Lo que si entra son, por ejemplo, editores de texto (consola, graficos, etc), IDES, interpretes, compiladores, etc.

Que el sistema operativo permita usar los recursos disponibles (procesador, memoria) para captar las ideas del usuario por medio de los perifericos de entrada, creo que no mucho tiene que ver con el sitio.

Comment: Me parece que "*herramienta de software comúnmente usada por programadores*" fue intencional, para no excluir a herramientas que no sean de desarrollo per sé, pero que aún estén relacionadas a la programación (Excel, DBMS, Notepad++, .htaccess, entre otros).

Comment: @Mariano Ese es un buen punto, que bueno que puse "quizas" hahaha. Pero me imagino que esta persona lo interpreto como que su SO era su herramienta para desarrollo, lo cual es raro de pensar asi. Quizas: "herramientas enfocadas al desarrollo de software"? No se.

Comment: Coincido Kenny, me parece que un sistema operativo es demasiado ambiguo para considerarlo dentro "herramienta de software comúnmente usada por programadores". Entiendo que un editor de texto también podría ser usado para escribir una novela, pero creo que sin duda habrá consenso que su uso principal es el de editar código de programación.