# ¿Son válidas las preguntas relacionadas a particiones de disco duro?

Tags: discusión, temática

En un publicación un usuario preguntó acerca de si una marca determinada de computadora es buena para programar. Entonces se votó por cerrar señalando que la pregunta debe cerrarse porque no es una pregunta de programación, pero el usuario señaló que en SO si son válidas esas preguntas.

Así que ante ello me puse a investigar entre las preguntas y respuestas de dicho usuario y encontré que él había hecho preguntas similares obteniendo respuesta y también había respondido (muchas con votos positivos).

Así que hice una búsqueda simple con: [`particiones is:question`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=particiones%20is%3Aquestion) encontrando 64 resultados que a simple vista son preguntas relacionadas a problemas con particionar su disco duro, o cómo hacerlo en tal OS. Haciendo un filtrado en encontrado 36 publicaciones con respuestas y 26 con respuestas aceptadas. Además otra cosa a observar es que varias de ellas fueron cerradas como *Principalmente basada en opiniones* que para mí no es la opción correcta.

Así que pregunto: ¿Ese tipo de preguntas son válidas?, si depende ¿En qué casos lo son y en qué casos no?, si no son válidas ¿Cómo podemos solucionar este tipo de problemas? Ya que por la cantidad es difícil que lo maneje la comunidad (al menos eso es lo que pienso).

Relacionado:

- [¿Son válidas las preguntas sobre instalación de sistemas operativos?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3336)

Comment: Bien por abrir el debate, realmente es bastante sorprendente la cantidad de votos negativos que te están dando.

Comment: @fedorqui si pues, a mi tambien me sorprende pero que se va a hacer :-)

Comment: un solo comentario.. hay que recordar que no todo lo que es valido en SO eng, es valido aca. Y tambien en que epoca fueron hechas determinadas preguntas. Hay preguntas muy viejas en SO, que ahora no serian validas y quedaron solamente por motivos historicos

Comment: @gbianchi es válido lo que señalas y lo he tomado en cuenta, si das una vista rápida veras que hay muchas preguntas son del 2018. Por otro lado si son preguntas viejas la tendencia es al menos hacer un bloqueo histórico. Es obvio que SOen tiene diferentes reglas pero hay que delimitarlo entonces ya que sino será dificil distinguir entre lo válido y lo inválido. IMHO las preguntas sobre instalación de SO, particiones de disco duro y temas similares deben ser off-topic

Comment: Relacionado: [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/definici%c3%b3n-de-la-tem%c3%a1tica-apropiada-para-el-sitio), aunque la publicación es algo antigua pienso que algo se podría sacar de ahí, en específico de [esta respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/162/22721). Parece que en ese tiempo la gente no estaba de acuerdo con las preguntas que podrían ir en [su]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### ¿Ese tipo de preguntas son válidas?

Sigo pensando que las preguntas sobre instalación de sistemas operativos son muy difíciles de encuadrar dentro de la temática del sitio. Algunas pocas, tal vez, por lo que mi respuesta es **depende**.

### ¿En qué casos lo son y en qué casos no?

Tal vez con el tiempo podríamos lograr un consenso sobre cuales son válidas y cuales no. Ahora se me ocurren tal vez aquellas que tiene  que ver con la configuración del sistema operativo de servidores de datos o de aplicaciones, y particularmente que traten de un tema de configuración que sea significativo para el funcionamiento de una herramienta relacionada con la programación. Por ejemplo: estamos de acuerdo que las preguntas sobre bases de datos entran dentro de la temática de SOes, preguntar sobre la forma de configurar el SO, el particionamiento y demás temas de instalación, para conseguir una performance apropiada de la base de datos, tal vez podría entrar dentro de los temas a preguntar.

### ¿Como podemos solucionar este tipo de problemas?

Creo que este tipo de preguntas debieran cerrarse, indicando como motivo de cierre el hecho que no se encuadran a la temática del sitio (off-topic).

Comment: Tengo que estar de acuerdo con Patricio. En general, Stack Overflow en Español debe tratar de asuntos sobre programación y sus herramientas. Las preguntas de sistemas (y por supuesto, preguntas sobre marcas concretas de hardware que serían además basadas en opiniones) creo que no tienen cabida.

Comment: @Pikoh ¿Conoces alguna documentación donde se indique claramente los temas que hasta el momento son off-topic u on-topic aquí?

Comment: @eyllanesc hasta donde yo se, no existe ninguna documentación al respecto, básicamente porque lo que sea off o on topic en el sitio es decidido por todos los usuarios en Meta, que es el sitio para discutir estos temas. Lo único que existe es [Sobre que temas puedo preguntar aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) del centro de ayuda, si alguien no me saca de mi error :)

Comment: Estoy pensando que tal vez no sería mala idea poner una pregunta genérica tipo "Puedo preguntar sobre X?", y que en cada respuesta se ponga un tema en concreto. De esa manera, mediante los votos a favor/en contra veríamos la opinión de la comunidad y tendríamos un sitio centralizado para redirigir a quien tuviera dudas +@eyllanesc

Comment: @Pikoh okay, gracias por la respuesta. Una consulta: la configuración de redes como el nateo de puertos ¿Segun tu punto de vista son válidos aquí?, IMHO no lo son ya que 1) no es problema de programación sino de configuración, 2) no es un algoritmo, 3) no es una herramienta de un programador, 4) No es un problema del desarrollo de software

Comment: @Pikoh Pienso que sería una opción sencilla que nos ahorraria trabajo :-)

Comment: @eyllanesc no, en mi opinión no lo sería, ya que sería un tema de configuración de sistemas en nada relacionado con la programación. Pero es únicamente mi opinión

Comment: @Pikoh [tenemos esa pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/161/definici%c3%b3n-de-la-tem%c3%a1tica-apropiada-para-el-sitio) :D Aunque debo admitirlo es algo antigua, me imagino que hoy en día la gente tendrá otra opinión

Comment: @KacosPro :O La cosa es que la conocía,pero la había olvidado. Me la apunto,puede servir para el futuro,gracias :)

Comment: Me parece extraño que nadie haya mencionado la misma pregunta en meta.SOen https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76731/where-do-i-ask-hardware-related-questions en la que claramente se dirige al usuario tanto  a Superuser(para preguntas sobre HW/Configuración en general) y Serverfault (para temas relacionados a configuración y hw de servidores)

Comment: @Killbunny parece que aquí no hay un claro límite de los tipos de preguntas que son válidas aquí, yo pienso que no existen comunidades similares a que mencionas en el idioma español.