# ¿Cuál es el alcance de preguntas sobre infraestructura?

Tags: discusión, temática

¿Hasta dónde deberían considerarse on-topic las preguntas relacionadas con infraestructura? Normalmente se ha dicho en el sitio original que son válidas las que hablen de herramientas para programación o configuraciones específicas que afecten el funcionamiento del código / programa / aplicación.

Sin embargo, como no tenemos ServerFault/SuperUser en español, ¿hasta dónde deberíamos recibir este tipo de preguntas?

Comment: Esta es una bonita discusion.. ojo con que el que mucho abarca, poco aprieta lo unico...

Comment: @gbianchi Tiendo a estar de acuerdo. Si algo, montemos uno de esos SU.es o SF.es para definir todo mejor :)

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con infraestructura?  (ya se han hecho preguntas sobre si están dentro de la temática preguntas sobre particiones del disco duro, instalación de sistemas operativos...) ¿tienes alguna pregunta específica en mente?

Comment: @Rubén cosas que he visto en el último mes como "Hola, estoy arrancando un docker en un EC2 de AWS", "estoy instalando un ubuntu y me da tal error", "configuré el apache así y asá pero no me sale tal aplicación", "nginx como balanceador blablabla".

Comment: En mi opinión personal y en particular considerando que no habrá nuevos sitios en idiomas distintos al inglés hasta nuevo aviso, considero que deberíamos admitir muchas de este tipo de preguntas de lo que no estoy seguro es donde se deberían poner los límites.

Comment: @Rubén pienso igual, pero como señalas hay que definir los límites de alguna manera.

Comment: En mi opinión, permitir este tipo de preguntas es abrir un abanico demasiado amplio. Los usuarios nuevos verían que hay mucha variedad de preguntas y entonces se ampliaría mas. No creo que sea bueno que se vea StackOverflowES como un reddit u otro foro en el que todo sea valido. Siempre se pueden trasladar las preguntas de este tipo a SuperUser en ingles, pidiendo que la traduzcan y mejoren si es necesario y después borrando la pregunta. A mi personalmente no me gusta la idea.

Comment: El ejemplo de hoy: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/273741/como-deshabilitar-modulos

Comment: @Alfabravo En este caso las repuestas tienen que ver con comandos de línea lo cual me parece lo hace estar dentro de la temática del sitio.

Comment: @Ruben La ayuda dice que las preguntas relevantes son sobre "un problema específico de programación, o un algoritmo de software, o herramientas de software comúnmente utilizadas por programadores; y es un problema práctico, que tiene respuesta y único al desarrollo de software". Ahí entran todas las que enumeré en un comentario anterior. Nginx como balanceador? entra. No me sirve el driver en Windows10? Entra. Cómo configuro el módulo xyz en RHEL7? Entra. Porque todo eso lo usamos más o menos a menudo como programadores. De ahí mi pregunta.

Comment: @Alfabravo ¿...?

Comment: @Rubén ¿Podrías ser más específico?

Comment: La pregunta problema de hoy: el modo avión en Ubuntu. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/278438/c%c3%b3mo-hacer-que-ubuntu-reconozca-mi-red-wifi

Answer (score 4):

La pregunta que deberíamos hacernos (de hecho ya se estuvo hablando de esto [aquí](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3336/son-v%C3%A1lidas-las-preguntas-sobre-instalaci%C3%B3n-de-sistemas-operativos)) es que cosas consideramos herramientas de desarrollo. En un sentido muy amplio, una hoja y un papel son las herramientas por excelencia de cualquier programador, pero claro, jamás aceptaríamos una pregunta que se trate de cual es el gramaje adecuado de papel, o las ventajas de usar un lapiz HB sobre el 2H. Obviamente esto es una humorada, pero si es cierto que habría que intentar llegar a un consenso en hasta dónde llegan las herramientas de desarrollo o la problemática relacionada con éstas.

Algunos ejemplos:

> Acabo de instalar Ubuntu x.x.x y me da X error al iniciarse.

Un sistema operativo ¿es una herramientas de desarrollo? si y no. ¿Este problema tiene una relación directa con la temática de programación?. En mi opinión No.

> Estoy particionando un disco para poder instalar X base de datos. ¿Que
>   debería tener en cuenta para maximizar la performance?

Acá la frontera es más difusa. En este caso en mi opinión, si la pregunta está bien formulada, podría ser pertinente.

> Necesito configurar un Apache para agregarle tal funcionalidad

Yo en este caso no tendría dudas, es una pregunta pertinente, de hecho existe la etiqueta `apache`.

> Tengo montado un dominio de Active Directory sobre Windows Server 2012
>   r2 al que le voy añadiendo un servidor de sub-dominio por
>   despacho/departamento. El caso es que tras tener toda la estructura montada con 2012 r2, creo que ha llegado la hora de pasar a 2016 o 2019. ¿Puedo empezar a utilizar 2016 o 2019 en los servidores de sub-dominio
>   que vaya instalando nuevos aún teniendo montado el dominio sobre 2012
>   r2?

En mi opinión NO, es un tema de IT pero que nada tiene que ver con programación

---

Todo esto es materia opinable, lo concreto, hay algunos temas de infraestructura en los que la relación con la programación o con herramientas de desarrollo es nula o no es tan clara, estos casos, no deberían entrar. En el resto de los casos, será la comunidad la que termine definiendo.

Yo creo que sí podríamos empezar a establecer un criterio, pero veo mucho más fácil ir haciéndolo sobre las preguntas que consideremos NO son adecuadas para el Sitio. Podríamos si les parece bien, usar esta pregunta o crear una nueva, para ir agregando respuestas, con ejemplos de preguntas cuya temática claramente consideremos NO es adecuada al sitio.

Comment: Me gusta esta aproximación.

Comment: En general me parece muy bien la respuesta, lo que no me convence es continuar agregando a Meta hilos de colecciones de cosas por medio de respuestas porque cuando se tienen muchas respuestas se vuelve difícil leerlas y encontrarlas. Mejor creemos una pregunta para cada caso que se vaya a discutir y si fuera necesario agreguemos una etiqueta particular para la iniciativa.

Comment: Me parece bien @Rubén, en lo que respecta a mí al menos, cada vez que vea una pregunta que considere fuera de la temática además de votar el cierre trataré de ir editando las respuesta a esta o una nueva pregunta, para agregar el nuevo caso. Cabe la posibilidad que se genere alguna discusión, pero habrá que ir viendo.

Comment: la pregunta de particionar el Disco esta rayando en Basada en Opiniones o búsqueda de sugerencias ...

Comment: Depende cómo se pregunte, la respuesta puede ser una opinión o una respuesta.

Comment: @PatricioMoracho hasta donde tengo entendido; los POST se evalúan por su contenido, Estructura y Pregunta Realizada; no sobre las futuras respuestas ...

Comment: @esta es la manzana de la discordia hoy .... https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/497815/error-de-virtualbox-kernel-driver-not-installed-rc-1908

Comment: @Arcanis-TheOmnipotent, no estoy diciendo eso, digo que las preguntas sobre cualquier cosa pueden llevar el hilo hacía a una opinión o a hacia una respuesta concreta.