# ¿Se responde en SOes a preguntas que no estén estrictamente relacionadas con la programación?

Tags: discusión, temática

Hace un par de días me encontré con [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/282562/es-l-w-%E2%88%88-%E2%88%91-w-termina-en-a-un-lenguaje-regular#comment519500_282562) en el sitio principal.

Me parece una pregunta sumamente interesante pero en aquel entonces pensé que tristemente no estaría relacionada con la [temática del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) (La cual, después de haber revisado y a la luz de la pregunta en cuestión, me parece vaga). Por ello puse un comentario al OP exponiéndole lo anterior y sugiriéndole que buscase ayuda en los sitios en inglés que me parecían más acordes.

He vuelto un par de días más tarde y he visto una [fenomenal respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/282580/57827) de @Abulafia que estaba marcada como aceptada y que tenía una buena cantidad de votos positivos.

Estoy un poco confuso: no sé si es mi juicio el que está mal, las reglas de temática de SOes son laxas o si por el contrario deberíamos especificar que, aunque una pregunta no tenga código como tal ni sea de programación, si está relacionada con la programación, es interesante y está bien redactada será aceptada.

En cualquier caso, me parece que se debería aclarar más este punto. **Yo me posiciono a favor de incluir estas preguntas en el sitio, pero creo que se debería hacer explícito en la ayuda del sitio qué temáticas son apropiadas y cuáles no.**

Comment: A veces me pregunto si habrá suficiente consenso para un sitio de Matemáticas en castellano. No sé si es prudente ampliar SOes para acobijar preguntas como la que te genera el cuestionamiento. Yo mismo opino que la pregunta debe seguir abierta, ya que en sí es una muy buena pregunta, bien formulada, y que muy en el fondo está relacionada con el mundo de la programación, aunque sea netamente teórica. Entiendo también que las reglas, pautas y normas existen por un motivo, y si somos estrictos en estas, tal vez la pregunta debería ser cerrada, muy a mi pesar. Es mi opinión al respecto.

Comment: Un par de comentarios: La temática del sitio no es exclusiva de programación. En [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](/help/on-topic) se especifica que son válidos los problemas específicos de programación, o algoritmos de software, o herramientas de software usadas para el desarrollo, o un problema práctico con respuesta y único al desarrollo de software. Además, que una pregunta no tenga código no quiere decir que no se ajuste a la temática del sitio, en esa misma página se indica que las mejores preguntas siempre suelen tener algo de código, pero no es un requisito obligatorio.

Comment: @DavidDPG ¿En qué sentido consideras vaga la descripción de la temática del sitio? ¿Cómo crees que se podría mejorar?

Comment: relacionada : [¿Cuál es el alcance de preguntas sobre infraestructura?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4202/cu%c3%a1l-es-el-alcance-de-preguntas-sobre-infraestructura)

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro Creo que el hecho de que haya tenido que hacer esta pregunta aún habiendo consultado la página de temática lo deja claro: es muy general y no acota los casos extremos como este.

Comment: Es dificil abarcar todos los casos, siempre habrá preguntas que susciten dudas sobre si entran en la temática o no y habrá que lidiar con ellas de forma individualizada. Por otra parte también creo que esa página de la ayuda da una definición muy general, si se concretara un poco más reduciríamos los casos dudosos.

Comment: Respecto a la pregunta concreta, creo que si tiene cabida en SOes (Está relacionada de cierta forma con programación). Por su parte, tendríamos que preguntarnos que hacer entonces con las preguntas relacionadas con infraestructura o DevOps (Hay bastantes), muchas de ellas han tenido respuestas (Bien puntuadas en SOes) y me parece bien, si se puede apoyar a la gente de la comunidad con temas derivados de la programación (Bases de datos, infraestructura, DevOps, Criptografía, etc).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Creo que estamos en lo límites de lo que es programación o no: Todo lo que son expresiones regulares y lenguajes formales se estudia (o se estudiaba, que uno tiene ya sus años...) en la Ingeniería Informática dentro de *Teoría de Autómatas y Lenguajes Formales*, que era la asignatura previa a *Traductores, Compiladores e Intérpretes*. Es posible que los nombres de las asignaturas cambien de una escuela a otra.

Por tanto esto es una pregunta dentro del ámbito de las ciencias de la computación.

En la versión global esto sería *fuera de tema* porque existe el sitio [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com/?tags=formal-languages), del mismo modo que existen otros exclusivamente para la revisión de código, seguridad, criptografía, ingeniería del software... etc.

En español considero que la pregunta es muy formal y teórica, pero los lenguajes y expresiones regulares son herramientas usadas en la programación, con lo que es válida.