# Que es programar en es.stackoverflow

Tags: discusión

Esta pregunta fue cerrada basada en la opinión:

[Fortigate, convertir interfaz en Software Switch](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/422140/fortigate-convertir-interfaz-en-software-switch/)

Existiendo posibles herramientas que resuelvan el problema del OP:

[Fortigate, convertir interfaz en Software Switch](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/422140/fortigate-convertir-interfaz-en-software-switch/422143#422143)

baso mi argumento en que si son aceptadas preguntas sin codigo basadas en configuraciones de aplicaciones o dispositivos:

[Como se llena el JDBC (JNDI) en CrystalReport 11 para conectarse a SQL Server 2008 R2](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/394063/como-se-llena-el-jdbc-jndi-en-crystalreport-11-para-conectarse-a-sql-server-20/394109#394109)

---

Claramente por desconocimiento de las partes y las opiniones:

Partiendo de que NO toda la programación siempre será aplicada para desarrollar software;
la programación **tambien** puede ser aplicada para configuración de dispositivos o Sistemas u otros software.

**interpretando que:**

una configuración directa se realiza normalmente por comandos o interface de usuario.
y una programación para la configuración se realiza mediante scripting, incluso sobre un archivo de texto, que sera interpretado.

**fuente:**

> La programación es el proceso utilizado para idear y ordenar las
> acciones necesarias para realizar un proyecto, preparar ciertas
> máquinas o aparatos para que empiecen a funcionar en el momento y en
> la forma deseados o elaborar programas para su empleo en computadoras.

[Fuente de Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programaci%C3%B3n)

**Ejemplificación:**
A partir de que un Archivo soporte scripting este pueda ser compilado (como .net), interpretado (como php) sea open-source o comercial (como las configuraciones de dispositivos comerciales), se considera que su implementación es una programación.

Entonces podemos crear Archivos o programas con scripting contenga o no Lógica o secuencia de comandos para que se ejecute como lenguaje de maquina, configurar automáticamente un dispositivo o Sistema Operativo.

Entonces podemos considerar que al igual que: C, bash , php o cualquier otro lenguaje de programación orientada a aplicaciones es separado de la programación orientada a configuración es que esta ultima no contenga instrucciones lógicas; pero si o si la finalidad es automatizar un proceso que un usuario a programado.

- C ejecutan comandos.
- bash ejecuta comandos incluso lo programas en un archivo txt con una extencion predeterminada y modificable.
- php ejecuta comandos incluso lo programas en un archivo txt con una extencion predeterminada y modificable.

**Entonces**

Que es lo que se considera programar en https://es.stackoverflow.com/

Estamos confundiendo la programación funcional con la programación en general?

Estamos segregando la configuración de un dispositivo mediante programación, por que no lo entendemos como tal?

**Update:**
este comentario lo dejo un compañero del chat:

> Buenas.. Hola @FranciscoNúñez, hay zonas grises dentro de la temática,
> recordemos que no hablamos solo de programación, sino de las
> herramientas que sirven para programar, sin esto, preguntas sobre
> definición de índice de tablas, o configuración de editores de texto o
> de base de datos no entrarían.

Comment: Dejando a un lado el tema del que trata la pregunta, el planteamiento de la misma es vaga y literalmente tiene como pregunta _"¿Alguna sugerencia?"_. También podía haber sido cerrada por "Necesita detalles o aclaraciones" o "Necesita ser más específica"

Comment: *Claramente por desconocimiento* -> No lo veo de esa manera. Para mi, igual que para muchos otros, editar un archivo de configuración no es *programar*. Por otro lado, la pregunta está totalmente fuera de lugar, **si bien podría haber sido válida si no fuese porque no tiene dudas con *LA PROGRAMACIÓN***, si no con cómo garantizar una subida correcta: *Mi preocupación es que el nuevo fichero de configuración tenga algún error tipográfico y la carga del mismo resulte en un desastre.*. Esa pregunta podría ser respondida con muchísimo mayor conocimiento en un SE de sysadmin, que se encargan de eso

Comment: @lois6b no estas respondiendo las 3 pregunta de mi post... esta respondiendo o argumentado lo que se dijo en el chat.

Comment: @Benito-B no estas respondiendo las 3 pregunta de mi post... esta respondiendo o argumentado lo que se dijo en el chat.

Comment: Estoy poniendo en un comentario un resumen de mi opinión, que efectivamente ya te di en el chat. No veo ningún motivo para no hacerlo, tu también has argumentado lo mismo que en el chat y no por ello tu pregunta es inválida. Meta está para que **TODA** la comunidad pueda opinar, esta es mi opinión, no veo necesidad de responder a tus tres preguntas, pues creo que estás totalmente equivocado respecto tanto al razonamiento como a que la pregunta sea correcta.

Comment: @Pikoh hay desconocimiento... no de eso no hay duda... por eso traje el post al meta para que se aclaren las 3 preguntas que hago en este post que solo an ignorado...

Comment: @Pikoh no, en realidad cada quien tiene una opinión, pero si vas a opinar sustenta en que se basa o no? yo puedo opinar que python es un invento para reinventar lo que ya puedes hacer en cualquier lenguaje existente... pero es cierto, es lo que opina ES o es lo que se opina a nivel mundial ???

Comment: @Benito-B respeto tu opinión pero no la puedo aceptar para juzgar un post el otro o Este, mi opinión y mi post se basa en documentación de wikipedia que aunque no sea OFICIAL es la opinión MUNDIAL.

Comment: En cuanto a la argumentación a la que te apegas para defender que la pregunta cerrada es válida: *La programación es el proceso utilizado para idear y ordenar las acciones necesarias para realizar un proyecto, preparar ciertas máquinas o aparatos para que empiecen a funcionar en el momento y en la forma deseados*... según eso, cuando pongo la smartTV a grabar un programa, también estoy *programando*? Porque es un proceso utilizado para ordenar las acciones necesarias para preparar cierta máquina para que empiece a funcionar en el momento y forma deseado... A eso nos dedicamos aquí también?

Comment: @Benito-B si preguntas por una herramienta para hacerlo y se usa lenguaje de scripting o camandos para configurar el TV si encajaria...  que tu no sepas o no te dediques a ello no es motivo para decir que no encaja...

Comment: Yo me dedico a programar, y en esa pregunta veo 0 dudas de programación, que es a lo que nos dedicamos aquí. Lo que si veo es una pregunta de *CONFIGURACIÓN*, así que la voto para que se cierre por pertenecer a otro sitio de la red, en concreto veo que esa pregunta sería excelente si se preguntase en [serverFault](https://serverfault.com/), que pertenece a la red de SE pero están especializados en ayudar con la configuración. Que aquí se *podría* responder? Si, supongo. Que allí tienen mil veces más experiencia? Por supuesto! Así que... por qué no hacerla allí? Es la mejor opción para el OP!

Comment: @Benito-B no le van a dar una respuesta por que el quiere programar el archivo Manualmente o mediante alguna herramienta que le deje ver errores de sintaxis... la solución que le darán será similar o igual a la solución que publique yo... que he programados equipos cisco... mediante scripting mesclando C, bash con comandos de consola cisco. a pero como la mayoría lo desconoce lo considera fuera de tema.

Comment: Decir que estamos equivocados, porque desconocemos del tema, ademas de que no es nada agradable, implica un desconocimiento tuyo sobre lo que el resto sabe o no sabe. Sabes si alguien aqui configuro routers? configuro sistemas operativos? Te pediria que en lo sucesivo evites esa clase de comentarios. Ya que como yo no se tu expertise, vos tampoco sabes el de nadie aqui.

Comment: esto no es una simple configuracion de un router @gbianchi no todos los post son agradables incluso aveces haces cuestionamientos desagradables... y deben ser aseptados por tu estatus de moderador... que alguien te diga que desconoces algo o eres ignorante de un contexto, no es insultativo, nadie sabe sobre todo ni es omnipotente... de eso estoy seguro...

Comment: ningun comentario mio debe ser aceptado por nada. No soy dios.. soy un moderador elegido por la comunidad para ayudar con ciertas tareas que los usuarios comunes no pueden hacer. Solamente eso. y si, los cuestionamientos desagradables no van con el sitio. Llamar a alguien ignorante es algo desagradable. Los post que no son agradables, se borran.

Comment: @gbianchi no le veo sentido a todos los comentario que han realizado que se basan en sentimentalismos, si todos tienen suficiente auto estima, madures y conocimiento para determinar que saben y están seguros del motivo por el cual cerraron la pregunta del OP y tienen con que sustentar su Opinión, no deberían sentirse ofendidos por que alguien diga que existió desconocimiento en algunas de las partes al momento de crear o cerrar el POST del OP.

Comment: @gbianchi no le he dicho aquí directamente a nadie que es ignorante. hice este POST para discutir sobre las 3 preguntas que he realizado y se han ido por la tangente del tema... boicoteando los 2 POST

Comment: "Claramente por desconocimiento de las partes" eso esta en a publicacion....

Comment: alguien desconoce algo, no se quien, puede ser el OP, los usuarios viejos los nuevos, que provoco el cierre de la pregunta bajo su opinión que otros tambien aceptaron... por eso yo lo tome de ejemplo y me lo traje al meta, para determinar si es que desconocemos la respuesta a las 3 pregunta que hice...

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Te recomiendo ser amable o escoger mejores palabras o frases para que tus comentarios no sean tomados a mal, a diferencia de una conversación personal las letras no tienen el poder de expresar sentimientos. Al final de todo (aunque no estemos de acuerdo siempre) se decidira por el consenso de la comunidad que en meta esta dado por los votos.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Los conceptos tan simples como programar o que es la vida tienen muchisimas acepciones dependiendo del ámbito donde se pregunte, wikipedia en ese caso da una concepción general cuyo objetivo es que el público genérico(con poco, con ninguna, o con mucha experiencia) entienda, pero ese no es el concepto que se espera en sitios especializados como SO.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Por otro lado una pregunta que pide sugerencias de SW es off-topic en SO, es muy diferente a como configurar algunas de herramientas que usa un programador(a eso se refiere principalmente a IDEs)

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Si dentro de los diversos sitios de SE hay un sitio que se adecue mejor a la pregunta entonces la comunidad lo hara como en tu caso ya lo señalaron.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Si tu consideras que ese tipo de post es adecuado para el sitio entonces sigue respondiendolos pero no reniegues de las consecuencias(votos de cierre y downvotes), igual que tu tienes la libertad de hacerlo los otros miembros de la comunidad puedon tomar sus propias acciones.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Si consideras que la acción es "más mala" por que la hizo un moderador diamantado entonces te puedo asegurar que la pregunta hubiese terminado cerrada de todas formas, prueba de ello es que ningun usuario a votado por reabrirla.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Antes de que comente, se debe entender que es "Fortigate". ¿Es una herramienta para programar? ¿Es un lenguaje de programacion? 2 preguntas sencillas que tienen una respuesta, no. Lo ultimo que comenta el OP, de buscar herramientas de debug, en cierta manera es de programacion porque son "herramientas" de ayuda para "programar", pero no el hecho de comentarlo, toda la pregunta va ser de programacion

Comment: @JuanRivera mira no me interesa si el usuario quiere usar notepad++ para comunicarse con los estraterrrestre **Escribiendo Código en una herramienta de desarrollo**; el OP simplemente quería saber si existía alguna manera de hacer resaltado/debug con una de las herramientas de programación que usemos y para este caso si lo habia... ** y no es una opinión porque son herramientas definidas** , en este caso existe ATOM que tiene soporte para casi todos los lenguajes de configuración de router via un package incluyendo fortigate de ellos...

Comment: @JuanRivera como el lenguaje no es programación pura si no que es configuración de un dispositivo y por que nadie sabia que existía tal utilidad, prefirieron boicotear el post ... esta bien ... asi es como actúa esta comunidad, pero la persona pregunto por una herramienta de desarrollo y gracias a dios le di la solución antes de que cerraran el post.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

@gbianchi y señores de la red, así es como los moderadores, aceptan y aplican las reglas basados en opiniones personales (de varios de la comunidad, en algunos casos hasta la mia) desvirtuando o manipulando el objetivo y reglas generales del sitio... en lugar de aplicarlas tácitamente o aplicando cualquiera de estas para cerrar los POST, en lugar de buscar una viabilidad o apoyo al OP.

Cuando un Usuario viene a realizar una pregunta en esta red es por que realmente necesita ayuda (aunque algunos abusan en lo que buscan).

**Esta pregunta original fue cerrada: por estar fuera de lugar, segun opiniones y el mal planteamiento del OP.**
[Fortigate, convertir interfaz en Software Switch](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/422140/fortigate-convertir-interfaz-en-software-switch/)

**Fue editada por mi persona:** para que encajara en el sitio, ya que el usuario era nuevo y no pudo realizar la pregunta/consulta textualmente correcta como se espera.

**Quedando esto:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Basado en que se brinda apoyo a las solicitudes de Usuarios sobre Herramientas de Desarrollo Comúnmente usadas y es un problema práctico, que tiene respuesta y único al desarrollo de software como dice esta norma del sitio **(no opiniones)**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

### **Solicito la reapertura del POST basado en los siguientes planteamientos**

**investigo y consulto**, veo a @Gbianchi diciendo que una pregunta solicitando **ayuda sobre que funcionalidad utilizar dentro de una herramienta de Desarrollo notepad++ no es aceptada. **

**Pero**  si acepta preguntas de otras herramientas de desarrollo como cristal Report, sobre la configuración de una funcionalidad de conexión a base de datos:

[¿Cómo se llena el JDBC (JNDI) en CrystalReport 11 para conectarse a SQL Server 2008 R2?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/394063/c%C3%B3mo-se-llena-el-jdbc-jndi-en-crystalreport-11-para-conectarse-a-sql-server-2)

**La diferencia**

Radica en que el OP preguntando por **notpad++** quiere saber si existe alguna funcionalidad para usarlo para programar una configuración de un dispositivo.
a lo cual se le dio esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/422143/46896

Mientras que el OP de Cristal Report esta en un desarrollo de Java y se le dio esta respuesta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/394109/46896

*Mismo contexto diferente finalidad.*

**Esto no justifica la decisión, tomada por el/los Moderadores o Usuarios con privilegio de voto de cierre de SOes para cerrar la primera pregunta, no hay imparcialidad, ni objetividad**

**Es mi Opinión y me remito directamente a las normas del sitio y no a opiniones. Saludos**

**Update:**
La satisfaccion del dia de hoy contra toda opinión:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 12):

La respuesta está en el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) y en el apartado [¿Sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) del Centro de Ayuda de StackOverflow en Español.

En primer lugar, la pregunta que mencionas pide *una sugerencia*, y eso ya es un aspecto que implica su cierre:

> Este sitio es para obtener respuestas. No es un foro de discusión. No es un lugar de conversación.

En segundo lugar, en la pregunta planteada no hay un problema real, sólo una especulación:

> Mi preocupación es que el nuevo fichero de configuración tenga algún error tipográfico y la carga del mismo resulte en un desastre.

> He buscado sin éxito herramientas para hacer debug al fichero de configuración antes de cargarlo en real.

Claramente no hay un problema, sino la especulación de que probablemente ocurra algo. Me pregunto si la carrera espacial hubiera tenido éxito sin el método científico por excelencia: *ensayo y error*.

Ante esto, el Centro de ayuda nos dice:

> Concéntrate en las preguntas sobre un problema real con el que te hayas encontrado. Incluye los detalles sobre lo que intentaste y lo que estás intentando hacer exactamente.

Por último, el Centro de Ayuda nos da la bienvenida sí y sólo sí:

> Creemos que las mejores preguntas en Stack Overflow tienen siempre un poco de código pero si tu pregunta es acerca de…

> - un problema específico de programación, o
> - un algoritmo de software, o
> - herramientas de software comúnmente utilizadas por programadores; y es
> - un problema práctico, que tiene respuesta y único al desarrollo de software

> … ¡entonces estás en el lugar correcto para preguntar!

La clave está en la última linea (frase) de la lista:

> **y es** un problema práctico, que tiene respuesta ...

Existe un apartado en los motivos de cierre que también se podría aplicar como causal de cierre de la pregunta que enlazas:

> **La pregunta está buscando recomendaciones de libros,herramientas,librerías u otros recursos externos.**
> Estas preguntas tienden a recibir respuestas basadas en opiniones

Y es que en la pregunta, el OP da muestras de estar buscando alguna sugerencia sobre *herramientas*:

> He buscado sin éxito herramientas para hacer debug al fichero de configuración...

Ante todo esto, y aún sin responder tu pregunta, lo que el OP plantea está muy lejos de ser una pregunta aceptable para el sitio.

En cuanto a la duda planteada por ti: **¿Qué es programar en es.stackoverflow?**, no puedo darte una respuesta que ssatisfaga a todos y cada uno de los que lean esto. Pero creo que hay una gran diferencia entre escribir código usando algún lenguaje (interpretado o no, incluso el pseudo código es válido) y escribir un archivo de configuración (`ini`, `cnf`, o el que gustes). Si programar es algo tan simple, en haras de la funcionalidad de un sistema, entonces yo puedo ser un *chef* en un restaurant con estrellas *Michelín* sólo por haber puesto agua a hervir. Si, con esa agua se prepará algún plato, tal como con ese archivo se configurará un dispositivo.

Claramente **programar**, en el entorno de StackOverflow en Español, requiere mucho más que una especulación o una sugerencia. Requiere aplicar lógica para la resolución de un problema práctico y real. Un problema al que ya te has enfrentado y has obtenido un error o un resultado no deseado o esperado. Un problema que puedes explicar con detalle, incluso que puedes reproducir. Y todo eso se observa en lo que dice el *recorrido* y el Centro de Ayuda del sitio.

Comment: me sorprende ver tantos votos positivos en un post con 2 minutos que requieres mínimo como 10 minutos para leerlo; voy a leerlo con calma y hare mis comentarios.

Comment: Mira Existen excepciones cuando la pregunta esta basada en uso de Herramientas comunmente usadas por programadores: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/394063/c%C3%B3mo-se-llena-el-jdbc-jndi-en-crystalreport-11-para-conectarse-a-sql-server-2

Comment: segundo la pregunta fue editada: para que encajara en el sitio: https://i.stack.imgur.com/42HG8.jpg

Comment: y la respuesta acorde a la pregunta realizada: https://i.stack.imgur.com/42HG8.jpg

Comment: herramientas de software comúnmente utilizadas por programadores; y es

Comment: estas confundiendo la exteriorisacion de un sentimiento con la consulta real: Consulta He buscado sin éxito herramientas para hacer debug/resaltado a los comandos del fichero tal cual lo hacen los editores como notepad++ al programar comandos en otros lenguajes de configuración, quiero hacer esto antes de cargarlo en real.

¿Existe alguna configuración a los editores oficial o no oficial (Herramientas de programación) para que me ayude en esto?

Comment: te dejo el contexto completo del pro que de las cosas

Answer (score 6):

Con respecto a:

> Que es programar en es.stackoverflow

Que yo sepa, en el sitio, no hay ninguna definición "oficial" al respecto, por lo que podría decirte que: "*programar en SOes, es lo que la comunidad considera que es programar"*, para algunos escribir código CSS no es programar, para otros editar configuraciones tampoco, pero más allá que sea o no programar, normalmente son procesos o actividades que suelen estar relacionadas a la temática del sitio, a herramientas o procedimientos relacionados con la actividades de un desarollador.

> Estamos confundiendo la programación funcional con la programación en
> general?

No lo creo.

> Estamos segregando la configuración de un dispositivo mediante
> programación, por que no lo entendemos como tal?

Puede ser, dependerá de la forma en que se pregunte o de lo que se pregunte. Imposible saberlo de antemano. Ahora, a **mi criterio, la pregunta que generó toda esta discusión, no es para esta comunidad**. En la vida real, gran parte de mi área de incumbencia es el desarrollo de software, si un usuario me viene a preguntar por la configuración de un firewall, lo mando a hablar con la gente de redes, si alguien me pregunta como configurar un ODBC seguramente lo ayude. No se trata de buena o mala voluntad, hay ciertas cosas que manejan mucho mejor ciertos profesionales, un parte importante de ser profesional es reconocer esto y asesorar adecuadamente, derivando incluso al especialista adecuado.

¿Preguntas sobre como configurar el INI de un dispositivo o sobre herramientas de validación de sintaxis o patrones, podrían ser preguntas válidas para SOes? Si, claro, pero dependen del contexto de la pregunta, y entiendo que en este caso, el contexto no es el adecuado, el problema sigue siendo la configuración de un firewall. ¿Esto quiere decir que cuando se pregunte sobre configuración de hardware o sistemas operativos en general, la pregunta esta fuera automáticamente de la temática del Sitio? Si, no, depende, se evaluará por la comunidad en su momento, pasará el filtro o eventualmente no, esto es algo que ya se ha [discutido](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3336/son-v%C3%A1lidas-las-preguntas-sobre-instalaci%C3%B3n-de-sistemas-operativos) hace tiempo.

¿Todo esto implica que hay que ser antipático con los usuarios noveles, "expulsarlos"  de sitio y no brindarles una ayuda? Para nada, podemos derivarlos amablemente mediante los comentarios "*Mira, tu pregunta no es la más adecuada en cuanto a la temática para esta comunidad, por que no intentas en [sitio o foro] dónde hay mas experiencia en lo que estás preguntando"* o incluso, se pude ayudar mediante los mismos comentarios *"tu pregunta lamentablemente no es para esta comunidad, pero de todas formas quiero ayudarte: por que no haces A o B"*. O ciertamente, también nada te impide responder de todas formas, ignorando los criterios generales de la comunidad, pero habrá que lidiar luego con la frustración de una respuesta que eventualmente termine cerrada o los votos negativos que algunos usuarios dan para desincentivar este tipo de respuestas (criterio que igual yo no comparto).

Con respecto a tu otra respuesta quiero decirte

- En este tema en particular, comparto totalmente la decisión de gbianchi, si hubiera tenido una pregunta como esta en la cola, seguramente hubiera votado para cerrarla, o bien por la temática o bien por que esta basada en opiniones.
- Con respecto a las normas, las leo y (lo siento), pero no interpreto lo mismo que tú. En mi opinión apoyan la idea que esta pregunta no es para esta comunidad. Las leyes son las leyes, hasta que las interpretan los jueces.

Comment: Excelente respuesta Patricio. Como moderador en este caso he tratado de no inmiscuirme para tratar de que el OP abriera los ojos al ver el criterio de la comunidad y no nos acusara de imponer nuestro criterio arbitrariamente, aunque lamentablemente parece que no es posible. Comparto totalmente tu opinión en este tema, y si hubiera respondido habría dicho algo muy similar.

Comment: no tiene sentido lo que argumentan: **CSS** no es un lenguaje de programación ni **HTML**; pero si se aceptan preguntas de estos lenguajes de Marcado.

Comment: pero si alguien pregunta por un lenguaje **no popular** como lenguajes de configuración de dispositivos lo acribillan de votos negativos; si se trata de preguntar por una **herramienta de desarrollo** que tenga la funcionalidad de soportar HTML y CSS o Reporting, si son aceptadas, pero si se busca que soporte lenguaje de configuración ... no es aceptada... entonces que tiene mas peso: **una norma escrita en el sitio aprobada por la comunidad** o **8 votos basados en opiniones personales**???

Comment: @Pikoh aunque el OP Este preguntando por algo que naturalmente si se hace desde una interface de Usuario estaria ubicado en otro Sitio el men horiginalmente esta preguntando por una herramienta de desarrollo que le de soporte al lenguaje de configuracion; eso es correcto por que no todos sabesmos que funcionalidad tienen las herramientas de desarrollo. no es basada en opiniones por que claramente puedo hacer una lista de funcionalidades basadas en fuentes oficiales.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez traté de explicártelo en el chat, y como no te convencieron mis explicaciones, te propuse preguntar a la comunidad aquí en meta. La comunidad ha respondido de forma clara, pero tu sigues en tu cruzada personal considerando que tu tienes razón y el resto del mundo está equivocado. Eres muy libre de hacerlo, pero personalmente tengo otras ocupaciones a las que dedicar mi tiempo. Por mi parte este tema está zanjado y te agradecería que no me mencionaras para nada mas sobre este tema. Si tienes alguna queja mas, te recomiendo que la eleves al equipo de StackExchange . Un saludo.

Answer (score 5):

Tu reclamo central de que "aplican las reglas basados en opiniones personales". Eso es una característica común a todos los sistemas de gobierno, grandes y pequeños.

Las leyes no son algo que el gobernante (o moderador) este obligado a ejecutar; es más bien un conjunto de herramientas de las cuales se echa mano a conveniencia para implementar su proyecto de gobierno.

Tampoco podría ser de otra manera. Si la policía tuviera que multar a toda la gente mal estacionada, no tendrían otra cosa que hacer el día entero. Por tanto, la policía elige **no** aplicar las reglas excepto en situaciones excepcionales.

Es una situación arbitraría comúnmente aceptada. Las reglas no son coherentes en ningún sistema. Tampoco cubren todos los casos. El legislador tampoco podía anticipar desarrollos futuros o los cambios sociales.

O sea, hay un montón de zonas grises, mal cubiertas, ignoradas, o regidas por reglas contradictorias.

La solución social, como ocurre aqui en SOes es confiar en el criterio y sentido común de quienes las aplican, y dejar que las dinámicas del poder entre gobernantes y gobernados dictamine finalmente donde están los limites entre lo permitido y lo prohibido.

Así veo yo lo que llamas "opinión personal".

Comment: estas equivocado en esto: "Las leyes no son algo que el gobernante (o moderador) este obligado a ejecutar;" si lo estan... o de lo contrario seria una dictadura... incluso el moderador debe apegarce a la norma no a la opinion... por que la norma fue levantada por la comunidad...

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Claro, y el sentir de la comunidad es que no es un problema de programación.

Comment: como lo explique en mi respuesta la comunidad no solo atiende problemas de programación según la norma que hizo la comunidad tambien debe atender funcionalidades de las herramientas de programación ... aunque se terminen usando para freir huevo o comunicándose con extraterrestres ...

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez. Hacer cumplir las leyes tiene costos y los recursos son acotados. Por tanto, tienes que elegir que vas a cumplir y que no.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4RSW.jpg

Comment: mira todo el desgaste de hoy en justificar cerrar una pregunta no era mas facil dejarla abierta entonces menos desgaste menos gasto de recurso???

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez. Mira quien habla.

Comment: me parece que si vas a invertir el tiempo/recurso que sea para hacerle el bien a la persona no para hacerle daño... como tu mismo lo dices una pregunta que ya tenia respuesta aceptada por el OP. el mayor esfuerso lo hice yo lo demas solo llegaron a leer y darle reportar...

Comment: esta es mi satisfacción ante todo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJKOP.jpg

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez. Trabaje 10 años en Sistemas. Lo que el quiere no existe.  O sea, no hay forma de ayudarle.

Comment: como que no si el mismo lo dijo que lo he ayudado ... mira la imagen y el chat...

Comment: abecés no lo sabemos todo... no importa cuantos años tengas en algo siempre hay algo nuevo que aprender. y la mejor virtud del ignorante es buscar ayuda y conocimiento.

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez por favor no califiques las acciones de la comunidad en base si se va a "hacer el bien" o no, en SO no tiene sentido ello, por ejemplo ¿los votos de cierre para ti no son "hacer el bien"?¿los *downvotes* son "hacer el mal"? Pues no, aqui son medidas que cada usuario puede tomar si cumple las reglas de SO. SO tiene como objetivo tener una coleccion de Q&A de calidad, y la consecuencia de implementar esa colección es la ayuda, no al reves.