# Es un buen momento para actualizar en el Recorrido las indicaciones sobre qué preguntar y qué no

Tags: discusión, estado-completado, recorrido

Estaba haciendo una revisión de varias cosas, sobre todo porque veo muchas preguntas que no deberían estar y aparecen una atrás de la otra.

Entonces, se me ocurrió mirar el [recorrido del sitio](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la sección sobre qué preguntar es ambigua y confusa. Como se ve en la imagen, actualmente incluye:

> Preguntar sobre...
>
> - Problemas específicos con Stack Overflow en español
> - Problemas o preguntas reales con los que te encontraste

> No preguntes sobre...
>
> - Cualquier tema que no esté directamente relacionado con Stack Overflow en español
> - Preguntas que se basan principalmente en opiniones
> - Preguntas con demasiadas respuestas posibles o que requerirían una respuesta muy extensa

Según eso, puedo preguntar casi cualquier cosa, porque es una pregunta real con la que me encontré.

Creo que algo se nos perdió en algún lado.

la sección de no preguntes sobre, también... ¿Qué cosas son las que no puedo preguntar? Salvo lo de opiniones, o la de demasiadas respuestas (¿no seria lo mismo que basada en opiniones?) está confusa.

Entonces, abrí el [recorrido en Stack Overflow en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Queda claro qué se puede y qué no se puede...

Entonces, basado en todo esto, inicio la encuesta para modificar todo esto, que a mi entender, es cualquier cosa menos claro.

Se podría decir que la opción uno es copiar textual lo que está en inglés, pero obviamente, escucho opiniones...

Comment: estoy de acuerdo... entre mas especifico sea menos confusiones ... y de paso si es posible a cada linea del recorrido agregarle su respectivo link de ayuda...

Comment: Por algún lado incluye este enlace: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Cada vez veo más preguntas con un potencial de mejora tremendo :D

Comment: Me parece bien, como primer paso seria la traduccion al español y como segundo si se puede agregar mas cosillas

Comment: Me parece correcto. Eso sí, habría que acotar un poco esta pregunta, con propuestas concretas, para que tenga algún resultado.

Comment: @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar' te referis a esta pregunta? yo escucho ideas.. por mi copio las que estan en ingles...

Comment: Estoy de acuerdo  pero yo añadiría también preguntas sobre bases de datos, he encontrado preguntas donde el usuario pide que se le revise su diagrama entidad relación, o preguntas que tienen que ver con indices, en general con bases de datos, esto enriqueceria el primer punto "specific programming coding", ya que igualmente problemas específicos de programación queda muy general en mi opinión, no se si también seria factible preguntas de perfil teórico, por ej cual es la diferencia entre una propiedad pública y otra privada(es un ejemplo tonto, simplemente espero que se entienda la idea),

Comment: que ambiguo _Problemas específicos con Stack Overflow en español_ es hora de un level-Up

Comment: No preguntes algo como: _Ayudaaa mi profe me pidio el siguiente enunciado ..... es para hoy_

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo. La confusión de lo que se debe o no se debe preguntar complica también la limpieza del sitio porque provoca que no todos se pongan de acuerdo.

Answer (score 16):

Hasta ahora, escribiríamos lo siguiente:

> Pregunta sobre...
>
> - Problemas específicos del desarrollo de software
> - Principios/patrones de diseño, algoritmos y estructuras de datos
> - Técnicas de programación
> - Herramientas/plataformas para desarrollo y despliegue de software
> - Manipulación de datos
>
> No preguntes sobre...
>
> - Cosas de las que no hayas buscado una solución (¡muestra tu trabajo!)
> - Recomendaciones sobre productos, servicios, librerías o herramientas
> - Requerimientos de listas, encuestas, opiniones, discusiones o cosas que no tengan una respuesta única
> - Cualquier cosa que no sea inherente a la creación de software
> - Enunciados de ejercicios, sin demostrar que se intentó resolver el ejercicio (no es suficiente con escribir una línea de código, ¡debes demostrar tu trabajo!)

Si tienen opiniones, mas respuestas, o si no, comentarios!

Comment: Si, más menos las cosas irían por ahí,  digamos que esas son las reglas para preguntar, pero como tal eso no evitaría que haya usuarios(sobre todo los nuevos) que pregunten algo que no tiene nada que ver con el sitio ya que muchos vienen a la comunidad a resolver su problema y poco les interesa leerse el recorrido , quizá también haya que poner estas reglas en la pantalla de formulación de preguntas, además de en el recorrido ya que el recorrido puede ser accedido opcionalmente,  pero la pantalla de formulación de preguntas si la ven completa todos los usuarios

Comment: En no preguntar dice sobre recomendaciones de **herramientas** y en lo que se puede preguntar dice **herramientas para desarrollo de software**. Lo último sería sobre cómo funcionan los IDE de desarrollo?

Comment: eso seria para diferencias entre por ejemplo git, y otra cosa es preguntar con que ide puedo hacer X cosa... se entenderia @Bicho

Comment: Supongo que con esto, la pregunta que se hizo hace tiempo tambien sera respondida no? https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5000

Comment: @JuanRivera pero esa pregunta tiene montones de respuestas.. a que te referis?

Comment: El primero lo pondría como: *Problemas específicos sobre desarrollo de software*; el segundo como: *Principios/patrones de diseño, algoritmos y estructuras de datos* y el cuarto: *Herramientas/plataformas para desarrollo y despliegue de software*.

Comment: @E.Betanzos a ver.. revisa que lo modifico

Comment: Así me parece excelente!!

Comment: Creo que "codificación tiene un significado distinto del que buscamos, ¿qué tal "Técnicas de programación"? Otras cosas que cambiaría serían: "Cosas para las que no hayas buscado una solución (¡demuestra tu trabajo!)"; y "Enunciados de ejercicios, sin demostrar que intentaste resolverlo (no es suficiente con una línea de código, de nuevo, ¡demuestra tu trabajo!)", en realidad el paréntesis del último podría ser sencillamente "(de nuevo, ¡muestra tu trabajo!)"

Comment: @ArianJM queria evitar ejercicios donde OP llega y pone solamente las cabeceras de sus funciones y con eso dice que ya hizo algo...

Comment: @gbianchi, ¿que hace falta hacer para que esto se implemente ASAP?

Comment: @Marcos nada, lo puedo editar yo.. solo espero un poco mas de consenso para no estar cambiandolo a cada rato

Comment: Veo que ya se actualizó, ¡bien! Habría que corregir un poco la ortografía y demás, eso sí :)

Comment: sabes que tengo problemitas con eso.. asi que te escucho!!!!! @fedorqui'SOdejadedañar'

Comment: @gbianchi En el último ítem, donde dice "sin demostrar que se intento" debería ser "sin demostrar que se intentó" (tilde en intentó) y donde dice "escribir una lineal de código" supongo que debería ser "línea" (con tilde también). También faltaría el signo '¡' antes del '!', en inglés se usa solo el ! pero en español no se considera válido