# ¿Debemos admitir preguntas sobre alquiler/hosting de dominios?

Tags: discusión

Ayer un usuario realizó esta pregunta:

[¿Cómo registro un dominio sin depender de terceros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/460974/15301)

Cerré dicha pregunta basándome en el hecho de que no tenía en mi opinión absolutamente ninguna relación con la programación. Sería una pregunta asimilable a sitios de la red como Serverfault o Webmasters probablemente, pero en ningun caso para StackOverflow.

A raiz de esa pregunta, otro usuario creó esta pregunta autorespondida:

[¿Es posible Obtener un Dominio del ICAAN sin el servicio de terceros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/460994/15301)

Para mi sigue siendo una pregunta totalmente fuera de tema en el sitio, pero lo cierto es que la pregunta ha tenido cierta acogida positiva, por lo que antes de tomar alguna decisión me gustaría saber cual es la opinión de la comunidad sobre este tipo de preguntas. ¿Debemos admitirlas, o deben ser cerrada por estar fuera de tema?

Comment: Mi opinión sobre la validez de la pregunta que tuvo aceptación por la comunidad se resume en una frase: *No lo sé Rick, parece falso*.

Comment: Considero que sí esta fuera de tema, porque la pregunta no tiene que ver con programación directamente pero, a la vez, forma parte del setup del programador y "tener un dominio en internet" es una herramienta indispensable, en algunos casos, para hacer pruebas.

Comment: La documentación relacionada encontrada en internet en español es pobre, solo la tocan en la misma web de la ICAAN en inglés.

Comment: Entonces hay una serie de preguntas alrededor como configurar mis herramientas alrededor de un dominio y otras sobre adquirir este dominio, la pregunta no esta basada en opiniones y creemos que beneficia a la comunidad de desarrolladores y por ende no debe ser eliminada o cerrada.

Comment: pero como sabemos esta en manos de la "comunidad"

Comment: @FranciscoNuñez puedes explicar por que has eliminado tu respuesta para añadirla como comentarios? Y que significa "comunidad" entre comillas?

Comment: por que era una opinión no una respuesta, pues hace referencia a todos los participantes... Actuales aunque la comunidad es mucho mas grande.

Comment: Es la misma opinion en comentarios como en una respuesta. Esto es meta,se supone que las respuestas son opiniones. No tiene nada que ver los votos negativos que tu respuesta tenía?

Comment: no , para nada, he tenido respuestas con mas votos negativos y he seguido sosteniendo mi punto como resolución...

Comment: @Pikoh mira aqui: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5002/46896

Comment: Eso no contesta a la pregunta. Tampoco has respondido que significa poner "comunidad" entre comillas. De todas maneras,no voy a entrar en discusion alguna contigo. En mi opinion,tu forma de actuar en el sitio choca mucho con mi vision de las cosas,asi que personalmente trataré de interactuar lo menos posible contigo,exceptuando por supuesto lo que me requiere mi condicion de moderador.

Comment: "Comunidad" hace referencia a todos los participantes Actuales aunque la comunidad es mucho mas grande... y muchos no participan del meta...

Comment: no entiendo a que te refieres con: "tu forma de actuar" y "mi vision de las cosas" hasta donde me han explicado las cosas son como la comunidad lo decide no al gusto o la visión de una personas en particular. si hay algo que te molesta personalmente eres libre de exprésalo sea aquí en publico o en privado en un room, yo no estoy aquí para imponerme, pero si trato de expresar mi opinión dentro del marco y las normas que ha ido fabricando la comunidad en el paso del tiempo.

Comment: No sabía que para usar SE era requisito saber inglés. Muy educados y privilegiados quienes cierran la puerta diciendo "aprendan inglés o usen google". Ahora resulta que sólo los universitarios programan. Yo creo que ni los amigos en España, europeos como son, van a ser excluyentes como más de un iberoamericano que anda dando portazos de esta forma.

Comment: @Pikoh En realidad la titulación del tema es incorrecta. Debería ser "¿Es posible registrar un dominio en ICANN de forma directa, sin terceros?". Es confuso porque pense que apuntaba mas a a un tema de como "desarrollar un whois sin servidores externos" o algo similar, pero se trata de conocer como hacer un tramite administrativo y no informático.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Deben cerrarse cuando es claro que pertenecen a otro sitio.

Un desarrollador de software tiene relación con temas como: programación,  servidores, alojamiento, bases de datos, redes, etc.

La red Stack Exchange tiene muchos sitios dedicados a diferentes áreas de TI. El que estén en inglés no debería ser ningún impedimento para hacer consultas ahí.

El manejo intermedio del inglés es un requisito obligatorio para todo programador que quiera avanzar en su carrera, esperar documentarse solo en español impone muchas limitaciones.

Dicho eso, este sitio tiene el mismo propósito que el StackOverflow original y que esté en español no significa que deba cargar con las preguntas que pertenecen claramente a los otros sitios en inglés.

Comment: no compares SOes con SO... la verdad es que haya aceptan un abanico de preguntas mas amplio que aqui, incluso he visto pregunta sobre configuracion de servidores existiendo serverfault entre otro largo etc...

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez-TodoPoderoso "aceptan un abanico de preguntas mas amplio que aqui"... Mi experiencia es la contraria. Allá admiten menos temas y preguntas que aquí porque hay otros sitios de la red de StackOverflow (en inglés) que son más apropiados. Aquí tendemos a ser más permisivos con ciertos temas que en SO serían cerrados por "pertenece a otro sitio de la red."

Comment: Esta pregunta es sobre configuración de servidores: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67967674/laravel-websockets-reverse-proxy-port-nginx-config-to-apache-virtual-host

Comment: y así hay muchas mas... implementacion de extenciones de terceros como CEF https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58024079/cefsharp-in-vsto-addin visual Studio addon, Como **Herramienta de Desarrollo...**

Comment: preguntas sobre compilar C/C++ en **Visual Code No Cerradas**: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64419619/cant-compile-c-in-vscode
Implementando la Terminal y comandos

Comment: Lo que ustedes catalogan como fuera de tema haya por lo menos lo dejan existir... para ver si alguien le responde al OP por que indirectamente esta Relacionado al Desarrollo. sigo pensando en alguna doble moral... pero no se ... lo que sea mejor para la "Comunidad" y elegido por la "Comunidad" me imagino que es lo correcto...

Comment: Como lo dices haya en Teoría (Cosa que no veo) deberían aceptar menos preguntas por que existen mas Sitios **en Ingles** especializados, los latinos que tenemos???

Comment: El propósito de fomentar la aplicación de las reglas es para mantener las cosas en el mayor orden posible, pero como en todo sistema con reglas, siempre habrá excepciones permisivas y también injusticias. Con respecto a las excepciones, para eso se convoca a la comunidad, para conocer su postura al respecto y decidir si se agrega la nueva excepción o no. Y en relación la pregunta: **¿Los latinos qué tenemos?** Mi respuesta es que tenemos acceso a todos esos sitios especializados.

Comment: Un millón por ciento de acuerdo. El hecho que no exista es."cómo programar una secadora".stackoverflow.com no significa que haya que aguantar preguntas que empobrecen el sitio únicamente porque la gente es muy perezosa para googlear. Y google no sólo está en español sino que ofrece traducir simplemente clickeando botón derecho.

Comment: Se creó SOes precísamente para no excluir a los que entraban a SO y quedaban en las mismas. Es absurdo cerrar la puerta de esta forma.

Comment: @alfabravo SOes se creó precisamente para tener un sitio sobre *programacion* como SO para la comunidad de habla hispana,afortunadamente. No debemos admitir preguntas no relacionadas porque no haya ese recurso en Español. No se cierra la puerta al que no habla ingles,se cierra la puerta a preguntas no relacionadas con la programación.

Answer (score 0):

Parce, no estamos para dar clases de redes pero sí son cosas con las que lidiamos a diario para el quehacer (los que vivimos de esto). SOes existe y salió de incubadora, persiste y ha crecido porque hay tantísimos interesados como para mantenerlo activo y relevante. Además, porque se sienten más cómodos preguntando y respondiendo en español.

Ya el debate de cerrar, reabrir y demás, es el mismo que con cualquier otra pregunta (y hay preguntas en meta sobre eso). Mi opinión, muy personal, es que deberían pasar si son canónicas o si están en la esquina de una actividad propia de programar (*estoy subiendo un sitio*, *estoy configurando el proxy*, etc.). Hablar de cosas como *vamos a terminar aceptando preguntas sobre cómo soldar un puerto ISA a una board microATX* es querer causar miedo infundado y no es real. Aunque parezca una zona gris, no es tan difícil. Preguntar por la mejor libreta para hacer pseudocódigo o poner pasta térmica no son actividades que se hagan al montar un sitio o al configurar un WINS.

Lo mismo, una cosa es la pereza de traer las tareas y otra *la supuesta pereza de no saber inglés*.

La respuesta no puede ser "intenten en inglés" porque eso deslegitima por completo la intención inicial de crear este lugar. Así como yo no los voy a mandar a crear un superuser en español porque ya hace rato se aclaró que, por ahora, no va a pasar.

Las leyes no existen en el éter; existen porque son acuerdos comunitarios pa hacer las cosas de cierta forma y evitar otras. Pero la gente existió antes que las leyes.

PD. Insisto en lo que puse en un comentario: olvídense que sólo los PhD, M.Sc programan. Poner una barrera de idioma en SE **pidiendo un idioma diferente al permitido en un sitio** es ridículo.

Comment: Por una parte,estoy de acuerdo en que "mandar a aprender inglés" no es la forma de responder a estas cuestiones. Pero solo porque no haya un sitio apropiado en español,no significa que se deban admitir todas las preguntas. Nuestros equipos son tambien parte de nuestro trabajo y supongo que estamos de acuerdo en que no debemos admitir preguntas sobre como se pone pasta termica en el procesador. SOes es un sitio de programación,y en mi opinion configurar un proxy no es programación. Y mucho menos elegir un hosting o comprar un dominio. Gracias por tu opinión de todas formas :)

Comment: @Pikoh ¿Elegir un hosting? No porque es una opinión. ¿Hacerle debug al hosting? Tampoco porque no somos soporte del hosting. ¿Revisar una configuración de un DNS que no deja ver un sitio? Aquí ya estamos hablando de algo interesante y sin opiniones. ¿Pasta térmica? No porque no está en ninguna esquina del proceso. Intentas llevarlo al absurdo pero tus ejemplos no funcionan bien y tus supuestos casos de terror se resuelven fácil con los lineamientos actuales.

Comment: No se si has leido la pregunta que ha motivado esta publicacion. Trata exclusivamente sobre como "montar" un dominio de internet sin pasar por las empresas registradoras. Todavía no te he leido una opinion sobre si es o no admisible en el sitio. Has hablado sobre generalidades de temas como bien dices ya tratados con anterioridad. Y no,no intento llevarlo al absurdo, simplemente he puesto un ejemplo que claramente esta fuera de tema para ejemplificar que no todo lo relacxonado con la informatica como la computacion es programación. Y no,la configuración de un DNS no es programacion.