# Preguntas sobre modelos relacionales/entidad-relación

Tags: discusión, preguntas, temática

Viendo esta pregunta [Cómo hago un diseño de base de datos sin redundancia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/207034/c%c3%b3mo-hago-un-dise%c3%b1o-de-base-de-datos-sin-redundancia) me queda claro que faltan muchos datos para responderla, pero antes de pedir al OP una aclaración me vino la duda de si aún con todos los datos sería on-topic una pregunta sobre lo que en el fondo es un modelo relacional.

A favor:

- Es una parte importante del desarrollo de cualquier software. Hay veces que duele ver cuando te describen en las preguntas un modelo de tablas que no cumplen ninguna normalización y que tiene toda la pinta de ser de sistemas en producción.

En contra:

- Suelen ser preguntas bastante amplias, que necesitan bastantes detalles.
- Los modelos relacionales no tienen una única solución "correcta" y que se pueda probar; puede haber varios modelos relacionales que respondan a la misma solución. Y los fallos que tengan puede que solo se vean en la implementación o mantenimiento del sistema, y a menudo vendrán por detalles que la gente que responda no conozca.
- Hasta donde yo sé, no son on-topic en ningún otro sitio de *stackexchange*.

¿Opiniones?

Comment: para intentar objetivizar, a parte de los detalles yo pediria tambien que el propio usuario haya barajado un par de opciones ( incluso parciales ) y que explique lo que busca, para poder contestarle qué le falla/falta a su planteamiento para que el modelo cumpla los requerimientos del negocio y uso de su bd.

Comment: Una db siempre depende de las reglas de negocios. y las reglas de negocios pueden ser un documento de 120 paginas. hay que tener en cuenta, que podriamos modelizar 3 o 4 tablas, pero eso no implica que en el modelo global, puedan estar mal. E inclusive, que no nos pongamos de acuerdo en esas pocas tablas. Para modelizar una db, en general, hay que mirar el sistema completo. Yo sigo opinando que estas deben cerrarse.

Comment: No me queda claro si esta consulta es únicamente sobre el caso particular del enlace o si sólo se ha puesto este como un ejemplo. ¿podrías aclarar?

Comment: @Rubén el enlace es solo un ejemplo, busco tener una idea sobre la actitud en general. Lo relevante de este caso es que no quiero pedirle al OP que aclare las dudas para que después se le cierre la pregunta.

Comment: Nota al margen: son validas en su propio sitio: https://dba.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @gbianchi: Es bueno saberlo :) Nota al margen: Un tema puede ser "on-topic" en varios sitios

Answer (score 5):

En [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/65) la [respuesta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/167/65) que menciona administración y uso avanzado de bases de datos tiene 28 de puntuación. No recuerdo otra discusión que hayamos tenido aquí y en particular más reciente sobre modelos relacionales, así que considero que si es un tema que se pueda tratar en el sitio principal dentro del marco de https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

En otras palabras, mientras la pregunta sea específica, etc., es válida. Preguntas sobre revisión de modelos de bases de datos complejas debería ser cerradas por ser demasiado amplias.

Answer (score 3):

**On Topic**

Motivos:

1. Tiene que ver con programación
2. Diferentes modelos pueden tener diferentes utilidades. Aún así existen modelos adecuados con ciertas características que permiten su aplicación en determinado escenario. Ejemplo: Patrones de diseño (En este caso, patrones de modelos de BD)
3. > Hasta donde yo sé, no son on-topic en ningún otro sitio de stackexchange

   Son On-topic en http://stackoverflow.com

   Ejemplo:

   Esta es una excelente pregunta con información bastante detallada del problema y *multiples opciones de respuestas*, que sin embargo tienen una mejor alternativa que las demás.

   Las otras respuestas (no eliminadas) que no fueron la aceptada que tienen respuestas diferentes a la aceptada incluso tienen muchos votos positivos y solo una tiene algunos votos negativos.

   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database

Comment: Esa pregunta es demasiado vieja como para ser valida. Algunas preguntas estan por cuestiones historicas, pero no quiere decir que sean validas en el modelo actual. Ademas la pregunta y algunas respuestas son wiki, con lo cual no suman puntos para nadie. Si ese fuera el caso, bienvenidas, pero no creo que nadie se tome ese trabajo asi a la ligera.