# ¿Qué hacemos con preguntas sobre suites o paquetes de software?

Tags: discusión, temática

La pregunta problema:

[Odoo, botón no cambia de idioma](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5334/odoo-bot%c3%b3n-no-cambia-de-idioma)

Y de esas he visto varias sobre Wordpress y similares. ¿Qué hacemos con estas preguntas? ¿Las cerramos siempre que no haya código involucrado? Yo voté por cerrarla porque no es algo que concierne a un programador ni es un problema de programación

Comment: Relacionado: [Definición de la temática apropiada para el sitio](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/161/22721)

Answer (score 3):

En el caso del ejemplo enlazado, ya ha sido puesta en espera por ser demasiado amplia. "varias sobre Wordpress y similares" no es nada claro, sería bueno que agregaras otros ejemplos, quizás revisar cada caso en particular con la etiquetas [temática](/questions/tagged/tem%c3%a1tica) y [pregunta-específica](/questions/tagged/pregunta-espec%c3%adfica). Otra acción a realizar sería, en caso de que fuera necesario, revisar las guías de uso de las etiquetas que correspondan a las suites y paquetes de software.

---

En el caso particular de [odoo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odoo) el resumen y wiki de etiqueta no siguen los lineamientos del sitio ya que mas parece contenido copiado / "enciclopédico" siendo que debería tratar sobre las guías de uso de la etiqueta en cuestión.

En el caso de [wordpress](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress), no hay wiki de etiqueta, pero pasa lo mismo con el resumen, parece una definición, cuando debería orientar sobre cuando usar la etiqueta.

De Centro de Ayuda > Privilegios > [Aprobación de wikis de etiqueta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/approve-tag-wiki-edits) (énfasis mío)

> Las wikis de etiqueta son una introducción general a la temática de una etiqueta. Es el lugar para formar y consolidar la subcomunidad que se forma alrededor de la misma. Contienen, entre otras cosas, **información de cuándo usarla**, las preguntas más frecuentes (FAQ), enlaces relevantes, los usuarios principales, y las mejores respuestas recientes de una etiqueta.

---

Algo de lo que recién me percaté es que las etiquetas mencionadas tiene un alto índice de preguntas sin responder. En los últimos 30 días:

- [odoo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/odoo) el 100% (4 preguntas) están sin responder.
- [wordpress](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress) mas del 90% de 46 preguntas están sin responder.

Comment: Más bien esto debería ser parte de la pregunta, ¿no? No contesta la pregunta

Comment: Ostras, que la pregunta no la publicaste tú, perdona

Comment: @fedorqui No hay problema :)

Comment: Pobre Rubén, qué hizo para que lo confundan conmigo? :P